# Is there any well-known paradigm for iterating enum values?

Tags: c++, enums, iteration

I have some C++ code, in which the following enum is declared:

```
enum Some 
{
   Some_Alpha = 0,
   Some_Beta,
   Some_Gamma,
   Some_Total
};
int array[Some_Total];
```

The values of Alpha, Beta and Gamma are sequential, and I gladly use the following cycle to iterate through them:

```
for ( int someNo = (int)Some_Alpha; someNo < (int)Some_Total; ++someNo ) {}
```

This cycle is ok, until I decide to change the order of the declarations in the enum, say, making Beta the first value and Alpha - the second one. That invalidates the cycle header, because now I have to iterate from Beta to Total.
So, what are the best practices of iterating through enum? I want to iterate through all the values without changing the cycle headers every time. I can think of one solution:

```
enum Some 
{
   Some_Start = -1,
   Some_Alpha,
   ...
   Some_Total
};
int array[Some_Total];
```

and iterate from (Start + 1) to Total, but it seems ugly and I have never seen someone doing it in the code. Is there any well-known paradigm for iterating through the enum, or I just have to fix the order of the enum values? (let's pretend, I really have some awesome reasons for changing the order of the enum values)...

Comment: Could you provide an example on when this is needed? Or is this purely theoretical ?

Comment: My code depends on the designers' team decisions. They sometimes change their mind about the order of elements, present on the screen. I have to update my enum values according to what the current order of the elements is...

Comment: Normally you wouldn't change the order - if you do, things that rely on that order (if you are using enums at both ends of a comms system, writing the values to a file/database) will break.

Comment: @Graham: I guess that's why he's asking how to write code which does not rely on the order, so that his code won't "break". IMO this is good practice and to be encouraged.

Comment: @onebyone The question is, why does he need to iterate over enum values (in order or not) at all? In over 25 years of C & C++ programming I've never needed to do this.

Comment: I don't dispute that part. I dispute the expectation that graham.reeds implies, that enums should never change order, because code using them can reasonably rely on their order. Obviously enums shouldn't change order just for the fun of it, but client code certainly should not be written with a particular enum order in mind, whether it's attempting to iterate or not. An enum could define that it occupies a contiguous range, if enumeration were for some reason required, but would still not need to have fixed order provided that start and end values were defined.

Comment: "Fixed" with respect to source-compatible API changes, I mean. Obviously any change breaks binary compatibility.

Comment: In Pascal, `for e := Low(MyEnum) to High(MyEnum) do` - typically used when enumerations are actually useful rather than just disguised integers though, e.g. for array indexes, sets, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enum Some
{
   Some_first_ = 0,
   Some_Alpha = Some_first_,
....
   Some_last_
};
```

Doing such you can grant first & last never changes order

Comment: Note: this still depends on the assumption that your enum values are continuous (i.e. only the start value is set).

Answer (score 13):

You can define an `operator++()` for your `enum`. This has the advantage that it uses the well-known paradigm of the standard incrementation operators. `:)`

Depending on whether your enums are contiguous, you can treat them as `int` or use a switch:

```
Some& operator++(Some& obj)
{
# if YOUR_ENUMS_ARE_CONTIGUOUS
  int i = obj;
  if( ++i > Some_Total ) i = Some_Alpha;
  return obj = static_cast<Some>(i);
# else 
  switch(obj)
  {
    case Some_Alpha : obj = Some_Beta;  break;
    case Some_Beta  : obj = Some_Gamma; break;
    case Some_Gamma : obj = Some_Total; break;
    case Some_Total : obj = Some_Alpha; break;
    default: assert(false); // changed enum but forgot to change operator
  }
  return obj;
# endif
}
```

Note that, if `operator++()` is defined, users will probably expect an `operator--()`, too.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way of doing this because there is no guarantee that someone hasn't written code like:

```
enum Some 
{
   Some_Alpha = 0,
   Some_Beta,
   Some_Gamma = 42,
   Some_Delta, 
  Some_Total
};
```

Comment: As sbi has pointed out, there actually is a way of doing this that can handle such a case just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use static class members.

Examples in this [article](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403955) with its [source code](http://www.ddj.com/showArticle.jhtml?documentID=cujweb0305meynard&pgno=4).

Comment: +1, enums are too primitive a datatype to iterate over them, dr. dobb comes to the rescue.

Comment: Great article, thanks! I remember the discussion of "typesafe enum" pattern in some Java book and this is just the same for c++

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 (and probably earlier), you could use the following hack, to make `Some` iterable:

```
Some operator++(Some& s) {
    return s = (Some )(std::underlying_type<Some>::type(x) + 1); 
}
Some operator*(Some s) {
    return s;
} 
Some begin(Some s) {
    return Some_Alpha;

Some end(Some s) {
    return Some_Gamma;
}

int main() { 
    // the parenthesis here instantiate the enum
    for(const auto& s : Some()) { 
        // etc. etc.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(This answer was shamelessly adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8498356/1593077).)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use any assignments, the enums are guaranteed to be sequential starting with 0 as the first. 
thers.

The best thing you can do is keep them in the order you want in your enum definition, and cycle through them with the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I place all Enums in their own namespace. Example:

```
namespace Foo {
enum Enum {
    First=0, // must be sequential
    Second,
    Third,
    End // must be last
};
}
```

In code:

```
for (int i=Foo::First; i!=Foo::End; i++) {
// do stuff
}
```

This is because C++ allows stuff like this (not tested in a compiler):

```
enum Foo {
Alpha = 1
};

enum Bar {
Beta = 2
};

Foo foo = Beta;
```

Which is clearly wrong.

Comment: Almost my enums are declared inside classes, which provide the scope. In C++, the class is the basic scoping unit, not the namespace.

Comment: A class that exists just for holding an enum doesn't feel right.

Comment: Well, neither does a namespace, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Namespaces are great (and my original enum is hidden inside a class). Ok, but the question is that you are forced to change your enum to { Second, First, Third, End } and you must find and replace all the code, where you iterate through it.

Comment: Normally you wouldn't change the order - if you do, things that rely on that order (if you are using enums at both ends of a comms system, writing the values to a file/database) will break.

Comment: @graham: `Foo foo = Beta;` is indeed wrong -- which is why it isn't allowed in C++.

Comment: Like I said - I haven't tested the code in an actual compiler, but there are problem like enum DaysOfWeek { Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday }; DaysOfWeek days = Wednesday + Friday;

Comment: @graham: This, too, doesn't compile in C++. I believe both of your examples compile in C. Are you perhaps confusing C and C++ here? (I wouldn't complain, but you specifically wrote _"because C++ allows stuff like this"_. And I do remember Stroustrup writing somewhere that he forbid that when he invented C++, because it is indeed unsafe and error-prone).

Comment: Well I am writing off the top of my head - I don't have access to a C++ compiler at my current work, and I am too lazy at home to dig one up and try it out, but I am pretty sure you can add with enums - they are only ints at heart.

Comment: @graham: As I said, they are _in C_. They are _not_ in C++. Why don't you check this at http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout? It's free and it's considered to be the most std-conforming compiler around.

Answer (score 0):

In a C# app, I have an icon that the user can click to change the sort order of a list. Here is the enum:

```
private enum sortByValues
{
    Date,
    Distance,
    Time,
    Speed,
    Name,
    LastOne
 }

 private sortByValues sortByValue = sortByValues.Date;
```

Note the value "LastOne" is not shown to the user (or, rather, an appropriate icon isn't) but used as a marker to denote the end of the enum.

Then when the user clicks the icon to change the sort order I simply increment sortByValue and check if it's reached the end. If it has, I reset it to the first enum value:

```
sortByValue++;

if (sortByValue is sortByValues.LastOne) sortByValue = sortByValues.Date;
```