# C preprocessor macro for returning a string repeated a certain number of times

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Does someone know of any C99 preprocessor magic that allows for creating a string consisting of another string repeated N times?

E.g.

```
STRREP( "%s ", 3 )
```

becomes

```
"%s %s %s "
```

after preprocessing.

The only thing I could think of myself was something like this

```
#define STRREP( str, N ) STRREP_##N( str )    
#define STRREP_0(str) ""
#define STRREP_1(str) str
#define STRREP_2(str) str str
#define STRREP_3(str) str str str
...
```

which works well, but is ugly as I have to define a macro for each repetition length manually. I want to use it together with variadic macros and the macro returning the number of macro arguments shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308243/macro-returning-the-number-of-arguments-it-is-given-in-c).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not possible. See another question here which is similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319328/writing-a-while-loop-in-the-c-preprocessor

Comment: Thank you, @mattjgalloway. You seem to be right. There is no way of variable recursion length in pure C99 using the preprocessor. So my idea seems to be the only (ugly!) way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My suggestion is to use the boost.

E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>

#define Fold(z, n, text)  text

#define STRREP(str, n) BOOST_PP_REPEAT(n, Fold, str)

int main(){
    printf("%s\n", STRREP("%s ", 3));//STRREP("%s ", 3) -> "%s %s %s "
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Alex , This code work in C. using the template(like to take advantage of C++)  does not use C.  
it can use  such a preprocessor.

Comment: `BOOST_PP_REPEAT` has `BOOST_PP_LIMIT_REPEAT` limit set to `256`(as for 1.48). Anyway, +1 for solution.

Comment: Thank supplement.
I think  enough if ordinary 256.

Comment: Thank you. As in principle there seems to be no cleaner way than what I did, I'll stick to the Boost-header as it looks quite elegant.

Comment: @Marcus S , Yes, but it is abnormal even if you look inside boost. However, better than making  from scratch.

Answer (score 56):

Since it's a macro and N is a numeric constant anyway, how about this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define REP0(X)
#define REP1(X) X
#define REP2(X) REP1(X) X
#define REP3(X) REP2(X) X
#define REP4(X) REP3(X) X
#define REP5(X) REP4(X) X
#define REP6(X) REP5(X) X
#define REP7(X) REP6(X) X
#define REP8(X) REP7(X) X
#define REP9(X) REP8(X) X
#define REP10(X) REP9(X) X

#define REP(HUNDREDS,TENS,ONES,X) \
  REP##HUNDREDS(REP10(REP10(X))) \
  REP##TENS(REP10(X)) \
  REP##ONES(X)

int main(void)
{
  printf(REP(9,0,7, "*")); // "*" repeated 907 times
  printf(REP(0,9,2, "#")); // "#" repeated 92 times
  printf(REP(0,0,1, "@")); // "@" repeated 1 times
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea! I'll keep that up my sleeves. Thank you.

Comment: \*Vomits all over screen\* but it's pretty easy to use though +1

Answer (score 5):

I recently discovered a recursion scheme with the CPP c-preprocessor file inclusion mechanism over the __INCLUDE_LEVEL__ preprocessor literal which is treated automatically - so maybe this algorithm only works for gcc ?!?

- The algorithm is conceptually unlimited, it can be extended with additional file indirection.
- The herin presented code handles an ITERATION_COUNT from 0-39202
- With the comment/uncomment of the ITERATION_SEPARATOR you can
  generate N elements, or 1 element with N concatenations, suitable for string repetitions.
- The ITERATION_ELEMENT macro is used as the "repetition element"

---

You can compile the code regulary, without any additional defines. The macro invocation inside the code is idempotent.

An exemplary output:

> gcc iterate.c -o iterate -Wall -s -O3 && ./iterate.exe

0-1591 Counter

1592 Elements

---

iterate.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {

const char * preproc_array[] = {
#define ITERATION_COUNT         1592                //0-(199*197-1)39202 (maximum counter)
#define ITERATION_SEPARATOR ,                       //this macro, if active, determines wheather there exits N separate elements otherwise, if outcommented, just 1 element with N concatenations
#define ITERATION_ELEMENT   0-__COUNTER__ Counter\n //the expanded macro as an arbitrary element
#include "iterate.h"
};

return !printf("%s%"PRIu32" Elements",preproc_array[
#ifndef NO_ITERATION_SEPARATOR
__COUNTER__-1
#else
0
#endif
], sizeof(preproc_array)/sizeof(const char *));

}
```

iterate.h:

```
#define     ITERATION_START 1   //start index of first inclusion
#define     ITERATION_LIMIT     199 //conforming to CPP preprocessor manual pg. 54 chapter 11.5, a limit of 200 is set arbitrary
#define     ITERATION(...)      _ITERATION(__VA_ARGS__)
#define     _ITERATION(...)     #__VA_ARGS__ ITERATION_SEPARATOR

#ifndef ITERATION_SEPARATOR
#define ITERATION_SEPARATOR
#define NO_ITERATION_SEPARATOR
#endif   

//here begins the recursive algorithm via preprocessor file inclusion, enable the warnings if you want to see how it loops through

#if __INCLUDE_LEVEL__   <=  ITERATION_COUNT/ITERATION_LIMIT
//~ #warning DIV
#define ITERATION_END   ITERATION_COUNT/ITERATION_LIMIT+3 // + offset
#include "loop.h"
#define ITERATION_END   ITERATION_LIMIT
#include "loop.h"
#include "iterate.h"
#endif

#if __INCLUDE_LEVEL__   ==  ITERATION_START
//~ #warning MOD
#define ITERATION_END   ITERATION_COUNT%ITERATION_LIMIT+ITERATION_START
#include "loop.h"
#if ITERATION_COUNT     %   ITERATION_LIMIT
#define ITERATION_END   3   // + offset
#include "loop.h"
#endif
#endif

//end of alogrithm
```

loop.h:

```
#if __INCLUDE_LEVEL__   <   ITERATION_END
#include "loop.h"
ITERATION(ITERATION_ELEMENT)
#undef ITERATION_END
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
#define DUP2(str) str str
#define DUP4(str) DUP2(str) DUP2(str)
#define DUP8(str) DUP4(str) DUP4(str)
#define DUP16(str) DUP8(str) DUP8(str)
#define DUP32(str) DUP16(str) DUP16(str)
#define DUP64(str) DUP32(str) DUP32(str)
#define DUP128(str) DUP64(str) DUP64(str)
#define DUP256(str) DUP128(str) DUP128(str)
#define DUP512(str) DUP256(str) DUP256(str)
#define DUP1024(str) DUP512(str) DUP512(str)
```

Comment: And how would one use this to duplicate a string, e.g., 1023 times? (With 1023 being a numerical input.)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure whether it can be done with the macro but you can do it with the function like:

```
char *strrep(const char *str, int nrep)
{
    if (nrep <= 0 || !str) return NULL;
    char *buf = malloc(strlen(str) * nrep + 1);
    if (!buf) return NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < nrep; ++i) {
        strcat(buf, str);
    }
    return buf;
}
```

Now you can use it:

```
char *r = strrep("%s", 3);
if (r) {
    ...
    free(r);
}
```

**UPD**: If you want to avoid `malloc/free` this is a variant of the first code:

```
/* .h */
#define STRREP_MAX_CHARS 1024
#define STRREP_INIT static char __strrep_buffer[STRREP_MAX_CHARS]
#define STRREP(str, nrep) strrep(str, nrep) ? __strrep_buffer : ""

char *strrep(const char *str, int nrep);

/* .c */
STRREP_INIT;

char *strrep(const char *str, int nrep)
{
    if (nrep <= 0 || !str) return 0;
    if (strlen(str) * nrep >= STRREP_MAX_CHARS) return 0;
    memset(__strrep_buffer, 0, STRREP_MAX_CHARS);
    for (int i = 0; i < nrep; ++i) {
        strcat(__strrep_buffer, str);
    }
    return __strrep_buffer;
}
```

Now:

```
printf("%s\n", STRREP("%s", 3));
```

OTOH, this looks even uglier than the first one.

Comment: Of course, it can be done using functions, but I'd like to have the string known at compile time.