# How to count the elements in a #define

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, c-preprocessor

How can I get the numbers of elements in a macro definition like this:

```
#define myThings @"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E"
```

What is the way to get the answer 5 from myThings?

`[myThings count]` does not work...

Comment: your `[myThings count]` and `@"A"` and nsstring make me think here we are dealing with Obj-C... maybe that tag could be more appropriate than nsstring - or numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defines are literal substitution of text: would it work a code like

```
  [@"A", @"B", @"C" count];
```

? If the answer is no, it won't work, then here it is your problem. You could do

```
  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: myThings, nil] count];
```

This should work, but I do not suggest to use this "pattern" at all.

**ADD**

Another way to count how many values there are, could be the following:

```
  NSString *arr[] = {myThings};
  size_t cnt = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(NSString *);
```

this is a C common way to know how many elements are in `arr`. Again, I stress the fact that `myThings` is *literally* replaced by whatever you defined it using `#define`, and so the result is the same as

```
  NSString *arr[] = {@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E"};
```

**Add2**

Note that, if you won't use `arr` "for real", optimizations will remove it, and there's no "waste of space".

However, another solution would be to count the number of arguments passed to a macro, so that CountingMacro(myThings) would be replaced with 5. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308243/macro-returning-the-number-of-arguments-it-is-given-in-c) might help in this case.

Comment: The problem is that "myThings" is a NSString, so count does not work. I don't want to create an array, just to count them (waste of memory).  What would you suggest?

Comment: as you've written it, myThings is not a NSString: it is (literaly) a common separated list of NSString, which is different! I'm going to update the answers with another possibility

Comment: Got it. Thanx. But let me then ask for _your suggestion_ in my "problem": What I want is do define the items (in a .h file) and use them in this: **segmentedButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:myThings,nil]];** But, then (in another ViewController.m file) I want to know the number of myThings. I understand what you suggest (I did it and it works _of course_), but I am asking if that is the most efficient way to do it, cos it looks like a waste of memory to create an array space, just to count the items. Is there a better way?

Comment: if it is a statically created array, I bet it is not that big; moreover, if the array is static, you know in advance how many strings there are (5 in the example); but you're right it's better the cmpiler counts them; but it can't, unless you "create" something it can operate on; but **don't worry**: if your temporary array is not used elsewhere, optimizations will remove it from the final code, leaving only the computed "length". Another solution could be given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308243/macro-returning-the-number-of-arguments-it-is-given-in-c