# C-preprocessor recursive macro

Tags: c-preprocessor

```
#define PP_ARG0_(arg0, ...) arg0
#define PP_REST_(arg0, ...) __VA_ARGS__
#define PP_ARG0(args) PP_ARG0_ args
#define PP_REST(args) PP_REST_ args

#define FUNCTION(name) void name();
#define FUNCTION_TABLE(...)                   \
    FUNCTION(PP_ARG0((__VA_ARGS__)))          \
    FUNCTION_TABLE(PP_REST((__VA_ARGS__)))    \
```

test code:

```
FUNCTION_TABLE(f1, f2,f3,testA,testB,testC);
```

Obviously, because of recursive expansion it will only declare `void f1();`  and the rest won't be expanded:

```
void f1(); FUNCTION_TABLE(f2,f3,testA,testB,testC);
```

What kind of trick can I use to achieve recursive expansion in this case? The problem is that I need to support MANY arguments (up 100) and I absolutely cannot use boost.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: It's overly simplified version of automatic code generator using c coprocessor. In the end, I came to conclusion that there is no way to get it done without writing separate macro for each iteration. That is, to be support FUNCTION_TABLE with 100 args I have to write 100 defines like FUNCTION_TABLE_1, FUNCTION_TABLE_2 etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the answer in case somebody wants to do the same.

```
#define _PP_0(_1, ...) _1            // (a,b,c,d) => a
#define _PP_X(_1, ...) (__VA_ARGS__) // (a,b,c,d) => (b,c,d)

//for each a in __VA_ARGS__ do f(a,x) 
//where x is some parameter passed to PP_TRANSFORM
#define PP_TRANSFORM(f,x,...) \
    PP_JOIN(PP_TRANSFORM_,PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__))(f,x,(__VA_ARGS__))

#define PP_TRANSFORM_0(...)
#define PP_TRANSFORM_1( f,x,a) f(_PP_0 a,x) PP_TRANSFORM_0( f,x,_PP_X a)
#define PP_TRANSFORM_2( f,x,a) f(_PP_0 a,x) PP_TRANSFORM_1( f,x,_PP_X a)
...
#define PP_TRANSFORM_51(f,x,a) f(_PP_0 a,x) PP_TRANSFORM_50( f,x,_PP_X a)
...
#define PP_TRANSFORM_99(f,x,a) f(_PP_0 a,x) PP_TRANSFORM_98(f,x,_PP_X a)
#define PP_TRANSFORM_100(f,x,a)f(_PP_0 a,x) PP_TRANSFORM_99(f,x,_PP_X a)
```

where [`PP_NARG`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2308651/468725) is the macro that counts number of arguments and `PP_JOIN` is the macro that joins tokens (that is `PP_JOIN(a,b) => ab`). You'll also need to patch that `PP_NARG` if you want to be able to process more than 64 arguments.

Now, back to the original question. Solution using the `PP_TRANSFORM` is:

```
#define FUNCTION(name, dummy) void name();
#define FUNCTION_TABLE(...) PP_TRANSFORM(FUNCTION,dummy,__VA_ARGS__)
```

if you want to generate c++ implementation functions then you can use that opaque x parameter of `PP_TRANSFORM`:

```
#define FUNCTION_CPP(name, class) void class::name(){}
#define FUNCTION_TABLE_CPP(...) PP_TRANSFORM(FUNCTION_CPP,MyClass,__VA_ARGS__)
```

All this works equally well with GCC and MSVC preprocessors; PP_TRANSFORM_NN doesn't use `__VA_ARGS__` to avoid separate implementations of 100 defines for GCC and MSVC

Answer (score 10):

The simplest solution is to use sequence iteration like this:

```
#define CAT(x, y) PRIMITIVE_CAT(x, y)
#define PRIMITIVE_CAT(x, y) x ## y

#define FUNCTION(name) void name();
#define FUNCTION_TABLE(seq) CAT(FUNCTION_TABLE_1 seq, _END)
#define FUNCTION_TABLE_1(x) FUNCTION(x) FUNCTION_TABLE_2
#define FUNCTION_TABLE_2(x) FUNCTION(x) FUNCTION_TABLE_1
#define FUNCTION_TABLE_1_END
#define FUNCTION_TABLE_2_END
```

Then you call `FUNCTION_TABLE` with a preprocessor sequence instead of varidiac arguments:

```
FUNCTION_TABLE((f1)(f2)(f3)(testA)(testB)(testC))
```

Not only is this much simpler, its also faster(ie faster compilation) than using the recursive solution(like the one you've shown or like this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10542793/375343)).

Comment: I got the idea. In my case however I need to pass function return type, function name, function args and function args look something like this: `(int, int, const char*)`, so, if I use sequence iteration then it would be somewhat confusing with all the braces: `(int)(doSomething)(int, int, const char*)` instead of `int, doSomething,(int, int, const char*)`

Comment: Actually, my iterative part doesn't process function declarations; iterative part processes function table that could have 1 or 256 functions. I might update my code to see if it works better

Comment: @Pavel If you want to avoid too many nested parenthesis, you can still do something like this: `FUNCTION_TABLE( (int, f1, int, int, const char*) (int, f2, int, int, const char*) )`, if you define your `FUNCTION` macro like this `#define FUNCTION(ret, name, ...) ret name(__VA_ARGS__);`. Or if that doesn't work, you can do better formatting to avoid confusion as well, such as putting each function on a separate line.

Comment: This solution is great. But I can't understand how it works. As far as I know, a token will not expand twice in the same scope. Because it is "painted blue". When FUNCTION_TABLE_2 is expanded, the macro FUNCTION_TABLE_1 should already be painted yet. Why is it still expanded?

Comment: @Yyao `FUNCTION_TABLE_2` is not expanded inside `FUNCTION_TABLE_1` so it has a different disabling context, so its not ever painted blue.

Comment: I tried it out and I'm fairly certain that this approach will not work whatsoever without using the format `(() () ())` instead of `( , , )`, because the function-style macros rely upon it in order to work with any parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I really struggled to understand this sequence iteration concept, but piecing together the [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16994140/1599699) and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43997072/1599699) - and, working my way through it bit by bit... - I believe I have figured it out, and how to explain and understand it.

---

Here is some friendly code, which I have tweaked by:

- renaming the macros (I find that naming the macros a little more sensibly helps me to understand the process a lot better)
- giving an optional empty parameters option if wanted via. `__VA_OPT__` (that part can be removed if unwanted)
- rearranging the order of the macros so they work with my current compiler, g++ *(Technically this code is c++, not c, but it's basically the same thing here.)*
- providing the ability to swap out which variadic macro is utilized for this recursion process

Note that the parameters **have** to be specified in the format `(() () ())` instead of `( , , )`, because the function-style macros rely upon it in order to work with any parameters. **See below the code for an in-depth explanatory walkthrough.**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define CONCAT(a, ...) a ## __VA_ARGS__
#define CONCAT_FUNC(a, ...) CONCAT(a, __VA_ARGS__)

//Whatever is inside each () will be prepended and appended with what's here.
#define MyVariadicMacro(...) << __VA_ARGS__ + 7 << " "
#define MyVariadicMacro2(...) << __VA_ARGS__ << " "

#define RESOLVE_A(...) __VA_OPT__(VARIADIC_FUNC(__VA_ARGS__)) RESOLVE_B
#define RESOLVE_B(...) __VA_OPT__(VARIADIC_FUNC(__VA_ARGS__)) RESOLVE_A
#define RESOLVE_A_END
#define RESOLVE_B_END
#define RECURSE(...) CONCAT_FUNC(RESOLVE_A __VA_ARGS__, _END)

int main()
{
  //Choose your own variadic macro, to provide what to prepend and append to each variadic argument!
  #define VARIADIC_FUNC MyVariadicMacro

  //Note: Empty ()'s are in here just to provide an example that they can be ignored via. __VA_OPT__().
  std::cout RECURSE(() (0) () (1) (2) (3) ());

  //Swapping out with variadic macro is being utilized for RECURSE.
  #undef VARIADIC_FUNC
  #define VARIADIC_FUNC MyVariadicMacro2

  std::cout RECURSE(() (0) () (1) (2) (3) ());

  #undef VARIADIC_FUNC

  return 0;
}
```

`Output: 7 8 9 10 0 1 2 3`

```cpp
//Starting with:
std::cout RECURSE(() (0) () (1) (2) (3) ());

//Apply: #define RECURSE(...) CONCAT_FUNC(RESOLVE_A __VA_ARGS__, _END)
std::cout CONCAT_FUNC(RESOLVE_A() (0) () (1) (2) (3) (), _END);

//Apply: #define CONCAT_FUNC(a, ...) CONCAT(a, __VA_ARGS__)
std::cout CONCAT(RESOLVE_A() (0) () (1) (2) (3) (), _END);

//Apply: #define CONCAT(a, ...) a ## __VA_ARGS__
std::cout RESOLVE_A() (0) () (1) (2) (3) () ## _END;

//Apply: #define RESOLVE_A(...) __VA_OPT__(VARIADIC_FUNC(__VA_ARGS__)) RESOLVE_B
//Note: Since the () is empty, the __VA_OPT__() part is simply skipped.
std::cout RESOLVE_B(0) () (1) (2) (3) () ## _END;

//Apply: #define RESOLVE_B(...) __VA_OPT__(VARIADIC_FUNC(__VA_ARGS__)) RESOLVE_A
std::cout VARIADIC_FUNC(0) RESOLVE_A() (1) (2) (3) () ## _END;

//Apply: #define MyVariadicMacro(...) << __VA_ARGS__ + 7 << " "
//Apply: #define VARIADIC_FUNC MyVariadicMacro
std::cout << 0 + 7 << " " RESOLVE_A() (1) (2) (3) () ## _END;

//Apply: #define RESOLVE_A(...) __VA_OPT__(VARIADIC_FUNC(__VA_ARGS__)) RESOLVE_B
//Note: Since the () is empty, the __VA_OPT__() part is simply skipped.
std::cout << 0 + 7 << " " RESOLVE_B(1) (2) (3) () ## _END;

//And so on... ending up with:
//Note: Ending with empty () or non-empty() doesn't matter; either way, we will end up with a RESOLVE_?_END.
std::cout << 0 + 7 << " " << 1 + 7 << " " << 2 + 7 << " " << 3 + 7 << " " RESOLVE_A() ## _END;

//Apply: #define RESOLVE_A(...) __VA_OPT__(VARIADIC_FUNC(__VA_ARGS__)) RESOLVE_B
//Note: Since the () is empty, the __VA_OPT__() part is simply skipped.
std::cout << 0 + 7 << " " << 1 + 7 << " " << 2 + 7 << " " << 3 + 7 << " " RESOLVE_B ## _END;

//Apply: ## simply concatenates.
std::cout << 0 + 7 << " " << 1 + 7 << " " << 2 + 7 << " " << 3 + 7 << " " RESOLVE_B_END;

//Apply: #define RESOLVE_B_END
//Note: In this particular case, we happened to end up with RESOLVE_B_END; in other cases, we will end with
//RESOLVE_A_END.
std::cout << 0 + 7 << " " << 1 + 7 << " " << 2 + 7 << " " << 3 + 7 << " ";

//Etc.
std::cout << 7 << " " << 8 << " " << 9 << " " << 10 << " ";
```

---

Note: If you want to use `RECURSE` with an X-macro concept, you have to do something a little extra. The problem with an X-macro is you would have it defined like this for usage in a recursive macro:

```cpp
#define MyThing (() (0) () (1) (2) (3) ())
```

and when you go to use it like that, either via. `RECURSE()` or any other macro, it's wrapped in some extra parentheses:

```cpp
//It interprets this as RECURSE((() (0) () (1) (2) (3) ())), which is bad.
std::cout RECURSE(MyThing);
```

The solution is to use a macro like this, and let it naturally resolve to remove the parentheses. Here's an example of modifying `RECURSE()` for this:

```cpp
#define ESCAPE_PAREN(...) __VA_ARGS__

//Old RECURSE():
#define RECURSE(...) CONCAT_FUNC(RESOLVE_A __VA_ARGS__, _END)

//New RECURSE():
#define RECURSE(...) CONCAT_FUNC(RESOLVE_A ESCAPE_PAREN __VA_ARGS__, _END)

//Alternatively, just use this instead of RECURSE() (seems to work better):
#define RECURSE_ESCAPE(...) ESCAPE_PAREN __VA_ARGS__
```

Important to note here is that `ESCAPE_PAREN` when used does not wrap the `__VA_ARGS__` in `()`.

---

Edit: I updated the above macros after attempting to use them in a real project. I also added some other related macros that may be of use (`RECURSE_FIRST` (only go through the first entry), `RECURSE_LATTER` (only go through the latter entries after the first entry), and their `_ESCAPE` versions, and `RECURSE_SPLIT` (go through the first entry, apply the `VARIADIC_FUNC_FIRST()` macro on that, go through only the latter entries, apply the `VARIADIC_FUNC()` macro on those, go through the first entry again, apply the `VARIADIC_FUNC_END()` macro on that, and concatenate all of these together...)):

```cpp
//#define ESCAPE_PAREN(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define RESOLVE_A(...) __VA_OPT__(VARIADIC_FUNC(__VA_ARGS__) RESOLVE_B)
#define RESOLVE_B(...) __VA_OPT__(VARIADIC_FUNC(__VA_ARGS__) RESOLVE_A)
#define RECURSE(...) RESOLVE_A __VA_ARGS__
//#define RECURSE_ESCAPE(...) RECURSE(ESCAPE_PAREN __VA_ARGS__)

#define RESOLVE_FIRST(...) __VA_OPT__(VARIADIC_FUNC(__VA_ARGS__) DISCARD_A)
#define RESOLVE_LATTER(...) RESOLVE_B
#define DISCARD_A(...) __VA_OPT__(DISCARD_B)
#define DISCARD_B(...) __VA_OPT__(DISCARD_A)
#define RECURSE_FIRST(...) RESOLVE_FIRST __VA_ARGS__ ()
#define RECURSE_LATTER(...) RESOLVE_LATTER __VA_ARGS__ ()

#define RESOLVE_SPLIT_FIRST(...) __VA_OPT__(VARIADIC_FUNC_FIRST(__VA_ARGS__) DISCARD_A)
#define RESOLVE_SPLIT_END(...) __VA_OPT__(VARIADIC_FUNC_END(__VA_ARGS__) DISCARD_A)
#define RECURSE_SPLIT(...) RESOLVE_SPLIT_FIRST __VA_ARGS__ () RESOLVE_LATTER __VA_ARGS__ () RESOLVE_SPLIT_END __VA_ARGS__ ()
```

These I found to be much less hassle/inhibiting when trying to work with commas and semicolons in my macros... They of course work just like above, and you can use X-macros in the following form with them:

```
MyXMacro((a) (b) (57) (32))
MyXMacro((c) (d) (49) (32))
```

---

See also:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro
- X-macros, a very powerful tool:

  - (This article showcases a cleaner way than you'll typically see:) https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2021/02/01/x-macros
  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro