# Why does sequence iteration work in C macro?

Tags: c++, c, macros

When writing C macro, there is a trick called "sequence iteration". It looks like as follow:

```
#define CAT(a, ...) PRIMITIVE_CAT(a, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PRIMITIVE_CAT(a, ...) a ## __VA_ARGS__
#define FUNCTION(name) void name();
#define FUNCTION_TABLE(seq) CAT(FUNCTION_TABLE_1 seq, _END)
#define FUNCTION_TABLE_1(x) FUNCTION(x) FUNCTION_TABLE_2
#define FUNCTION_TABLE_2(x) FUNCTION(x) FUNCTION_TABLE_1
#define FUNCTION_TABLE_1_END
#define FUNCTION_TABLE_2_END

FUNCTION_TABLE((x) (y) (z) (e))
```

The sequence, i.e. the argument of FUCTION_TABLE, will be processed one by one. However, as far as I know, a token will not be expanded twice in the same scope. Because it is "painted blue". When FUNCTION_TABLE_2 is expanded, the macro FUNCTION_TABLE_1 has already been painted yet. Why is it still expanded?

Comment: @user694733 sorry, my bad. I modified the question and added the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that inside a macro expansion all the expansion of parameters will start with the same BLUE-SET.

inside `FUNCTION_TABLE(seq)` the expansion of ALL parameters inside `FUNCTION_TABLE_1 seq` will start all the time with BLUE-SET={seq}. So after entering inside the FUNCTION_TABLE_1 the BLUE-SET is added the `x`, but when this finishes it comes back to the scope of `FUNCTION_TABLE` where the expansion starts again with the `BLUE-SET={seq}`.

So, the first time it is expanded `FUNCTION_TABLE_1(x)` and INSIDE this expansion the `BLUE-SET={seq,x}` but when the expansion of `FUNCTION_TABLE_1` finishes, it comes back to `FUNCTION_TABLE` and it will expand next FROM this scope the `FUNCTION_TABLE_2(y)` and INSIDE `FUNCTION_TABLE_2` the BLUE-SET={seq, x} again, etc.

Comment: Thank you :) But I still have a question. In the processing, `FUNCTION_TABLE_1(x) ` is expanded to `void x(); FUNCTION_TABLE_2`. At this moment, `FUNCTION_TABLE_2` is not a macro yet. But after subsitution, `FUNCTION_TABLE_2(y)` is expanded as a macro. It seems that the processor rescanned the result of substitution. Is there really a rescanning?

Comment: Yes, the preprocessor generates a new stream after each evaluation and it rescans the new stream all the time.  The new stream will have preprocessing tokens each with a new BLUE-SET, such that the recursion is not possible.  NOTE: the blue set is attached on EACH PREPROCESSING-TOKEN, NOT on EACH STREAM.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps me a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

Function-like macro replacement is a recursive process:

- The macro is expanded non-recursively first, except for `#` and `##`
- Then, recursively, any token that isn't the operand of `#` or `##` is expanded
- `#` and `##` (if any) are applied to the resulting operands
- Go to 1, until steps 1-3 cause no changes.

(this is somewhat more complicated to describe than implement!). So for your code:

- `FUNCTION_TABLE((x) (y) (z) (e))` expands to `CAT(FUNCTION_TABLE_1 (x) (y) (z) (e), _END)`
- `CAT(X, _END)` expands to `PRIMITIVE_CAT(expand(X), _END)` . Working out `expand(X)` now:

  - `FUNCTION_TABLE_1 (x) (y) (z) (e)` expands to `FUNCTION(x) FUNCTION_TABLE_2 (y) (z) (e)`:

    - `FUNCTION(x)` expands to `void x();`
    - `FUNCTION_TABLE_2 (y) (z) (e)` expands to `FUNCTION(y) FUNCTION_TABLE_1 (z) (e)`
    - `FUNCTION(y)` expands to `void y();`
    - `FUNCTION_TABLE_1 (z) (e)` expands to `FUNCTION(z) FUNCTION_TABLE_2(e)`

      - `FUNCTION(z)` expands to `void z();`
      - `FUNCTION_TABLE_2(e)` expands to `FUNCTION(e) FUNCTION_TABLE_1`
      - `FUNCTION(e)` expands to `void e();`
      - **Result:** `void e(); FUNCTION_TABLE_1`
      - **Result:** `void z(); void e(); FUNCTION_TABLE_1`
    - **Result:** `void y(); void z(); void e(); FUNCTION_TABLE_1`
    - **Result:** `void x(); void y(); void z(); void e(); FUNCTION_TABLE_1`
- So, having fully expanded `X`, let's recap where we are: `PRIMITIVE_CAT(void x(); void y(); void z(); void e(); FUNCTION_TABLE_1, _END)`
- This expands to `void x(); void y(); void z(); void e(); FUNCTION_TABLE_1_END`
- After rescanning, this gives `void x(); void y(); void z(); void e();`

Comment: So if there are three macros waiting to be expanded, the whole body will be scanned three times. After every full expansion of a macro,  a rescan will take place. Is it right?

Comment: Well...It's hard to understand this processing.   `FUNCTION_TABLE_1(x)` is expanded to `void x(); FUNCTION_TABLE_2`. At this moment, `FUNCTION_TABLE_2` is not a macro yet. But after subsitution, `FUNCTION_TABLE_2(y)` is expanded as a macro. It seems that the processor rescanned the result of substitution.

Comment: I believe I've done this right; here's my own way of explaining it, by example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66130832/1599699