# C-preprocessor: iteratively expand macro to comma-separated list

Tags: c-preprocessor, variadic-macros, comma-operator

Using Paul Fultz II's solution in the post [C-preprocessor recursive macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614992/c-preprocessor-recursive-macro), I'd like to expand an unlimited number of parenthesized macro arguments, e.g.

```cpp
#define MY_CHAIN (alpha) (beta) (gamma)
```

into a comma-separated list which can be passed to a variadic macro, e.g.

```cpp
CHAIN_COMMA(MY_CHAIN) // alpha, beta, gamma
```

I'm able to expand into braces `[alpha] [beta] [gamma]` and delimit the list with everything I've tried except a comma, `alpha :: beta :: gamma` in the example below.

Here is my full (compiling) code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// unrelated macro utilities
#define SEE(expression) cout << #expression ": " << STR(expression) << endl;
#define CMD(function, ...) function(__VA_ARGS__)
#define STR(s) CMD(STR_, s)
#define STR_(s) #s

// concatenation
#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)
#define CAT_(x,y) x ## y // error from CHAIN_COMMA: passed 4 arguments

// surround each chain element with square brackets []
#define CHAIN_BRACE(chain) CAT(CHAIN_BRACE_1 chain, _END)
#define CHAIN_BRACE_1(x) [x] CHAIN_BRACE_2
#define CHAIN_BRACE_2(x) [x] CHAIN_BRACE_1
#define CHAIN_BRACE_1_END
#define CHAIN_BRACE_2_END

// separate each chain element with the scope operator ::
#define CHAIN_SCOPE(chain) CAT(CHAIN_SCOPE_0 chain, _END)
#define CHAIN_SCOPE_0(x) x CHAIN_SCOPE_1
#define CHAIN_SCOPE_1(x) :: x CHAIN_SCOPE_2
#define CHAIN_SCOPE_2(x) :: x CHAIN_SCOPE_1
#define CHAIN_SCOPE_0_END
#define CHAIN_SCOPE_1_END
#define CHAIN_SCOPE_2_END

// trouble here: can't separate chain elements with commas
#define CHAIN_COMMA(chain) CAT(CHAIN_COMMA_0 chain, _END) // error
#define CHAIN_COMMA_0(x) x CHAIN_COMMA_1
#define CHAIN_COMMA_1(x) , x CHAIN_COMMA_2
#define CHAIN_COMMA_2(x) , x CHAIN_COMMA_1
#define CHAIN_COMMA_0_END
#define CHAIN_COMMA_1_END
#define CHAIN_COMMA_2_END

// define a custom chain and save various forms of it
#define MY_CHAIN (alpha) (beta) (gamma)
#define MY_BRACES CHAIN_BRACE(MY_CHAIN) // [alpha] [beta] [gamma]
#define MY_SCOPES CHAIN_SCOPE(MY_CHAIN) // alpha :: beta :: gamma
#define MY_COMMAS CHAIN_COMMA(MY_CHAIN) // alpha , beta , gamma

int main() {
    SEE(MY_CHAIN);
    SEE(MY_BRACES);
    SEE(MY_SCOPES);
//  SEE(MY_COMMAS); // error: macro "CAT_" passed 4 arguments, but takes just 2
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```cpp
MY_CHAIN: (alpha) (beta) (gamma)
MY_BRACES: [alpha] [beta] [gamma]
MY_SCOPES: alpha :: beta :: gamma
```

I tried parenthesizing the comma-separated list but CAT won't append `)` to `_END`. Any clever ideas to expand into `alpha, beta, gamma`?

Comment: Some possible hints from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842468/comma-in-c-c-macro

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the comma is both important to your output and is a syntactic element, you need to make a substitute comma for outputting.

```
#define COMMA() ,
```

We will also need some deferring functions so that `COMMA` isn't evaluated immediately.

```
#define EMPTY()
#define DEFER(id) id EMPTY()
```

Now we can redefine your two macros into

```
#define CHAIN_COMMA_1(x) DEFER(COMMA)() x CHAIN_COMMA_2
#define CHAIN_COMMA_2(x) DEFER(COMMA)() x CHAIN_COMMA_1
```

However, your `SEE` macro also doesn't like the commas that are placed, and so will error for having too many parameters passed.

You can see that the macro is performing correctly by [looking at the output of the preprocessor](https://godbolt.org/g/DDhrNQ) with the `-E` option.

Comment: Thanks! Nice `DEFER`/`EMPTY` macro trick, I'll remember that.

Comment: Thank you so much.