# Writing c function in preprocessror MACRO

Tags: c, recursion, c-preprocessor

I am working with converting C functions into pre-processor MACRO in c language. I know that for example:

```
int plus(int x, int y) {
  return x + y;
}
```

will be as:

```
#define PLUS(x, y) ((x) + (y))
```

in pre-processor MACRO in C language. My question is what would:

```
int factorial(int n) {
  if (n == 0)
    return 1;
  else
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

look like as pre-processor MACRO in C language. I have tried:

```
#define FACTORIAL(n) (n == 0 ? : n * FACTORIAL(n - 1))
```

But it is not working. Any tips?

Comment: You can't do this in a macro because it can't test the variable value to know when to stop expanding.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447557/can-we-have-recursive-macros

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614992/c-preprocessor-recursive-macro

Comment: Basically, recursion can't be done in a macro because the base case is determined when the code is running, but the macro expands at compile time.

Comment: @IłyaBursov You have enough rep to vote to close as a dupliate.

Comment: @Barmar they're are not direct answers to factorial question, so I want them to be as linked questions only

Comment: If you ditch the recursion you could likely do a preprocessor calculation based on `n`, up to `n == 12` or whatever. Larger than that doesn't make sense, because then you get integer overflow.

Comment: I found a better dupe, added to the duplicate list.

Comment: And well, this took me 5 minutes to write https://godbolt.org/z/6rc17PT7a.

Comment: You probably know this, but in ordinary code, replacing functions by macros is *not* generally considered a Good Thing.