# expand c macro __VA_ARGS__ elements

Tags: c, macros, variadic-functions

I want to define a macro like this

```
#define ASSERT_EXIST(error, ...)  some-impl-here
```

then we can call it like this

```
ASSERT_EXIST(100, a, b, c)
```

and it should be expand to this

```
if (!a_exists)  return error("a is missing", 100);
if (!b_exists)  return error("b is missing", 100);
if (!c_exists)  return error("c is missing", 100);
```

the most trouble part of this is I can't iterate over `__VA_ARGS__` easily in a macro.

Comment: You need to have a limit on the number of variables that you can pass to the `ASSERT_EXIST` macro. AFAIK, there is no way to write a macro that can expand all the arguments passed to it.

Comment: Look at the [Boost Preprocessor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) library (nominally for C++, but perfectly usable with C too).  It has tools to handle those requirements, at least for sensible sizes of argument list.  If you insist on 300 arguments, you may have some extra work to do.  See also [Macro returning the numnber of arguments it is given in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308243/macro-returning-the-number-of-arguments-it-is-given-in-c) and related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various dirty tricks where you can have variadic macros work up to a certain fixed number. However, the proper and correct solution is to not write a variadic macro at all. It is much better practice to simply use

```
#define ASSERT_EXISTS(val, x) if (!x##_exists) { return error(#x " is missing", val); }

ASSERT_EXIST(100, a);
ASSERT_EXIST(100, b);
...
```

Or better yet, drop all such icky macros in favour of readable standard C.

```
if(!a_exists) { return error("a is missing", 100); }
if(!b_exists) { return error("b is missing", 100); }
if(!c_exists) { return error("c is missing", 100); }
```

Sure, code repetition is bad practice, but secret macro languages are extremely bad practice.

Comment: I agree with you,  by practice it doesn't mean a lot.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to throw variable number of arguments to a function, `__VA_ARGS__` is enough as you already did. To handle the trending comma, sometimes you may also need `##`.

If you want to iterate through the arguments, use varargs from `<stdarg.h>`.

[stdarg.h](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html)

Comment: varargs have nothing to do with variadic macros