# Variadic macro trick

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

What's the trick to create a variadic macro `FOO(a1, a2, a3,..., an)` such that it expands to `FOOn(a1, a2, a3,..., an)` for values of `n` in whatever preselected bounded range you choose? That is, `FOO(a)` should expand to `FOO1(a)`, `FOO(a, b, c)` to `FOO3(a, b, c)`, etc. I know there's a standard trick but I can't seem to find it.

Please feel free to mark this question as a duplicate and close it if there's another question with the answer. I suspect there is but I couldn't find it.

Comment: this post has something that you might find usefull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420459/c-preprocessor-macro-overloading

Comment: see the answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124339/c-preprocessor-va-args-number-of-arguments

Comment: @aaa:  The answers to that question do not answer this question.  The question linked by @Mat is more similar, though I wouldn't consider it an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This post [Variadic macro to count number of arguments](https://cpptalk.wordpress.com/2010/07/17/variadic-macro-to-count-number-of-arguments/) has what you're looking for I believe. Look at the first and second responses.

Comment: Thanks, this link was just what I needed. It's much better than the potential-duplicates posted.

Answer (score 13):

```
#define VA_NARGS_IMPL(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, N, ...) N
#define VA_NARGS(...) VA_NARGS_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

#define FOO_IMPL2(count, ...) FOO ## count (__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOO_IMPL(count, ...) FOO_IMPL2(count, __VA_ARGS__) 
#define FOO(...) FOO_IMPL(VA_NARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

FOO(a)
FOO(a, b)
FOO(a, b, c)
```

The invocations are replaced by:

```
FOO1 (a)
FOO2 (a, b)
FOO3 (a, b, c)
```

Comment: Excellent answer, but how do you solve the zero-parameter case when calling `FOO()`, where it should expand to `FOO0 ()`, but your solution expand to `FOO1 ()`? I'd like to know how to do this in pure c99 (no GNU extension)

Comment: @mchiasson:  To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to do that in standard C.  You must pass at least one token to the `__VA_ARGS__`; you can't call such a macro with an empty argument list.

Answer (score 7):

Improving upon James answer to add some flexibility:

```
#define VA_NARGS_IMPL(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, N, ...) N
#define VA_NARGS(...) VA_NARGS_IMPL(X,##__VA_ARGS__, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)
#define VARARG_IMPL2(base, count, ...) base##count(__VA_ARGS__)
#define VARARG_IMPL(base, count, ...) VARARG_IMPL2(base, count, __VA_ARGS__) 
#define VARARG(base, ...) VARARG_IMPL(base, VA_NARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

#define MyMacro0() Also works without arguments.
#define MyMacro2(x,y) [x...y]
#define MyMacro(...) VARARG(MyMacro, __VA_ARGS__)

MyMacro()
MyMacro(a)
MyMacro(a, b)
MyMacro(a, b, c)
```

Output:

```
Also works without arguments.
MyMacro1(a)
[a...b]
MyMacro3(a, b, c)
```

Comment: Excellent answer, but `##__VA_ARGS__` only works with the GNU extension. Do you know how to solve this for c99?