# Passing variable name as string to function with default parameters

Tags: c++, stringify, variable-names, default-parameters

Let’s say there is a debugging function, simplified here as:

```
void DumpString(char* var, char* varname) {
    printf("%s : '%s'\n", varname, var);
}

char str[10]="foobar";
DumpString(str, "str");

> str : foobar
```

Let’s make it easier by removing the unnecessarily extraneous requirement of passing the variable twice, once in quotes:

```
#define VARASSTR(v) #v

void DumpString(char* var) {
    printf("%s : '%s'\n", VARASSTR(var), var);
}

char str[10]="foobar";
DumpString(str);

> var : foobar
```

Oops! It uses the local variable name instead of the one passed in. Let’s try a different (and less ideal) tack:

```
#define DumpStr(v) DumpString(v, #v)

void DumpString(char* var, char* varname) {
    printf("%s : '%s'\n", varname, var);
}

char str[10]="foobar";
DumpStr(str);

> str : foobar
```

Great it works. But what if the function was a little more complicated:

```
void DumpString(char* var, char* varname, int optionalvar=0) {
    printf("%s : '%s'\n", varname, var);
    printf("blah: %d", optionalvar);
}
```

It is not possible to overload a macro, so `DumpStr` won’t work, and we have already ruled out the version with `VARASSTR`.

How can this be handled (without resorting to multiple similarly, but differently-named functions/macros)?

Comment: "How can this be handled (without resorting to multiple similarly, but differently-named functions/macros)?" It can't. You can't overload macros.

Comment: You should try some language with reflection capabilities. No, really.

Comment: You could use [Variadic macro trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365440/variadic-macro-trick) to "simulate" overloading with macros.

Comment: Thanks for linking my question. :-)

Comment: You cannot overload functions too (or why did you tag this question `c`), so what is the problem?

Comment: @Jesse, yes, I thought of that, and I could if I had a C99 compiler.

Comment: @Synetech Even C99 doesn't support overloaded functions, or even default arguments.

Comment: @Synetech: What compiler are you using? MSVC and gcc both support variadic macros.

Comment: John variadic macros are in C99. Jesse, not VC2003.

Comment: VC2003? Ever think its time to upgrade? A lot has changed (bug fixes, etc.) in the last 9 years.

Answer (score 1):

This is non-standard, but works as an extension in GNU C:

```
#define DumpStr(v, ...) DumpString(v, #v, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

In GNU C, you can pass no arguments to a variadic macro, and the "token pasting operator" `##` when applied between a comma and an empty variadic argument list produces nothing (so the trailing comma is suppressed).

In Visual C++, I believe the token pasting operator `##` is unnecessary (and will probably break the macro), as Visual C++ automatically suppresses a trailing comma if it appears before an empty variadic argument list.

Note that the only thing that makes this nonstandard is the desire to sometimes pass an empty argument list. Variadic macros are standardized in both C99 and C++11.

---

**Edit:** And here's an example that doesn't use non-standard features. You can see why some people really, really wish this sort of thing was addressed in the standard:

```
#define DUMPSTR_1(v) DumpString(v, #v)
#define DUMPSTR_2(v, opt) DumpString(v, #v, opt)
#define DUMPSTR_NARG(...) DUMPSTR_ARG_N(__VA_ARGS__, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)
#define DUMPSTR_ARG_N(_1, _2, _3, _4, n, ...) n
#define DUMPSTR_NC(f, ...) f(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DUMPSTR_NB(nargs, ...) DUMPSTR_NC(DUMPSTR_ ## nargs, __VA_ARGS__)
#define DUMPSTR_NA(nargs, ...) DUMPSTR_NB(nargs, __VA_ARGS__)
#define DumpStr(...) DUMPSTR_NA(DUMPSTR_NARG(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)
```

There's probably a few cleaner ways to do this. But not that many.

---

**Edit 2:** And here's yet another example that doesn't use non-standard features, courtesy of  [R..](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379897/r)

```
#define STRINGIFY_IMPL(s) #s
#define STRINGIFY(s) STRINGIFY_IMPL(s)
#define ARG1_IMPL(a, ...) a
#define ARG1(...) ARG1_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__, 0)
#define DumpStr(...) DumpString(STRINGIFY(ARG1(__VA_ARGS__)), __VA_ARGS__)
```

Note that this requires the argument order of the `DumpString` to be changed so that the stringified function name is the first argument.

Comment: There are solutions to this problem without nonstandard hacks like this.

Comment: In particular, you subsume the whole argument list into the `...` and then use macros that extract the first (or whatever index you want) argument from `__VA_ARGS__`.

Comment: @R.. Yes, there is. And *wow* is it terrifying. I added a self-contained way that I drummed up. Can you suggest a better one?

Comment: I haven't used it, but I believe boost preprocessor will hide some of that ugliness for you if you would like.

Comment: @Jesse Yes, it will, at the cost of a large unwieldy dependency. Between that and not being standards-compliant, I'll take the one-line solution. (Assuming it works on your compiler.)

Comment: @R.. I can't think of any better ways to do it without running into warnings about too many or too few parameters…?

Comment: I was thinking something like `#define DumpStr(...) DumpString(STRINGIFY(ARG1(__VA_ARGS__)), __VA_ARGS__)` (note that the order of arguments to `DumpString` has to be changed then, but this function should presumably not be used directly anyway).

Comment: @R.. But doesn't the definition of `ARG1` run into the same problems? It might have to take an empty variadic argument list, which is non-standard, or else use a messy implementation like mine.

Comment: `#define ARG1_X(a, ...) a` and `#define ARG1(...) ARG1_X(__VA_ARGS__, 0)` should work.

Comment: @R.. Ah, yes, that's not bad. That only requires *four* supporting macros, not seven. (Somehow, in C-land, we consider that elegant.)

Comment: Well most of them are reusable and tend to already be handy if you're using the preprocessor a lot...