# Variadic template counting arguments with ellipsis passed as argument

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

This question is a follow-on from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5365786/383306.

```
#define _DEFINE_REF_INTERNAL2(id, ...)

#define _DEFINE_REF_INTERNAL1(id)

#define _VA_NARGS_2_IMPL(_1, _2, N, ...) N
#define _VA_NARGS_2(...) _VA_NARGS_2_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__, 2, 1)
#define _DEFINE_REF_IMPL2(count, ...) _DEFINE_REF_INTERNAL ## count (__VA_ARGS__)
#define _DEFINE_REF_IMPL(count, ...) _DEFINE_REF_IMPL2(count, __VA_ARGS__)
#define DEFINE_REF(...) _DEFINE_REF_IMPL(_VA_NARGS_2(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

DEFINE_REF(MyClass, typename... Args, Args...); 
// error: ‘_DEFINE_REF_INTERNALArgs’ does not name a type
DEFINE_REF(MyClass, typename T, T); // this is OK
```

How do I make the macro trick work when passing ellipsis as part of an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with the ellipsis.  The problem is that you are passing three arguments in `__VA_ARGS__` to `DEFINE_REF`, but `_VA_NARGS_2` only handles up to two arguments.

Once you fix that, the program (I believe) exhibits the desired behavior.  gcc 4.7.2 and Clang 3.2 both transform this:

```
#define DEFINE_REF_INTERNAL3(arg0, arg1, arg2) [arg0] [arg1] [arg2]

#define VA_NARGS_(_1, _2, _3, N, ...) N
#define VA_NARGS(...) VA_NARGS_(__VA_ARGS__, 3, 2, 1)

#define DEFINE_REF_IMPL_(count, ...) DEFINE_REF_INTERNAL ## count(__VA_ARGS__)
#define DEFINE_REF_IMPL(count, ...) DEFINE_REF_IMPL_(count, __VA_ARGS__)

#define DEFINE_REF(...) DEFINE_REF_IMPL(VA_NARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

DEFINE_REF(MyClass, typename... Args, Args...); 
DEFINE_REF(MyClass, typename T,       T      );
```

into this:

```
[MyClass] [typename... Args] [Args...];
[MyClass] [typename T] [T];
```

(Also note that names beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the implementation.  You may not use such names for your own macros.)

---

If you are targeting Visual C++, you will need a barrel of indirection to make this work, as it does not correctly replace macros before rescanning in all cases.  The following will work with Visual C++ (This solution is also conforming and works with gcc and Clang as well):

```
#define DEFINE_REF_INTERNAL3(id, arg0, arg1) id [arg0] [arg1]

#define CONCATENATE_(x, y) x ## y
#define CONCATENATE(x, y) CONCATENATE_(x, y)

#define VA_NARGS1(_1, _2, _3, N, ...) N
#define VA_NARGS0(x) VA_NARGS1 x
#define VA_NARGS(...) VA_NARGS0((__VA_ARGS__, 3, 2, 1))

#define DEFINE_REF_IMPL1(macro, pargs) macro pargs
#define DEFINE_REF_IMPL0(count, ...) \
    DEFINE_REF_IMPL1(CONCATENATE(DEFINE_REF_INTERNAL, count), (__VA_ARGS__))
#define DEFINE_REF_IMPL(count, ...) DEFINE_REF_IMPL0(count, __VA_ARGS__)

#define DEFINE_REF(...) DEFINE_REF_IMPL(VA_NARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: RE: comment about underscore + cap letter. Specifically, what is 'the implementation'?

Comment: Generally, _the implementation_ is the compiler, the Standard Library, and perhaps some platform libraries (like parts of the OS).  There's no clear division between what is and is not part of _the implementation_, but most code is not _the implementation_.

Comment: Ah mine falls perfectly in that compiler / std lib category. So it would've been wrong for me to pollute the global namespace.

Comment: I now face another problem where I have multiple template typenames -- `DEFINE_REF(MyClass, (typename T, typename U), (T, U))` but how do I get rid of the additional `()` when the macro gets expanded? (should this be another SO question?)

Comment: If you require that _all_ uses of `DEFINE_REF` have parenthesized arguments (i.e., that you require `DEFINE_REF(MyClass, (T), (T))`, even if there is only one argument), then you can use `#define EAT_YUMMY_PARENTHESES_(x) x` and `#define EAT_YUMMY_PARENTHESES(x) EAT_YUMMY_PARENTHESES_ x`.  This is the same trick as is used in the `VA_NARGS0` in the Visual C++-compatible code I presented.