# Macro: How do I change each value in __VA_ARGS__

Tags: c++, c, macros, c++builder-xe2

I am using C++ Builder XE3.

Currently I have such macro as below:

```
#define LOGG(message, ...) OTHER_LIB_LOG(message,__VA_ARGS__)
```

Now I want to make all arguments be AnsiString. 
It is easy for me to deal with the argument: message like below:

```
#define LOGG(message, ...) OTHER_LIB_LOG(AnsiString(message),__VA_ARGS__)
```

But for **VA_ARGS**, I do not know how to deal with the arguments to make sure all arguments which are put to `OTHER_LIB_LOG` are AnsiString.

It is hard for me to modify the source code of  `OTHER_LIB_LOG`, so I have to do this with Macro.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C macros don't recurse. So you will *have to* do some *manual* work.
Find the max number of arguments LOGG will take & use as below: My example takes max 6 arguments.

```
#define ENCODE0(x) AnsiString(x)
#define ENCODE1(x,...) AnsiString(x), ENCODE0(__VA_ARGS__)
#define ENCODE2(x,...) AnsiString(x), ENCODE1(__VA_ARGS__)
#define ENCODE3(x,...) AnsiString(x), ENCODE2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define ENCODE4(x,...) AnsiString(x), ENCODE3(__VA_ARGS__)
#define ENCODE5(x,...) AnsiString(x), ENCODE4(__VA_ARGS__)
#define ENCODE6(x,...) AnsiString(x), ENCODE5(__VA_ARGS__)
//Add more pairs if required. 6 is the upper limit in this case.
#define ENCODE(i,...) ENCODE##i(__VA_ARGS__) //i is the number of arguments (max 6 in this case)

#define LOGG(count,...) OTHER_LIB_LOG(ENCODE(count,__VA_ARGS__))
```

Sample Usage: `LOGG(5,"Hello","Hi","Namaste _/\_","Hola!","bonjour");`

Comment: check also this post  [Variadic macro trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365440/variadic-macro-trick)  for possible improvements