# Generate multiple macro calls according to the number of arguments

Tags: c++, macros, variadic-macros

I'm trying to call this function several times in a repeditive fashion.

```
template<class T>
void METADATA_METHODS_IMPL(std::string& metadata, const T &value, const std::string &key)
{
    metadata += boost::format("%1%:%2%") % key % value();
}
```

I have written the following macro:

```
#define METADATA_METHODS_IMPL_1(md, v1)\
   METADATA_METHODS_IMPL(md, v1, #v1);

#define METADATA_METHODS_IMPL_2(md, v1, v2)\
   METADATA_METHODS_IMPL_1(md, v1)\
   METADATA_METHODS_IMPL_1(md, v2)

#define METADATA_METHODS_IMPL_3(md, v1, v2, v3)\
   METADATA_METHODS_IMPL_2(md, v1, v2)\
   METADATA_METHODS_IMPL_1(md, v3)
```

and so on ...

I need to call `METADATA_METHODS_IMPL_N` where `N` is a number of arguments in `__VA_ARGS__`

```
#define METADATA_METHODS(...)\
std::string METADATA_METHODS_IMPL_FUNC()\
{\
    std::string metadata;\
    BOOST_PP_OVERLOAD(METADATA_METHODS_IMPL_,__VA_ARGS__)(metadata, __VA_ARGS__)\
    return metadata;\
}
```

The code above (with `BOOST_PP_OVERLOAD`) gives me unsuitable result:

```
class X
{
    std::string F1();
    std::string F2();
    std::string F3();

    METADATA_METHODS(F1, F2, F3);
};
```

This results in

```
std::string METADATA_METHODS_IMPL_FUNC() 
{
    std::string metadata; 
    METADATA_METHODS_IMPL(metadata, F1, F2, F3, "F1", "F2", "F3"); 
    METADATA_METHODS_IMPL(metadata, , ""); 
    METADATA_METHODS_IMPL(metadata, , ""); 
    return metadata; 
};
```

And I want something like this:

```
std::string METADATA_METHODS_IMPL_FUNC() 
{
    std::string metadata; 
    METADATA_METHODS_IMPL(metadata, F1, "F1"); 
    METADATA_METHODS_IMPL(metadata, F2, "F2"); 
    METADATA_METHODS_IMPL(metadata, F3, "F3"); 
    return metadata; 
};
```

- Does anyone know how to achieve the desired result?
- Can I use `Boost.preprocessor` library to automagically generate `METADATA_METHODS_IMPL_K` for some `K in [1 .. 10]` using `METADATA_METHODS_IMPL_1`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variadic macro trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365440/variadic-macro-trick)

Comment: Here's something that can be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308243/macro-returning-the-number-of-arguments-it-is-given-in-c

Comment: @PlasmaHH, I think the topic cannot be closed until the second question will be answered. Thanks for the help, though. One down, one to go :)

Comment: @maverik: This is why it is bad to post multiple questions as one on SO: I am sure many people will also simply overlook that there is a second question. Remember that SO preserves questions for others to find too; I would suggest you simply open a new question for your second one, and explain it in more detail there.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, you're right. Anyway, I'm checking the answers from the topic you suggested. The second one doesn't work for me (in VS 2008).

Comment: @maverik: afaik vs2008 doesn't implement the preprocessor very well in that regard; learn how to look at the preprocessed code in your compiler (always a good idea) and play with it, step by step.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, already doing that. I have no problems with boost.pp library (already wrote some things) in VS 2008, but can't figure out how to solve this question using boost.pp (lack of examples in this library makes me sad, nobody knows nothing)

Comment: @PlasmaHH, I don't know why but VS here `METADATA_METHODS(F1, F2, F3)` treats `F1, F2, F3` as one argument, so `VA_NARGS` results in `1` and function call is `METADATA_METHODS_IMPL(metadata, F1, F2, F3, "F1, F2, F3")` :( Can't find the way out

Answer (score 0):

Using these macros we can cause the preprocessor to keep rescanning and allow for recursive macros.

```
#define EVAL(...)  EVAL3(EVAL3(EVAL3(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL3(...) EVAL2(EVAL2(EVAL2(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL2(...) EVAL1(EVAL1(EVAL1(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL1(...) EVAL0(EVAL0(EVAL0(__VA_ARGS__)))
#define EVAL0(...) __VA_ARGS__
```

We can define some helper functions to build up concepts.

```
#define CAT(a, ...) PRIMITIVE_CAT(a,__VA_ARGS__)
#define PRIMITIVE_CAT(a, ...) a ## __VA_ARGS__

#define EMPTY()
#define EAT(...)
#define IDENT(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define DEFER(id) id EMPTY()
#define OBSTRUCT(...) __VA_ARGS__ DEFER(EMPTY)()   

#define I_TRUE(t,f) t
#define I_FALSE(t,f) f
#define I_IS_DONE(a,b,...) b
#define TRUE_DONE() ~, I_TRUE
#define IS_DONE(b) OBSTRUCT(I_IS_DONE)(CAT(TRUE_,b)(),I_FALSE)
```

And build this Macro Mapping function that carries the first parameter to each.

```
#define MM() MM_CALL
#define MM_NEXT(Macro,md,a,...) \
  IS_DONE(a)(                    \
     EAT                          \
  ,                                \
     OBSTRUCT(MM)()                 \
  )                                  \
  (Macro,md,a,__VA_ARGS__)
#define MM_CALL(Macro,md,a,...)   \
  Macro(md,a)                      \
  MM_NEXT(Macro,md,__VA_ARGS__)
#define MacroMap(Macro,md,...) EVAL(MM_CALL(Macro,md,__VA_ARGS__,DONE))
```

After defining the implementation related functions

```
#define METADATA_METHODS_IMPL_MACRO(md,a) \
  METADATA_METHODS_IMPL(md, a, #a);

#define METADATA_METHODS(md,...) \
  MacroMap(METADATA_METHODS_IMPL_MACRO,md,__VA_ARGS__) \
  return md
```

This:

```
METADATA_METHODS(metadata, F1, F2, F3);
```

Results in this (after adding some formatting):

```
METADATA_METHODS_IMPL(metadata, F1, "F1");
METADATA_METHODS_IMPL(metadata, F2, "F2");
METADATA_METHODS_IMPL(metadata, F3, "F3");
return metadata;
```