# Is there an easier way to do a macro to define a function with variable amount of arguments?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

I have a macro that defines a function with a variable amount of arguments, the macro has some logic to decide which real function must be called. My current approach is the following:

```
#define FUNC(ret,args,args_call) \
    ret my_func(args) { \
        if( something ) other_func(args_call);\
        return one_func(args_call);\
    }
#define PARAM(...) __VA_ARGS__
```

I use it like that:

```
class AClass : public AInterface {
public:
    FUNC(int,PARAM(int a, int b),PARAM(a,b))
};
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do that.

Note: The declared (`my_func` in my example) function will be used to reimplement a method from the super class, so the approaches using templates (the ones that I am aware of) will not solve my problem.

Edit2: Even using a proper variadic templated function, I still need the macro to declare the function because it overrides a function in the superclass.

```
#define FUNC(ret,args,args_call) \
ret my_func(args) { \
    return proper_variadic_templated_function<ret>(args_call);\
}
```

Comment: I guess there is some duplicate somewhere in Stackoverflow, but I did not find anything related to this problem because I do not know how to phrase correctly the question.

Comment: Have you heard of variadic templates?

Comment: @40two, Yes. In fact, `other_func` and `one_func` are defined this way in my context.

Comment: @AndréPuel why not write a proper forwarding variadic template function then? Do you really need the macro?

Comment: Even with a proper forwarding variadic template I would still need to define the function with a macro. I edited the question to show my point.

Comment: To me, this seems just plain wrong... To get a good answer, you probably should describe the actual problem you are seeing, rather than asking about your preferred solution. Aka "you are asking an XY Question".

Comment: @MatsPetersson http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643183/how-to-do-a-runtime-subclassing-system There you go

Answer (score 0):

If we use the `EVAL`, helper, and Conditional macros from the first two code blocks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46508666/4499969). We can create some recursive macros to parse the parameter array.

As the comma is syntactic we will need to escape it for outputting.

```
#define COMMA() ,
```

We can generate two functions to separate the types from the names.

```
#define I_WT_R() I_WT
#define I_WT(t,v,n,...) \
    t v IS_DONE(n)(      \
        EAT               \
    ,                      \
       OBSTRUCT(COMMA)()    \
       OBSTRUCT(I_WT_R)()    \
    )(n,__VA_ARGS__)
#define WithTypes(...) I_WT(__VA_ARGS__,DONE)
```

And.

```
#define I_WoT_R() I_WoT
#define I_WoT(t,v,n,...) \
    v IS_DONE(n)(         \
        EAT                \
    ,                       \
        OBSTRUCT(COMMA)()    \
        OBSTRUCT(I_WoT_R)()   \
    )(n,__VA_ARGS__)
#define WithoutTypes(...) I_WoT(__VA_ARGS__,DONE)
```

Redefining your macro as such:

```
#define FUNC(ret,args) EVAL(                           \
    ret my_func(WithTypes args) {                      \
        if( something ) other_func(WithoutTypes args); \
        return one_func(WithoutTypes args);            \
    })
```

Allows you the slightly better syntax of:

```
class AClass : public AInterface {
public:
    FUNC(int,(int,a,int,b))
};
```

Compiling to (after adding newlines):

```
class AClass : public AInterface {
public:
    int my_func(int a , int b ) {
        if( something )
            other_func(a , b );
        return one_func(a , b );
    }
};
```

Hope that helps.