# Is it possible to put a preprocessor conditional inside a C macro?

Tags: c, macros

Is there a way to write a C preprocessor macro that expands to different things depending on what argument it receives?

```
#define foo() ???

/* 1 */
foo(name)

/* 2 */
foo(_)
```

Desired result:

```
/* 1 */
int name;

/* 2 */
/*ignore*/
```

Yes, I know macros are evil. I'm asking this mostly out of curiosity.

Comment: Macros are awesome.

Comment: Could you explain the purpose, or perhaps give a better example? The parameter would have to be fixed at compile time, which means you could just as well use two different macro names.

Comment: @mbratch: In this particular case, I'm using a macro to define a set of variables but some variables are optional and I want to avoid defining them. Multiple macro names wouldnt work well because of a combinatorial explosion: with two variable names I would need separate macros for `foo(a,b)`, `foo(a,_)`, `foo(_,b)` and `foo(_,_)`.

Comment: You're sort of trying to implement a form of overloading then. Perhaps you should look into variadic macros. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420459/c-preprocessor-macro-overloading?rq=1

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: The problem is that I need to overload over the values I pass the macro, not over the number of arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps try some multi-stage macro expansion? This is the strategy used by the [Boost preprocessor/control/if library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/if.html).

```
#define FOO_NAME 1
#define FOO__ 2

#define CONC(a,b) a##_##b
#define FOO(x) CONC(FOO,x)
```

I don't think there is any way to check conditions within a C macro expansion.

The best thing I could come up with is to covert the macro arguments to a string literal using the `#` stringizing operator, and then checking using run-time functions. (This won't work for your case, though, where you want to output variable declarations.)

For example, the following prints "011":

```
#define FOO(x) (strcmp("NAME", #x) ? 1 : 0)

main()
{
    printf("%d", FOO(NAME));
    printf("%d", FOO(1));
    printf("%d", FOO(2));
}
```

The compiler would likely optimize the `strcmp` comparisons at compile-time so it would be no more inefficient than it would have been had genuine pre-processor conditionals been available. However, making `FOO` a normal function would be clearer and probably just as efficient.

Comment: Interesting trick! But is there a way where I don't need to enumerate all the possibilities for the "1" case? For example, if its `_` then the macro yields 2 if its anything else it yields 1?

Comment: I updated my answer with a limited workaround that won't work for your original question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use a runtime test in my case. I'm starting to think that the first solution you game is the best I'm gonna get.

Comment: @hugomg what you want is possible, but it requires a lot of dirty preprocessor tricks: https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms

I will add an answer

Answer (score 17):

To expand on Gavin Smith's answer, you actually can check conditions within a macro expansion:

```
#define FOO_name 1
#define FOO__ 0

#define CONC(a,b) a##_##b

#define IF(c, t, e) CONC(IF, c)(t, e)
#define IF_0(t, e) e
#define IF_1(t, e) t

#define FOO(x) IF(CONC(FOO,x), int x;, )

FOO(name) // -> int name;
FOO(_)    // -> /*nothing*/
```

If you're feeling adventurous you can easily extend `IF` to allow commas, suppress macro expansion, etc. with helper macros.

As above though this does require that you know all of the desired names in advance.

Answer (score 3):

With the tricks described [here](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms), it is possible to do what you want at compile time.

You could use the `EQUAL` macro defined at the end of the document, and do this:

```
#define COMPARE__(x) x
#define OPTION_0(x) int x;
#define OPTION_1(x) /* nothing */
#define foo(x) CAT(OPTION_, EQUAL(_, x))(x)

foo(name1) // int name1;
foo(_)     // /* nothing */
foo(name2) // int name2;
```