# Is this macro argument counting tactic legit?

Tags: c, macros, variadic-macros

I've been aware of the `VA_NARGS` macro as described at [C Preprocessor, Macro "Overloading"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420459/c-preprocessor-macro-overloading)
for a while, but I've always been put off by the large amount of boilerplate that it takes to make it work.

I recently had a need for this functionality, and so I gritted my teeth and wrote all the requisite macro code, in all its "glory."

In my particular case, I can consistently rely on all of the varargs arguments to be of a particular type. This led me to think that perhaps there's a better way, using `sizeof` and an array type. I tried this out on my local system, and it seems to work. However, I am concerned that this solution may be brittle (beyond the type restriction).

My questions are: Is this in fact a safe and reasonably sane solution to the problem? Or perhaps: What trouble am I asking for, down the line, if I use this? And finally: To the extent that there are problems with the attempt (below), are there tweaks that can be applied in order to salvage the general approach?

Here's the code, along with a demo `main()` function. In this case, the varargs arguments all have to be ints:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARG_ARRAY(...) ((int[]) { __VA_ARGS__ })
#define ARG_COUNT(...) (sizeof (ARG_ARRAY(__VA_ARGS__)) / sizeof (int))

#define STUFF(label, ...) \
    stuff(label, ARG_COUNT(__VA_ARGS__), ARG_ARRAY(__VA_ARGS__))

void stuff(char *label, int count, int *values) {
    printf("[%s] count %d", label, count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s %d", (i == 0) ? ":" : ",", values[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int return1(void) {
    printf("Called `return1()`.\n");
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    STUFF("blort");
    STUFF("frotz", return1());
    STUFF("fizmo", 2 + 3, 6 + 1);
    STUFF("glorf", 99, 999, 999);
    STUFF("igram", 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);
}
```

Here's a transcript:

```
[blort] count 0
Called `return1()`.
[frotz] count 1: 1
[fizmo] count 2: 5, 7
[glorf] count 3: 99, 999, 999
[igram] count 9: 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

The `return1()` printout is to verify that the function isn't called twice.

---

UPDATES:

It was pointed out in the comments that `(int[]) { args }` is C99 but not C++. In my case I can count on using a C compiler for the code in question, but it's still good to know this particular limitation.

It was pointed out in a now-deleted answer that C99 requires a varargs macro argument to be filled by at least one actual argument (though I think the spec is at best ambiguous in that regard). The compiler I have at hand (Clang on OS X) accepts the code with `-Wall` but does in fact complain with `-pedantic`, as @2501 aptly demonstrates in their comment.

`-pedantic` also complains about a zero size array (the no-args expansion `(int[]) { }`), though this could be fixed by always including a dummy element.

Comment: If you can use Boost.PP, do it. So much handy stuff with all the boilerplate done for you. It works in both C and C++.

Comment: `(int[]) { __VA_ARGS__ }`: That is a C99 compound-literal (if it's valid at all), no C++ equivalent existing.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, I can count on it being C code. I'll update the question.

Comment: @2501 Yes it did, using Clang on OS X.

Comment: Your code is not C. http://ideone.com/XyINb0

Comment: FWIW I'd've "accepted" the earlier answer, ensuing discussion notwithstanding.

Answer (score 1):

If the macro arguments are all valid and non-void expressions, you could try and use `decltype`, like so:

```
#include <tuple>
#define NARGS(...) std::tuple_size<decltype(std::make_tuple(__VA_ARGS__))>::value
```

The macro arguments are not evaluated. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Have "
              << NARGS("bar", 1, argc, 3, std::declval<int>())
              << " things\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, though my question isn't about alternatives, of which there are several available (one of which I noted). Rather, I want to specifically know about problems with this particular proposed solution. Also FWIW, in my immediate situation I do have to compile with a C compiler, not C++.

Comment: @danfuzz: Why did you tag the question C++?!

Comment: I originally thought the proposed solution would apply to both C and C++. I'll un-tag.

Comment: @chris: Can you do that in a way that doesn't evaluate the arguments?

Comment: Fair point. I can't think of anything off the top of my head without manually attaching `decltype` to each of them.