# Generating function declaration using a macro iteration

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, c99, variadic-macros

I'm trying to generate a function declaration using a macro

```
/* goal: generate int f(int a, float b) */
template<typename P>
struct ptype;

template<typename P>
struct ptype<void(P)> { typedef P type; };

#define NAMEe
#define COMMAe
#define COMMA ,

#define NAME(N) N PARAMS
#define PARAMS(P, ...) COMMA ## __VA_ARGS__ P NAME ## __VA_ARGS__
#define PARAM_ITER(P) P NAME

#define PROTO(R, N, P)  \
  ptype<void R>::type N (PARAM_ITER P (,e))

PROTO((int), f, (int)(a)(float)(b));
```

It will iteratively process the next `(name)` or `(type)` by `NAME` or `PARAMS` respectively, with the `...` having an empty macro argument. But GCC complains with

```
prototype.hpp:20:35: warning: ISO C99 requires rest arguments to be used
```

And clang complains with

```
ptype<void (int)>::type f (int aprototype.hpp:20:1: warning: varargs argument missing, but tolerated as an extension [-pedantic]
```

I think this happens because of the following

```
#define FOO(X, ...)
FOO(A);
```

Because I'm not passing an argument for the `...` or each of those `(name)` or `(type)`. Is there any simple work around I can apply?

---

I've now used a technique similar to the technique used by @James to find the length of a parameter list. If as second argument, instead of `O`, `ONT` is passed, I will print the comma and `NAME`. The following is the final solution:

```
/* goal: generate void f(int a, float b) */
template<typename P>
struct ptype;

template<typename P>
struct ptype<void(P)> { typedef P type; };

#define TYPE_DO(X) X
#define TYPE_DONT(X)
#define TYPE_MAYBE(X, A, ...) TYPE_D ## A (X)

#define COMMA_DO ,
#define COMMA_DONT
#define COMMA_MAYBE(A, B, ...) COMMA_D ## B

#define NAME_DO NAME
#define NAME_DONT
#define NAME_MAYBE(A, B, ...) NAME_D ## B

#define NAME(N) N PARAMS
#define PARAMS(...) COMMA_MAYBE(__VA_ARGS__,O,O) TYPE_MAYBE(__VA_ARGS__,O,O) \
                    NAME_MAYBE(__VA_ARGS__,O,O)
#define PARAM_ITER(P) P NAME

#define PROTO(R, N, P)  \
  ptype<void R>::type N (PARAM_ITER P (D,ONT))
```

Test:

```
#define STR1(X) #X
#define STR(X) STR1(X)

int main() {
  // prints correctly
  std::cout << STR(PROTO((int), f, (int)(a)(float)(b)));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/) has a macro that does exactly what you want, I think, namely `P99_PROTOTYPE`. It has a "signature" of

```
P99_PROTOTYPE(RT, NAME [, AT]*)
```

where `RT` is the return type (may be `void`) and `AT` are the argument types. The list of argument types may be empty, in which case it is substituted by `void`.

Beware that P99 is made for C99 and not for C++. You'll encounter particular difficulties if your arguments contain commas. C++'s syntax abuse of tokens `<` and `>` as bracketing expressions for templates is particularly bad for the preprocessor. C-preprocessor and C++ are basically incompatible languages on the syntax level.

P99 gets away from the difficulties that you are facing by detecting the number of arguments that the macro receives on a call and reacts differently on the border cases.

Comment: Yeah, the comma issue is actually why I put the return type into parentheses. So I could use the `void P` trick to get the type. I will look into `P99_PROTOTYPE` code and see how it does stuff. Thanks!

Comment: @Johannes, for the rare points that commas make difficulties in P99 I use `P00_ROBUST` to bracket the expression. This macro is just returning its argument list, but in the context of a macro expansion this has the advantage that the commas separating the arguments of `P00_ROBUST` are not counted for the arguments of the other macro. I am not sure if the C++ has the same evaluation order than the one of C99, so this might or might not work.

Answer (score 6):

To solve the "`FOO`" problem, you can select different macros depending on the arity of the variable arguments pack.  Here's a first shot at that:

```
// These need to be updated to handle more than three arguments:
#define PP_HAS_ARGS_IMPL2(_1, _2, _3, N, ...) N
#define PP_HAS_ARGS_SOURCE() MULTI, MULTI, ONE, ERROR

#define PP_HAS_ARGS_IMPL(...) PP_HAS_ARGS_IMPL2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PP_HAS_ARGS(...)      PP_HAS_ARGS_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__, PP_HAS_ARGS_SOURCE())

#define FOO_ONE(x)     ONE_ARG:    x
#define FOO_MULTI(...) MULTI_ARG:  __VA_ARGS__

#define FOO_DISAMBIGUATE2(has_args, ...) FOO_ ## has_args (__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOO_DISAMBIGUATE(has_args, ...) FOO_DISAMBIGUATE2(has_args, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOO(...) FOO_DISAMBIGUATE(PP_HAS_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)
```

Usage example:

```
FOO(1)     // replaced by ONE_ARG:   1
FOO(1, 2)  // replaced by MULTI_ARG: 1, 2
```

(I'll try to revisit this to clean it up; I think there are definitely some unneccessary macros in there.  I haven't had a chance to look into the broader problem that you describe, so I'm not sure if this solves that too.  There may be a simpler way to solve that problem, too... I'm not particularly familiar with variadic macros.  This preprocesses cleanly on mcpp.)