# Standard alternative to GCC's ##__VA_ARGS__ trick?

Tags: c, c99, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

There is a [well-known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054085/gcc-appending-to-va-args) [problem](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) with empty args for variadic macros in C99.

example:

```
#define FOO(...)       printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#define BAR(fmt, ...)  printf(fmt, __VA_ARGS__)

FOO("this works fine");
BAR("this breaks!");
```

The use of `BAR()` above is indeed incorrect according to the C99 standard, since it will expand to:

```
printf("this breaks!",);
```

Note the trailing comma - not workable.

Some compilers (eg: Visual Studio 2010) will quietly get rid of that trailing comma for you. Other compilers (eg: GCC) support putting `##` in front of `__VA_ARGS__`, like so:

```
#define BAR(fmt, ...)  printf(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

But is there a standards-compliant way to get this behavior?
Perhaps using multiple macros?

Right now, the `##` version seems fairly well-supported (at least on my platforms), but I'd really rather use a standards-compliant solution.

Pre-emptive: I know I could just write a small function. I'm trying to do this using macros.

**Edit**: Here is an example (though simple) of why I would want to use BAR():

```
#define BAR(fmt, ...)  printf(fmt "\n", ##__VA_ARGS__)

BAR("here is a log message");
BAR("here is a log message with a param: %d", 42);
```

This automatically adds a newline to my BAR() logging statements, assuming `fmt` is always a double-quoted C-string. It does NOT print the newline as a separate printf(), which is advantageous if the logging is line-buffered and coming from multiple sources asynchronously.

Comment: Why use `BAR` instead of `FOO` in the first place?

Comment: @GMan: I added an example at the end

Comment: In that case, you can just do a multi-statement macro with a `printf("\n");` at the end.

Comment: @GMan: Read the last sentence (:

Comment: This feature [has been proposed for inclusion](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2023.pdf) in C2x.

Comment: @Leushenko Would you happen to know the status of that proposal as of now (a bit more than a year later)?

Comment: @zwol the latest version submitted to WG14 [looks like this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2153.htm), which uses a new syntax based on the `__VA_OPT__` keyword. This [has already been "adopted"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/) by C++, so I expect C will follow suit. (don't know whether that means it was fast-tracked into C++17 or if it's set for C++20 though)

Comment: Followon from @AlexCeleste's comment above - \_\_VA_OPT\_\_ did not make it into C++17, but was indeed in C++20.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It is possible to avoid the use of GCC's `,##__VA_ARGS__` extension if you are willing to accept some hardcoded upper limit on the number of arguments you can pass to your variadic macro, as described in [Richard Hansen's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11172679/388520). If you do not want to have any such limit, however, to the best of my knowledge it is not possible using only C99-specified preprocessor features; you must use some extension to the language.  clang and icc have adopted this GCC extension, but MSVC has not.

Back in 2001 I wrote up the GCC extension for standardization (and the related extension that lets you use a name other than `__VA_ARGS__` for the rest-parameter) in [document N976](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n976.htm), but that received no response whatsoever from the committee; I don't even know if anyone read it.  In 2016 it was proposed again in [N2023](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2023.pdf), and I encourage anyone who knows how that proposal is going to let us know in the comments.

Comment: Judging by my disability to find a solution on the web and the lack of answers here, I guess you're right ):

Comment: Is [n976](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n976.htm) what you are referring to?  I searched the rest of the [C working group](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/)'s [documents](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/) for a response but never found one.  It wasn't even in the [agenda for the subsequent meeting](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n981.htm).  The only other hit on this topic was Norway's comment #4 in [n868](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n868.htm) back from before C99 was ratified (again with no follow-up discussion).

Comment: Yes, specifically the second half of that.  There may have been discussion on `comp.std.c` but I was unable to find any in Google Groups just now; it certainly never got any attention from the actual committee (or if it did, nobody ever told me about it).

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11742317/146041) to a related question there is a standard way to count the args to a macro.  I don't understand any of it though!

Comment: Do you have a proof as to why this is impossible in standard C?  I'm interested for theoretical reasons.  See [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474061/detect-presence-or-absence-of-arguments-in-a-c-macro) on the subject.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a proof, nor am I anymore the right person to try to think one up. I did write half of GCC's preprocessor, but that was more than ten years ago, and I'd never have thought of the argument-counting trick below, even then.

Comment: This extension works with clang & intel icc compilers, as well as gcc.

Answer (score 122):

There is an argument counting trick that you can use.

Here is one standard-compliant way to implement the second `BAR()` example in jwd's question:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define BAR(...) printf(FIRST(__VA_ARGS__) "\n" REST(__VA_ARGS__))

/* expands to the first argument */
#define FIRST(...) FIRST_HELPER(__VA_ARGS__, throwaway)
#define FIRST_HELPER(first, ...) first

/*
 * if there's only one argument, expands to nothing.  if there is more
 * than one argument, expands to a comma followed by everything but
 * the first argument.  only supports up to 9 arguments but can be
 * trivially expanded.
 */
#define REST(...) REST_HELPER(NUM(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)
#define REST_HELPER(qty, ...) REST_HELPER2(qty, __VA_ARGS__)
#define REST_HELPER2(qty, ...) REST_HELPER_##qty(__VA_ARGS__)
#define REST_HELPER_ONE(first)
#define REST_HELPER_TWOORMORE(first, ...) , __VA_ARGS__
#define NUM(...) \
    SELECT_10TH(__VA_ARGS__, TWOORMORE, TWOORMORE, TWOORMORE, TWOORMORE,\
                TWOORMORE, TWOORMORE, TWOORMORE, TWOORMORE, ONE, throwaway)
#define SELECT_10TH(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, ...) a10

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    BAR("first test");
    BAR("second test: %s", "a string");
    return 0;
}
```

This same trick is used to:

- [count the number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2124339/712605)
- [expand differently depending on the number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5355946/712605)
- [append to `__VA_ARGS__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204947/712605)

### Explanation

The strategy is to separate `__VA_ARGS__` into the first argument and the rest (if any).  This makes it possible to insert stuff after the first argument but before the second (if present).

#### `FIRST()`

This macro simply expands to the first argument, discarding the rest.

The implementation is straightforward.  The `throwaway` argument ensures that `FIRST_HELPER()` gets two arguments, which is required because the `...` needs at least one.  With one argument, it expands as follows:

1. `FIRST(firstarg)`
2. `FIRST_HELPER(firstarg, throwaway)`
3. `firstarg`

With two or more, it expands as follows:

1. `FIRST(firstarg, secondarg, thirdarg)`
2. `FIRST_HELPER(firstarg, secondarg, thirdarg, throwaway)`
3. `firstarg`

#### `REST()`

This macro expands to everything but the first argument (including the comma after the first argument, if there is more than one argument).

The implementation of this macro is far more complicated.  The general strategy is to count the number of arguments (one or more than one) and then expand to either `REST_HELPER_ONE()` (if only one argument given) or `REST_HELPER_TWOORMORE()` (if two or more arguments given).  `REST_HELPER_ONE()` simply expands to nothing -- there are no arguments after the first, so the remaining arguments is the empty set.  `REST_HELPER_TWOORMORE()` is also straightforward -- it expands to a comma followed by everything except the first argument.

The arguments are counted using the `NUM()` macro.  This macro expands to `ONE` if only one argument is given, `TWOORMORE` if between two and nine arguments are given, and breaks if 10 or more arguments are given (because it expands to the 10th argument).

The `NUM()` macro uses the `SELECT_10TH()` macro to determine the number of arguments.  As its name implies, `SELECT_10TH()` simply expands to its 10th argument.  Because of the ellipsis, `SELECT_10TH()` needs to be passed at least 11 arguments (the standard says that there must be at least one argument for the ellipsis).  This is why `NUM()` passes `throwaway` as the last argument (without it, passing one argument to `NUM()` would result in only 10 arguments being passed to `SELECT_10TH()`, which would violate the standard).

Selection of either `REST_HELPER_ONE()` or `REST_HELPER_TWOORMORE()` is done by concatenating `REST_HELPER_` with the expansion of `NUM(__VA_ARGS__)` in `REST_HELPER2()`.  Note that the purpose of `REST_HELPER()` is to ensure that `NUM(__VA_ARGS__)` is fully expanded before being concatenated with `REST_HELPER_`.

Expansion with one argument goes as follows:

1. `REST(firstarg)`
2. `REST_HELPER(NUM(firstarg), firstarg)`
3. `REST_HELPER2(SELECT_10TH(firstarg, TWOORMORE, TWOORMORE, TWOORMORE, TWOORMORE, TWOORMORE, TWOORMORE, TWOORMORE, TWOORMORE, ONE, throwaway), firstarg)`
4. `REST_HELPER2(ONE, firstarg)`
5. `REST_HELPER_ONE(firstarg)`
6. (empty)

Expansion with two or more arguments goes as follows:

1. `REST(firstarg, secondarg, thirdarg)`
2. `REST_HELPER(NUM(firstarg, secondarg, thirdarg), firstarg, secondarg, thirdarg)`
3. `REST_HELPER2(SELECT_10TH(firstarg, secondarg, thirdarg, TWOORMORE, TWOORMORE, TWOORMORE, TWOORMORE, TWOORMORE, TWOORMORE, TWOORMORE, TWOORMORE, ONE, throwaway), firstarg, secondarg, thirdarg)`
4. `REST_HELPER2(TWOORMORE, firstarg, secondarg, thirdarg)`
5. `REST_HELPER_TWOORMORE(firstarg, secondarg, thirdarg)`
6. `, secondarg, thirdarg`

Comment: Note that this will fail if you call BAR with 10 or more arguments, and though it's relatively easy to extend to more arguments, it will always have a upper bound on the number of arguments it can deal with

Comment: @ChrisDodd:  Correct.  Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a way to avoid a limit in the number of arguments without relying on compiler-specific extensions.  Also, I'm unaware of a way to reliably test if there are too many arguments (so that a useful compiler error message can be printed, rather than a strange failure).

Comment: Unfortunately, it works only with string arguments! BAR("val:%d", 1); fails to compile!

Answer (score 19):

Not a general solution, but in the case of printf you could append a newline like:

```
#define BAR_HELPER(fmt, ...) printf(fmt "\n%s", __VA_ARGS__)
#define BAR(...) BAR_HELPER(__VA_ARGS__, "")
```

I believe it ignores any extra args that aren't referenced in the format string. So you could probably even get away with:

```
#define BAR_HELPER(fmt, ...) printf(fmt "\n", __VA_ARGS__)
#define BAR(...) BAR_HELPER(__VA_ARGS__, 0)
```

I can't believe C99 was approved without a standard way to do this. AFAICT the problem exists in C++11 too.

Comment: the problem with this extra 0 is that it will actually end up in the code if it calls vararg function. Check for solution provided by Richard Hansen

Comment: @Pavel is correct about the second example, but the first works great. +1.

Answer (score 11):

There is a way to handle this specific case using something like [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/libs/preprocessor/).  You can use [BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE](http://www.boost.org/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/variadic_size.html) to check the size of the argument list, and then conditionaly expand to another macro.  The one shortcoming of this is that it can't distinguish between 0 and 1 argument, and the reason for this becomes clear once you consider the following:

```
BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE()      // expands to 1
BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(,)     // expands to 2
BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(,,)    // expands to 3
BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(a)     // expands to 1
BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(a,)    // expands to 2
BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(,b)    // expands to 2
BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(a,b)   // expands to 2
BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(a, ,c) // expands to 3
```

The empty macro argument list actually consists of one argument that happens to be empty.

In this case, we are lucky since your desired macro always has at least 1 argument, we can implement it as two "overload" macros:

```
#define BAR_0(fmt) printf(fmt "\n")
#define BAR_1(fmt, ...) printf(fmt "\n", __VA_ARGS__)
```

And then another macro to switch between them, such as:

```
#define BAR(...) \
    BOOST_PP_CAT(BAR_, BOOST_PP_GREATER(
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), 1))(__VA_ARGS__) \
    /**/
```

or

```
#define BAR(...) BOOST_PP_IIF( \
    BOOST_PP_GREATER(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), 1), \
        BAR_1, BAR_0)(__VA_ARGS__) \
    /**/
```

Whichever you find more readable (I prefer the first as it gives you a general form for overloading macros on the number of arguments).

It is also possible to do this with a single macro by accessing and mutating the variable arguments list, but it is way less readable, and is very specific to this problem:

```
#define BAR(...) printf( \
    BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_ELEM(0, __VA_ARGS__) "\n" \
    BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF( \
        BOOST_PP_GREATER(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__), 1)) \
    BOOST_PP_ARRAY_ENUM(BOOST_PP_ARRAY_POP_FRONT( \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_ARRAY(__VA_ARGS__)))) \
    /**/
```

Also, why is there no BOOST_PP_ARRAY_ENUM_TRAILING?  It would make this solution much less horrible.

Edit: Alright, here is a BOOST_PP_ARRAY_ENUM_TRAILING, and a version that uses it (this is now my favourite solution):

```
#define BOOST_PP_ARRAY_ENUM_TRAILING(array) \
    BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(BOOST_PP_ARRAY_SIZE(array)) BOOST_PP_ARRAY_ENUM(array) \
    /**/

#define BAR(...) printf( \
    BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_ELEM(0, __VA_ARGS__) "\n" \
    BOOST_PP_ARRAY_ENUM_TRAILING(BOOST_PP_ARRAY_POP_FRONT( \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_ARRAY(__VA_ARGS__)))) \
    /**/
```

Comment: Nice to learn about Boost.Preprocessor, +1.  Note that `BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE()` uses the same argument counting trick I documented in my answer, and has the same limitation (it will break if you pass more than a certain number of arguments).

Comment: Yep, I saw that your approach was the same one used by Boost, but the boost solution is very well maintained, and has a lot of other really useful features for use when developing more sophisticated macros.  The recursion stuff is particularly cool (and used behind the scenes in the last approach that uses BOOST_PP_ARRAY_ENUM).

Comment: A Boost answer that actually applies to the [tag:C] tag! Hooray!

Answer (score 11):

A very simple macro I'm using for debug printing:

```
#define DBG__INT(fmt, ...) printf(fmt "%s", __VA_ARGS__);
#define DBG(...) DBG__INT(__VA_ARGS__, "\n")

int main() {
        DBG("No warning here");
        DBG("and we can add as many arguments as needed. %s", "nice!");
        return 0;
}
```

No matter how many arguments are passed to DBG there are no c99 warning.

The trick is `DBG__INT` adding a dummy param so `...` will always have at least one argument and c99 is satisfied.

Comment: A small warning about this code, as written: the double-underscore in `__DBG_INT` is considered to be something that results in "undefined behavior". It's something that's *unlikely* to cause problems, but it's good to know about when writing things from scratch or refactoring--situations where it's easy to choose a different convention like `DBG_INT_` or `DBG__INT`.

Comment: Relevant snippets from the C11 standard (N1570), 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers:

"1. All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use."

"2. No other identifiers are reserved. If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined."

(Note: this also rules out something like `_DBG_INT`.)

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks. Is it considered undefined behavior also for C99?

Comment: You're welcome; I hope it helps. And yep, it is UB in C99 as well. It's the same section (7.1.3, p1 and p2) in C99/N1256. Best of luck!

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar problem recently, and I do believe there's a solution.

The key idea is that there's a way to write a macro `NUM_ARGS` to count the number of arguments which a variadic macro is given. You can use a variation of `NUM_ARGS` to build `NUM_ARGS_CEILING2`, which can tell you whether a variadic macro is given 1 argument or 2-or-more arguments. Then you can write your `Bar` macro so that it uses `NUM_ARGS_CEILING2` and `CONCAT` to send its arguments to one of two helper macros: one which expects exactly 1 argument, and another which expects a variable number of arguments greater than 1.

Here's an example where I use this trick to write the macro `UNIMPLEMENTED`, which is very similar to `BAR`:

**STEP 1:**

```
/** 
 * A variadic macro which counts the number of arguments which it is
 * passed. Or, more precisely, it counts the number of commas which it is
 * passed, plus one.
 *
 * Danger: It can't count higher than 20. If it's given 0 arguments, then it
 * will evaluate to 1, rather than to 0.
 */

#define NUM_ARGS(...)                                                   \
    NUM_ARGS_COUNTER(__VA_ARGS__, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13,       \
                     12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)    

#define NUM_ARGS_COUNTER(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7,        \
                         a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13,        \
                         a14, a15, a16, a17, a18, a19, a20, \
                         N, ...)                            \
    N
```

**STEP 1.5:**

```
/*
 * A variant of NUM_ARGS that evaluates to 1 if given 1 or 0 args, or
 * evaluates to 2 if given more than 1 arg. Behavior is nasty and undefined if
 * it's given more than 20 args.
 */

#define NUM_ARGS_CEIL2(...)                                           \
    NUM_ARGS_COUNTER(__VA_ARGS__, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, \
                     2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1)
```

**Step 2:**

```
#define _UNIMPLEMENTED1(msg)                                        \
    log("My creator has forsaken me. %s:%s:%d." msg, __FILE__,      \
        __func__, __LINE__)

#define _UNIMPLEMENTED2(msg, ...)                                   \
    log("My creator has forsaken me. %s:%s:%d." msg, __FILE__,      \
        __func__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

**STEP 3:**

```
#define UNIMPLEMENTED(...)                                              \
    CONCAT(_UNIMPLEMENTED, NUM_ARGS_CEIL2(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Where CONCAT is implemented in the usual way. As a quick hint, if the above seems confusing: the goal of CONCAT there is to expand to another macro "call".

Note that NUM_ARGS itself isn't used. I just included it to illustrate the basic trick here. See [Jens Gustedt's P99 blog](http://gustedt.wordpress.com/) for a nice treatment of it.

Two notes:

- NUM_ARGS is limited in the number of arguments that it handles. Mine
  can only handle up to 20, although the number is totally arbitrary.
- NUM_ARGS, as shown, has a pitfall in that it returns 1 when given 0 arguments. The gist of it is that NUM_ARGS is technically counting [commas + 1], and not args. In this
  particular case, it actually works to our
  advantage. _UNIMPLEMENTED1 will handle an empty token just fine
  and it saves us from having to write _UNIMPLEMENTED0. Gustedt has a
  workaround for that as well, although I haven't used it and I'm not sure if it would work for what we're doing here.

Comment: +1 for bringing up the argument counting trick, -1 for being really hard to follow

Comment: The comments you added were an improvement, but there are still a number of issues: 1. You discuss and define `NUM_ARGS` but don't use it. 2. What is the purpose of `UNIMPLEMENTED`?  3. You never solve the example problem in the question. 4. Walking through the expansion one step at a time would illustrate how it works and explain the role of each helper macro. 5. Discussing 0 arguments is distracting; the OP was asking about standards compliance, and 0 arguments is forbidden (C99 6.10.3p4). 6. Step 1.5?  Why not step 2? 7. "Steps" implies actions that occur sequentially; this is just code.

Comment: 8. You link to the whole blog, not the relevant post.  I couldn't find the post you were referring to. 9. The last paragraph is awkward:  This method **is** obscure; that's why nobody else had posted a correct solution before. Also, if it works and adheres to the standard, Zack's answer must be wrong. 10. You should define `CONCAT()` -- don't assume readers know how it works.

Comment: (Please don't interpret this feedback as an attack -- I really did want to upvote your answer but didn't feel comfortable doing so unless it was made easier to understand.  If you can improve the clarity of your answer, I'll upvote yours and delete mine.)

Comment: No, that was an honest question. I know that these macros can be hard. Since I already understand my post, I don't know which parts of it are confusing. Your approach is different in a useful way, so I think you shouldn't delete it. (It's more complicated in implementation, but it saves the user from having to define helper functions like _UNIMPLEMENTED1 and _UNIMPLEMENTED2 each time they want to use it).

Comment: I would never have thought of this approach, and I wrote roughly half of GCC's current preprocessor!  That said, I do still say that "there is no standard way to get this effect" because both your and Richard's techniques impose an upper limit on the number of arguments to the macro.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `gcc 8+`, `clang 6+` or `MSVC 2019` ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro_in_the_C_preprocessor#Support)), then you can also use the (newer) `__VA_OPT__` macro, which conditionally expands if `__VA_ARGS__` is non-empty.

So, we can convert the two `FOO` and `BAR` macros into one:

```c
#define FOO(s, ...) printf(s __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__)
```

and so, `FOO("hello!")` will expand to `printf("hello!")`, and `FOO("x = %d", 5)` will expand to `printf("x = %d", 5)`.

This is a relatively new feature (introduced in C++2a) so your compiler might not support it yet.

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplified version that I use.  It is based upon the great techniques of the other answers here, so many props to them:

```c
#define _SELECT(PREFIX,_5,_4,_3,_2,_1,SUFFIX,...) PREFIX ## _ ## SUFFIX

#define _BAR_1(fmt)      printf(fmt "\n")
#define _BAR_N(fmt, ...) printf(fmt "\n", __VA_ARGS__);
#define BAR(...) _SELECT(_BAR,__VA_ARGS__,N,N,N,N,1)(__VA_ARGS__)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    BAR("here is a log message");
    BAR("here is a log message with a param: %d", 42);
    return 0;
}
```

**That's it.**

As with other solutions this is limited to the number of arguments the macro.  To support more, add more parameters to `_SELECT`, and more `N` arguments.  The argument names count down (instead of up) to serve as a reminder that the count-based `SUFFIX` argument is provided in reverse order.

This solution treats 0 arguments as though it is 1 argument.  So `BAR()` nominally "works", because it expands to `_SELECT(_BAR,,N,N,N,N,1)()`, which expands to `_BAR_1()()`, which expands to `printf("\n")`.

If you want, you can get creative with the use of `_SELECT` and provide different macros for different number of arguments.  For example, here we have a LOG macro that takes a 'level' argument before the format.  If format is missing, it logs "(no message)", if there is just 1 argument, it will log it through "%s", otherwise it will treat the format argument as a printf format string for the remaining arguments.

```
#define _LOG_1(lvl)          printf("[%s] (no message)\n", #lvl)
#define _LOG_2(lvl,fmt)      printf("[%s] %s\n", #lvl, fmt)
#define _LOG_N(lvl,fmt, ...) printf("[%s] " fmt "\n", #lvl, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOG(...) _SELECT(_LOG,__VA_ARGS__,N,N,N,2,1)(__VA_ARGS__)

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    LOG(INFO);
    LOG(DEBUG, "here is a log message");
    LOG(WARN, "here is a log message with param: %d", 42);
    return 0;
}
/* outputs:
[INFO] (no message)
[DEBUG] here is a log message
[WARN] here is a log message with param: 42
*/
```

Comment: This still triggers a warning when compiled with -pedantic.

Answer (score 2):

if c++11 or above is available, and the macro is intended to be expanded to a function call, you can make a wrapper for it, for example:
`#define BAR(fmt, ...) printf(fmt, __VA_ARGS__)`
can be converted to
`#define BAR(fmt, ...) BAR_wrapper(fmt)(__VA_ARGS__)`
where `BAR_wrapper` can be defined as:

```
struct BAR_wrapper_t {
  BAR_wrapper_t(const char* fmt) : fmt(fmt) {}
  const char* fmt;
  int operator()() const { return printf(fmt); }
  template <typename... Args>
  int operator()(Args&& args) const { return printf(fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
};
inline BAR_wrapper_t BAR_wrapper(const char* fmt) { return BAR_wrapper_t(fmt); }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your situation (at least 1 argument present, never 0), you can define `BAR` as `BAR(...)`, use [Jens Gustedt's](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/detect-empty-macro-arguments/) `HAS_COMMA(...)` to detect a comma and then dispatch to `BAR0(Fmt)` or `BAR1(Fmt,...)` accordingly.

This:

```
#define HAS_COMMA(...) HAS_COMMA_16__(__VA_ARGS__, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
#define HAS_COMMA_16__(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, ...) _15
#define CAT_(X,Y) X##Y
#define CAT(X,Y) CAT_(X,Y)
#define BAR(.../*All*/) CAT(BAR,HAS_COMMA(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)
#define BAR0(X) printf(X "\n")
#define BAR1(X,...) printf(X "\n",__VA_ARGS__)


#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    BAR("here is a log message");
    BAR("here is a log message with a param: %d", 42);
}
```

compiles with `-pedantic` without a warning.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 762 bytes

```c
#define EMPTYFIRST(x,...) A x (B)
#define A(x) x()
#define B() ,

#define EMPTY(...) C(EMPTYFIRST(__VA_ARGS__) SINGLE(__VA_ARGS__))
#define C(...) D(__VA_ARGS__)
#define D(x,...) __VA_ARGS__

#define SINGLE(...) E(__VA_ARGS__, B)
#define E(x,y,...) C(y(),)

#define NONEMPTY(...) F(EMPTY(__VA_ARGS__) D, B)
#define F(...) G(__VA_ARGS__)
#define G(x,y,...) y()

#define STRINGIFY(...) STRINGIFY2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define STRINGIFY2(...) #__VA_ARGS__

#define BAR(fmt, ...) printf(fmt "\n" NONEMPTY(__VA_ARGS__) __VA_ARGS__)

int main() {
    puts(STRINGIFY(NONEMPTY()));
    puts(STRINGIFY(NONEMPTY(1)));
    puts(STRINGIFY(NONEMPTY(,2)));
    puts(STRINGIFY(NONEMPTY(1,2)));

    BAR("here is a log message");
    BAR("here is a log message with a param: %d", 42);
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZFfS4RAFMXf/RQXl2AGZoWkp3rS9Q9CWagEQSDijq6QJmrkEn12m1XXmQHb9c17z/2dc5h0m6fpMGz2NCsqCvbTS/TmeEEYoZ5omobBgB6QiZWzwkA9hh7xgYkwEEWRCGg83SEBF8evRmwEbhjHGELPdx9tacaBu@naktbL1joHE7bcfQaPAolPQOhgM8aRzBmPCBPMCf6zL1RwpgpyekuCOZPSXY/rcitmJASNAhbVc2af5Vdfxwj7Ub9ZbW8aAcrKjsCoqZui6rLTANT3SuXNpDKSncIuoEyKir3pjwLsq7@6FvGwCwNj/HBRcHtVQfTrkFkzik7t1ANtKBQtJPDxmUNJ2zbJqTpj/lfAd9Ed2KhOmqS8h5u9SuBOZ2e/w/AH)

Assumes:

- No arg contain comma or bracket
- No arg contain `A`~`G` (can rename to hard_collide ones)

Comment: The `no arg contain comma` limitation may be bypassed by checking multi after some more passes, but `no bracket` still there

Answer (score -2):

The standard solution is to use `FOO` instead of `BAR`. There are a few weird cases of argument reordering it probably can't do for you (though I bet someone can come up with clever hacks to disassemble and reassemble `__VA_ARGS__` conditionally based on the number of arguments in it!) but in general using `FOO` "usually" just works.

Comment: The question was "is there a standards-compliant way to get this behavior?"

Comment: And the question has included a rationale for not using FOO for ages now.

Comment: How is your answer helping in any way?