# How to define same macro function based on different parameters

Tags: c++, macros

```
#define UPUT_SET_CHECK_POINT1(appType, tag, argNum1, v1, ...)  \

if(NUMARGS(##__VA_ARGS__) == 0)           \
UPUT_SET_CHECK_POINTx(1, appType, tag,  argNum1, v1,  UPUT_P_INVALID, 0, UPUT_P_INVALID, 0, UPUT_P_INVALID, 0, UPUT_P_INVALID, 0, __FILE__, __LINE__, UPUT_SEQUENTIAL);                   \
else                                     \
UPUT_SET_CHECK_POINTx(1, appType, tag,  argNum1, v1,  UPUT_P_INVALID, 0, UPUT_P_INVALID, 0, UPUT_P_INVALID, 0, UPUT_P_INVALID, 0, __FILE__, __LINE__ , __VA_ARGS__)
```

so when **VA_ARGS** is empty I am getting a compile time error "expected primary-expression before ')' token". Any way to fix the compilation error.

```
void UPUT_SET_CHECK_POINTx(int numArg, CtblAppType appType, int tag, UputArgPos argNum1, int v1, UputArgPos argNum2, int v2, UputArgPos argNum3, int v3, UputArgPos argNum4, int v4, UputArgPos argNum5, int v5, char* fileName, unsigned int lineNumber, UputCheckPointAlgo checkPointAlgo=UPUT_SEQUENTIAL);
```

Comment: Can't you just do it with templates instead?

Comment: Seems a rather compilcated and unreadable way of doing whatever you are trying to do. There would be a simpler, type safe and easier to read solution.

Comment: UPUT_SET_CHECK_POINT1 was a function which is present in 2 thousand files and I don't want to touch that files so I thought to make it to macro and replacing with a function UPUT_SET_CHECK_POINTx

Comment: @PawanKumarSrivastava - you can still do that just as well with templates most likely

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using GCC, [you could use `, ## __VA_ARGS__`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) to eliminate the comma when `__VA_ARGS__` is empty.

```
#define UPUT_SET_CHECK_POINT1(appType, tag, argNum1, v1, ...)  \
    UPUT_SET_CHECK_POINTx(1, appType, tag,  argNum1, v1, \
                          UPUT_P_INVALID, 0, \
                          UPUT_P_INVALID, 0, \
                          UPUT_P_INVALID, 0, \
                          UPUT_P_INVALID, 0, \
                          __FILE__, __LINE__ , ## __VA_ARGS__)
```

See also [Standard alternative to GCC's ##__VA_ARGS__ trick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588855/standard-alternative-to-gccs-va-args-trick). There's no standard workaround to this if you have to use preprocessors.