# C++ Preprocessor macro loop __VA_ARGS__ 1 vs 2+ arguments

Tags: c++, macros

I'm using the macros from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872220/is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-arguments-in-variadic-macros) looping through my arguments. Everything works great! However, is there a way to combine these two `CCB_CREATE` and `CCB_CREATE_MORE`?

I need to extract the first argument `object_type` to write additional code. The additional `object_type`s will be using the `FOR_EACH` loop to insert into the map.

The compiler complaints when I only have one argument when using `CCB_CREATE_MORE(Type1)`. To fix that I made another macro to handle that `CCB_CREATE(Type1)`. Hoping to find a clever solution to combine these two into one elegant macro. Any ideas?

```
#define INSERT_LOADER_MAP(object_type) loader_map.insert(make_pair(#object_type, object_type##Loader::loader()))


#define CCB_CREATE_MORE(object_type,...) \
static CCNode * create##object_type##Node() { \
    std::map<std::string, CCNodeLoader*> loader_map; \
    std::string classname = #object_type; \
    FOR_EACH(INSERT_LOADER_MAP,object_type,__VA_ARGS__); \
    return loadCCBFile((classname + ".ccbi").c_str(), loader_map); \
}


#define CCB_CREATE(object_type) \
static CCNode * create##object_type##Node() { \
    std::map<std::string, CCNodeLoader*> loader_map; \
    std::string classname = #object_type; \
    INSERT_LOADER_MAP(object_type); \
    return loadCCBFile((classname + ".ccbi").c_str(), loader_map); \
}
```

Comment: I don't recommend using `__type__`. It's a reserved identifier.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Just did a search and replace on that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler is likely complaining about the trailing comma when the variadic arguments list is empty.  GCC and Visual Studio compilers support the non-standard extension `##__VA_ARGS__` to suppress the trailing comma:

```
#define FOO(fmt, ...) printf(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

The Visual Studio compilers will also suppress the trailing comma even without the `##` extension.

See GCC documentation [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html), and Visual Studio documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177415.aspx).

If you need a standards-compliant solution, there is one detailed in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588855/standard-alternative-to-gccs-va-args-trick).

So if you are using either gcc or Visual Studio, you should be able to use your original macro with this simple change:

```
#define CCB_CREATE(object_type,...) \
static CCNode * create##object_type##Node() { \
    std::map<std::string, CCNodeLoader*> loader_map; \
    std::string classname = #object_type; \
    FOR_EACH(INSERT_LOADER_MAP,object_type,##__VA_ARGS__); \
    return loadCCBFile((classname + ".ccbi").c_str(), loader_map); \
}
```

**Edit:**
You would need to use the `##__VA_ARGS__` extension in the `FOR_EACH()` macro as well, or the more elegant modification suggested by ugoren.

```
#define FOR_EACH(what, x, ...) FOR_EACH_(FOR_EACH_NARG(x, ##__VA_ARGS__), what, x, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Chris Olsen's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19474943/1111371), a slight change to the `FOR_EACH` macro is needed:

```
#define FOR_EACH(what, ...) FOR_EACH_(FOR_EACH_NARG(__VA_ARGS__), what, __VA_ARGS__)
```

As a result, `FOR_EACH(X, a)` will become `X(a)` (instead of `X(a); X();`). This eliminates an empty `INSERT_LOADER_MAP` invocation.