# Detect presence or absence of arguments in a C macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

How can one define a C macro `IFARGS(YES, NO, ...)` such that invoking `IFARGS` with no additional arguments produces `NO`, and invoking `IFARGS` with one or more arguments produces `YES`?

I have an answer using GCC (see below), but I'd prefer one for C99 if possible (or a proof of its impossibility).

Answer (score 6):

In C99 it is possible to detect if a macro argument is empty, but making that robust against all odds that may appear in that argument (arguments that are themselves expanding, contain `()` and stuff like that) is difficult. My macro package [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr) implements such a thing, so you wouldn't have to worry too much. With that your macro can be implemented as

```
#define IFARGS(YES, NO, ...) P99_IF_EMPTY(__VA_ARGS__)(YES(__VA__ARGS__))(NO())
```

As its name indicates, P99 is only building on C99 features for that.

Comment: How can one detect an empty argument in C99?

Comment: @augurar, this one is in the top search on my favorite search engin :) http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/detect-empty-macro-arguments/

Comment: Interesting; however, the `ISEMPTY` macro in that post appears to fail when given exactly 16 arguments.

Comment: After some investigation, I see that `P99_IF_EMPTY` works for 16 arguments, but has some theoretical maximum number of arguments (`P99_MAX_NUMBER`).  So this is another good partial solution.

Comment: Well the current value of `P99_MAX_NUMBER` and the restriction of `P99_IF_EMPTY` (in P99) is at `152` or so, and easily extendable if needed. In any case, the maximum number of macro arguments that a platform *must* accept is 128 or so. It may accept more, but I think writing code with more arguments than that should be somewhat exotic.

Comment: For real-world applications, this is a great solution.  I'm still interested in the theoretical question of whether `##__VA_ARGS__` actually adds any "power" to the macro language, or whether it's just a convenience feature.

Comment: @augurar, then why didn't you ask *that* question?

Answer (score 2):

```
#define GET(_0, _1) _0  // Return the first of two arguments
#define GET_(_0, _1) _1  // Return the second of two arguments

#define JOIN(_0, _1) _0 ## _1  // Concatenate two arguments
#define EJOIN(_0, _1) JOIN(_0, _1)  // Expand macros and concatenate

#define FIRST(_, ...) _  // Truncate everything after first comma
#define EFIRST(_) FIRST(_)  // Expand argument and pass to FIRST

#define REST(_0, ...) __VA_ARGS__  // Remove everything before first comma

#define GET_GET(...) \
    EJOIN(GET, EFIRST(REST(,,##__VA_ARGS__ _)))  // Branch between GET and GET_

#define IFARGS(YES, NO, ...) GET_GET(__VA_ARGS__)(YES, NO)
```

Note that if this were possible in C99, then it would be possible to simulate `##__VA_ARGS__`, like so:

```
#define PREPEND_COMMA(...) , __VA_ARGS__
#define NO_COMMA()
#define PREPEND_COMMA_IF_NONEMPTY(...) IFARGS(PREPEND_COMMA, NO_COMMA, __VA_ARGS__)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Then any instance of `, ##__VA_ARGS__` could be replaced by `PREPEND_COMMA_IF_NONEMPTY(__VA_ARGS__)`.

Comment: This is not really an answer, but merely a complement to your own question.

Comment: @JensGustedt  The first code box is a partial solution -- it has the desired behavior, but requires `##__VA_ARGS__`, which is a GCC extension to C99 macro syntax.

Comment: I noticed that. A little bit of research on SO could have revealed you an answer to that. See the link above.

Comment: @I don't understand.  My answer shows that `##__VA_ARGS__` and `IFARGS` are equivalent in power, since with one you can emulate the other.  However, this is a nontrivial fact (unless I'm overlooking some easier solution).

Comment: This might be, but that is not your original question. And I don't think that it has much of a relevance, since that gcc extension is something that can be avoided in most cases with tricks that are simpler than that.

Comment: @JensGustedt  Please, if you can think of an implementation of `IFARGS` that does not require GCC, post it here!!  That would be really cool, because as I have proven above, *any* macro that can be implemented with `##__VA_ARGS__` can be implemented with `IFARGS`.

Comment: I did that, didn't you see my answer? If you want that reference to `P99_IF_EMPTY` expanded, you'd have to do that by yourself. I don't find your interface `IFARGS` interesting enough for me to do that myself.