# C Macro Stringify Only If Argument is Present

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am trying to figure out how to write a preprocessor macro which will "stringify" its argument only if an argument is present

For example:

```
STRINGIFY(foo) -> "foo"
STRINGIFY() ->
```

In my very basic example:

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
```

Calling STRINGIFY() results in "" rather than nothing at all (which is what I want)

How can this be achieved?

**EDIT**

As An example of why I want this behavior, I am using the macro to generate an initializer for an array of strings as such

```
const char* STRINGS[] = {MAP_LIST(STRINGIFY, __VA_ARGS__)};
```

Where MAP_LIST comes from the following project: https://github.com/swansontec/map-macro

If my **VA_ARGS** lsit has items in it, you end up with, for example, the following:

```
const char* STRINGS[] = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

But if **VA_ARGS** is empty, I end up with:

```
const char* STRINGS[] = {""};
```

Because, when you "stringify" an empty argument, it gives you an empty string.

Comment: How would you use this in the non-string case?

Comment: Why would you call it without an argument?

Comment: @Barmar See my edit

Comment: That seems more like a problem with `MAP_LIST()`. It doesn't handle an empty list properly, it calls the function once.

Comment: Um... 0 sized arrays are illegal. You are basically working hard to obtain an invalid declaration.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Dang... I didn't even think about that... Perhaps a better approach is in order.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica are they illegal. I think in ANSI-C only

Comment: If a function-like macro is declared to accept an argument, then you literally *cannot* invoke it without one.  If there are no tokens between the parentheses in the invocation of such a macro then the argument consists of zero tokens, and stringifying that gets you an empty string.

Comment: You can take inspiration from P99 FOR implementation (see [here](https://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/p99__for_8h_source.html#l00084) ): you need only to implement FOR_0 and FOR_1, where FUNC is your stringigicatsion macro. If I have time I will write an example

Comment: @0___________, every version of the C language specification disallows zero-length arrays.  Some implementations (notably GCC) accept them as an extension.

Comment: So what you like instead of `const char* STRINGS[] = {""};` ? `const char* STRINGS[] = ???`

Comment: Is this a duplciate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474061/detect-presence-or-absence-of-arguments-in-a-c-macro ?

Answer (score 1):

> how to write a preprocessor macro which will "stringify" its argument only if an argument is present

You can do a variadic macro and put a macro with `()` that will expand to a comma (or specific count of commas) and put `__VA_ARGS__` between that macro and `()` and then overload on the count of arguments.

```
#define TRIGGER_PARENTHESIS(...)  ,
#define STRINGIFY_0()
#define STRINGIFY_1(a)  #a
#define STRINGIFY_N2(_0,_1,N,...) STRINGIFY_##N
#define STRINGIFY_N(...) STRINGIFY_N2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define STRINGIFY(...) STRINGIFY_N(TRIGGER_PARENTHESIS __VA_ARGS__ (),0,1)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

See [A way to count the number of __VA_ARGS__ arguments, including 0, without compiler specific constructs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66556552/a-way-to-count-the-number-of-va-args-arguments-including-0-without-compile) for a more roboust method.

With a compiler with `__VA_OPT__` and in newer C++, it's just:

```
#define STRINGIFY(...) __VA_OPT__(#__VA_ARGS__)
```

---

As noted in the comments, your use case is invalid. If the result of `MAP_LIST(STRINGIFY, __VA_ARGS__)` would be empty, then it would result in:

```
const char* STRINGS[] = {};
```

which is invalid C code, because [Is an empty initializer list valid C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589533/is-an-empty-initializer-list-valid-c-code) and [What happens if I define a 0-size array in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722632/what-happens-if-i-define-a-0-size-array-in-c-c) . Both zero sized arrays and empty initializer lists are extensions in GNU C compiler.