# Expand parameter list in C

Tags: objective-c, c, variadic-functions

I am using a C library in my Objective C project. The C library offers the following function

```
void processData(...);
```

which can be used with 1, 2 or 3 parameters, where the first parameter is mandatory and can have different types `int`, `double`, `long`, `float` and the other two arguments are optional and have `int` and `long` values and can be in whatever order.

Examples of use of this function are:

```
int myInt = 2;
double myDouble = 1.23;
int dataQuality = 1;
long dataTimestamp= GET_NOW();

processData(myInt);
processData(myInt, dataQuality);
processData(myDouble, dataQuality, dataTimestamp);
processData(myDouble, dataTimestamp);
```

I need to make an Objetive C wrapper that uses `DataType` class to call `processData`with the correct parameters. The `Data` class has getters that allows to get the data type (first argument), its value and whether the second and third arguments have value and their value.

The problem is **how to make this expansion**? I think it must be done at compile time, and I think the only mechanism available in C to do so is macros. But I have never used them. The implementation should be something like this (the following is pseudocode, where the arguments list is evaluated at runtime, something that I guess should be replaced by macros in order to evaluate the arguments at compile time):

```
-(void) objetiveCProcessData: (Data) d {
      argumentList = {}
      switch (d.getDataType()) {
         case INT_TYPE:
              append(argumentList, d.getValueAsInt()); // <-- appends a value with type `int`
              break;
         case DOUBLE_TYPE:
              append(argumentList, d.getValueAsDouble()); // <-- appends a value with type `double`
              break;
         ...
      }

      if (d.hasQuality()) {
           append(argumentList, d.getQuality());
      }

      if (d.hasTimeStamp()) {
           append(argumentList, d.getTimestamp());
      }

      // Call to the C function with correct number and type of arguments
      processData(argumentList);          
}
```

Comment: i might be mistaken, but... it seems like what you need is a macro in standard c99 to allow 'varargs' to a c function? maybe this is a good lead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588855/standard-alternative-to-gccs-va-args-trick or this? https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11b.html

Comment: if the `Data` class has getters, and if you rely on calling the getters, then i do not see how you could accomplish that at compile time. (??)