# How to write a vfprintf wrapper that adds a prefix to format specifier and passes the new format specifier to vfprintf in C89?

Tags: c, argument-passing, c89

I am trying to write a wrapper around `vfprintf` function but with the requirement that I want to add a prefix to the format specifier and then pass the new format specifier to `vfprintf`.

Now I don't know how to do this, but I have captured my intention in the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void err(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vfprintf(stderr, "foo: error:" format, args);
    va_end(args);
}

int main()
{
    err("%s: %d\n", "Transaction failed with error code", 42);
    return 0;
}
```

You can see in the above code, that I want to prefix `"foo: error"` to the format specifier and then pass it to `vprintf`. This code, of course, would lead to compile time error because this code is not valid. It only captures my intention of what I am trying to achieve.

```
lone@debian:~/lab/c$ gcc -std=c89 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic vfprintf-wrapper.c 
vfprintf-wrapper.c: In function ‘err’:
vfprintf-wrapper.c:8:36: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘format’
     vfprintf(stderr, "foo: error:" format, args);
                                    ^
vfprintf-wrapper.c:8:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘vfprintf’
     vfprintf(stderr, "foo: error:" format, args);
     ^
```

Can you help me to write this code correctly?

Comment: Looks like a needlessly complicated thing to do. Why not just print the error prefix in a separate statement inside the wrapper, and then call vprintf as is?

Comment: @n.m. That is a perfectly valid way to do things, however, I want to learn if what I am asking is possible and how to do it.

Comment: Of course, it is possible. Just create a new format string ( malloc and a couple of strcpys would do it). But it is likely not the most efficient solution.

Comment: What you can't do is add more arguments to the varargs list.

Comment: `prog` is a mystery variable not accounted for in `err("%s: %d\n", "Transaction failed with error code", 42)`  What is ir? What is code trying to do with it?

Comment: Sorry, the `prog` was present there by mistake. I have removed it now. The `err` is an example call to demonstrate how I want to call the wrapper function.

Comment: one way is to declare a buffer that is the length of the current format string+the length of the part you want to prepend.  clear that buffer to all '\0'.  Then strcat the prepend value then strcat the original format string. Use a pointer to the new format string in the call to vfprintf()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pseudocode `vfprintf(stderr, "foo: error:" format, args);` should be:

```
fprintf(stderr, "foo: error:");
vfprintf(stderr, format, args);
```

You seem to be indicating that you want to avoid the "extra" `fprintf` call. If so then you could do this:

```
char *fail = malloc(sizeof "foo: error:" + strlen(format));
if ( !fail )
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
strcpy(fail, "foo: error:");
strcat(fail, format);

vfprintf(stderr, fail, args);

free(fail);
```

although that would be a waste of time and resource.

Comment: It seems a pity to write `if (!fail) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` — if you didn't fail, exit with failure. Maybe a better choice of variable name would be `msg_format`, or `msgfmt` or something like that.

Comment: Oh, you inherited the `prog` name from the older version of the question.  I think it is just an interloper, or should be interpolated into the format as part of the string: `char *msgfmt = malloc(sizeof(": error: ") + strlen(prog) + strlen(format); sprintf(msgfmt, "%s: error: %s", prog, format); vfprintf(stderr, msgfmt, args);` (ignoring the necessary error check after `malloc()`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler oops,I read that off his error messages and didn't match it up to the actual code (which it doesn't match as you say).  Yeah, `fail` is a dumb name for a pointer variable, that was intentional..:)

Comment: The second solution is more robust against threads, but I'd love to avoid using `malloc`. Any good ideas?

Comment: @syockit yeah, use the first one. Nothing wrong with two calls to fprintf.  If you are multithreaded and want to avoid interleaving from different threads writing to `stderr` simultaneously then you should use a mutex to surround writes to `stderr`.

Comment: @syockit: if the caller is passing a string literal as the "format" arg (which is typical), then you can use a macro to expand `LOG("format", args...)` to `printf("prefix" "format", args...)`. The case where there are no args gets a little harder to do cross-platform, though. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588855/standard-alternative-to-gccs-va-args-trick)