# C variadic macro with two named parameters

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I want to use a variadic macro but it appears to be designed to only treat the first parameter specially. I want the first two parameters to be named and the rest not, like so:

```
#define FOO(AA,BB,...) AA->BB(AA,##...)

FOO(mystruct,funcname,123)
```

However this is not working with LLVM. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a limitation to how the variadic macro works?

---

UPDATE

The correct answer is, use ##**VA_ARGS** instead of ##...

There are some webpages that claim that "..." is valid but at least with the MacOS llvm it is not.

Comment: What is it that you *intend* to achieve here? What is the *expected* expansion of that macro? Do you know what `##` even does? What is the error message you got?

Answer (score 1):

The macro arguments are not expanded with `...` in the macro expansion - how could they, because then you couldn't have a macro that used ellipsis in the expansion. Instead it will be available as a special parameter `__VA_ARGS__`.

With this, the following program

```
#define FOO(AA,BB,...) AA->BB(AA, __VA_ARGS__)

FOO(mystruct,funcname,123)
FOO(mystruct,funcname,123,456)
```

[will be preprocessed to](https://godbolt.org/z/-hp8pM)

---

The `##` is a token-pasting operator. It will make a single preprocessing token out of 2 parts. `, ## ...` attempts to make a preprocessing token `,...`. It is not a valid C token, and that is why Clang will report

```
<source>:3:1: error: pasting formed ',...', an invalid preprocessing token
```

Comment: I need to use  ##__VA_ARGS__. Your solution covers the >=1 params cases but not 0.

Comment: I don't know why I was seeing webpages claiming that "..." would work. I used to have the original C programming book-- that would have been a better source of truth than blogs.

Comment: @popoe that's a [GNU extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206118/va-args-not-swallowing-comma-when-zero-args-under-c99)

Comment: @popoe: variadic macros aren't described at all in K&R, because the original C didn't have variadic macros. They were added in C99, although they were already implemented as a gcc extension. Afaik, `...` has never been used to indicate where varargs should be expanded. At least, not in C.

Answer (score 1):

`...` macro arguments are pasted into macro bodies with `__VA_ARGS__`.
The problem is how to allow for it to be empty.
If it is empty, you'll usually want to comma before it erased and
you can use the `GNU ##__VA_ARGS__` extension to achieve that.

```
#define FOO(AA,BB,...) AA->BB(AA,##__VA_ARGS__) /*GNU extension*/
FOO(mystruct,funcname) //warning with -pedantic
FOO(mystruct,funcname,123)
```

The above, however, will trigger warnings if compiled with `-pedantic`.
If you want your macro usable without warnings at `-pedantic`, you could perhaps achieve that by swapping the first two arguments in the macro definition.

```
#define FIRST(...)  FIRST_(__VA_ARGS__,)
#define FIRST_(X,...) X
#define BAR_(CallExpr,...) CallExpr(__VA_ARGS__)
#define BAR(BB,/*AA,*/...) BAR_(FIRST(__VA_ARGS__)->BB,__VA_ARGS__)

BAR(funcname,mystruct) //no warning
BAR(funcname,mystruct,123)
```