# variadic macro - optional initializer expression

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

I want a `macro` that declares an `int` with a given name and optional initializer expression.

I tried using [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11172679/3162383) but with no success.

This is what I tried:

```
#define macro(...) int FIRST(__VA_ARGS__)(REST(__VA_ARGS__))
```

when used like this there are no problems:

```
macro(foo);
```

but when given an initializer there are errors:

```
macro(foo, 42);
```

The alternative - of just using `__VA_ARGS__` gives a warning from `-pedantic` in GCC when there are no arguments.

How can I fix this?

And is it also possible to avoid the `()` braces when there is no initializer expression - meaning no zero initialization but default?

Note that my real use case is not just for `int` but for any type and using a third party like boost is not an option.

Comment: Using macros is something very few recommends as they tend to obfuscate code. Can you perhaps elaborate on the *original* problem you try to solve with this solution? *Why* are you using macros this way? Perhaps there are other ways to solve you solution, ways that doesn't depend on macros?

Comment: You can fix this by actually writing C++ code, instead of attempting to use this kind of a crufty, obsolete C syntax, and by using templates; which is the correct way to do this in C++. This is a very broad topic, not suitable for a brief answer; so what you need to do is open your C++ to the chapter that talks about templates, and start reading.

Comment: C++ is not powerful enough and thus I need to resort to macros for code generation. Thousands of projects depend on the preprocessor. I understand that this is not a pleasant problem to solve but I'm just asking for help - if I don't get it - its fine.

Comment: What is the point to do a macro for this use case?? `int foo=42;` is more explicit.

Comment: How do you *know* C++ "is not powerful enough"? How do *we* know? Your question is an example of [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), where you tell us about a solution you want fixed, but don't tell us what the solution is supposed to solve. And just because thousands of projects uses macros in a possible bad way doesn't mean you have to do the same.

Comment: C++ is quite powerful enough to me. Templates, with type-safety, will be far more powerful than simple preprocessor tricks.

Comment: Well this is just a small part of a huge macro which does a lot of things - and this is the final piece of the puzzle I need to solve... So many times I've been told to produce a minimal example - and when I do - the XY problem gets linked... wtf

Comment: Well, apart from the macro-ness, you also said _optional constructor arguments_ when `int` doesn't have a constructor (I think you mean _initializer expression_). So, it's reasonable for people to guess you're also mistaken about the need to do it this way.

Comment: @onqtam: Even if it's part of a huge macro, and for one reason or another that's not replaceable with a template, you still might be better of delegating this particular bit of functionality from the macro to a separate template.

Comment: @Useless I will correct that part.

Comment: *this is just a small part of a huge macro which does a lot of things*. This alone would frighten me... Macro language is indeed powerful, but also awful to write (syntax) and debug. Most C++ programmers actually think that templates can do much of what was done by macros in C. Maybe you could try to build a C extract of your requirements, and ask it in a new question with the C tag. You could find some *macro geeks* with C tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I ended up with the following: [link](https://gist.github.com/onqtam/2d07dac989eee2fd5ecc68ca37b14f03)

I forward the `__VA_ARGS__` to a variadic template because my problem wasn't exactly what I described here (as suggested in the comments) - but the problems when not supplying an initializer persisted - so I silenced the warnings in the header for GCC with `#pragma GCC system_header` and for Clang I used `_Pragma()` for `-Wgnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments`. MSVC wasn't a problem.

I also fell victim to the most vexing parse as @MSalters points out in his answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
#define macro(...) int FIRST(__VA_ARGS__){REST(__VA_ARGS__)}
```

Your chief problem is that `int foo();` is a function declaration. `int foo{};` isn't.

Comment: omg I had totally forgotten about the vexing parse - thanks for pointing it out!