# How to add an extra argument to a C++ log macro

Tags: c++, variadic-macros

Suppose I have below macro for logging

*TRACE(type, sub-type, message, fmt, args);*

Now I have a requirement to punch extra argument, say machine IP to this log:

```
#include <conio.h>

char *IP = "100.200.200.100";
#define TRACE(type, sub-type, message, fmt, args) do{ <<<< expands to func which logs to a file >>>> }while(0)

#define NEW_TRACE(type, sub-type, message, fmt, args) do { \
        TRACE (type, sub-type, message, fmt, ##args); \
    } while (0)

int main()
{
    char *w = "world!";
    NEW_TRACE("my-type", "my-subtype", 2, "Hello %s", w);
    return 0;
}
```

How do I write *NEW_TRACE* such that I punch the *'IP'* into the log?
Any thoughts!?

Comment: The macro expansion includes `<<<< expands to func which logs to a file >>>>`.     Why not modify the "func which logs to a file"?  No need to modify the macro at all.

Comment: Well, modifying the "func which logs to a file" isn't an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fmt is always string literal, this should work:

```
#define NEW_TRACE(type, sub-type, message, fmt, args) do { \
        TRACE (type, sub-type, message, "IP:%s " fmt, IP, ##args); \
    } while (0)
```

(Disclaimer: untested)

In C++, like C, you can just concatenate string literals, `"part1" "part2"`  is same as `"part1part2"`.

Comment: Since it's actually tagged C++ (despite being pure C so far), you can use `(std::string{"IP %s"}+fmt).c_str`. This will also concatenate ordinary C strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the macro with variable arguments to macro.

Existing => TRACE( x, y)

Extend => TRACE( x, y, ...)

```
e.g. #define TRACE(fmt, ...) printf(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Here [**VA_AGRS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124339/c-preprocessor-va-args-number-of-arguments), as well as [tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588855/standard-alternative-to-gccs-va-args-trick), can help.