# How to implement C/C++ variadic logging macro with __FILE__ and __LINE__ info for multiple platforms?

Tags: c++, c, macros, variadic-macros

I want to implement a C/C++ variadic logging macro, which contains `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` information.

This is my simple implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MYLOG(format, ...) printf("%s:%d " format, __VA_ARGS__)
```

The only issue is that, this macro doesn't compile when my logging has no parameters, for example:

```
MYLOG("hello world");
```

I've read some wikis and blogs, there's a solution for GCC compiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MYLOG(format, ...) printf("%s:%d " format, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

But is there a more standard way to implement this macro working on GCC/Clang/MSVC compilers?

Comment: What about simply using 2 different macros? `#define MYLOG(text) printf("%s:%d %s", __FILE__, __LINE__, text)` ... `#define MYLOG_FMT(format, ...) printf("%s:%d " format, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)` Call `MYLOG()` when you don't have format parameters, and call `MYLOG_FMT()` when you do.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, It really solve the issue, but I'm just looking for a killer solution.

Comment: Take a good look at [`#define` macro for debug printing in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1644868/15168) — it covers most of the territory you need, and includes passing reference to adding `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` information to the logging.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8673872/918959

Comment: Also there is no such language as C/C++. Either something is C or is not, something is C++ or not. A minority of code is in the **intersection**. What it is that you want?

Comment: You could use the [facil.io STL library logging macros (or copy them)](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/cef033faad21659ce20f95d910fe5c558a32ffc8/lib/facil/fio-stl.h#L698-L825)

Comment: P.S., there's [documentation as well](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/cef033faad21659ce20f95d910fe5c558a32ffc8/docs/_SOURCE/0.8.x/fio-stl.md#logging-and-assertions).

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports C++20 then there is a standard way to solve this problem using [`__VA_OPT__`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace). `__VA_OPT__(,)` will expand to a comma if `__VA_ARGS__` is not empty. So when `__VA_ARGS__` is empty, there's no extra comma and no compilation error.

```
#define MYLOG(format, ...) printf("%s:%d " format __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: It looks `__VA_OPT__` is the only standard way.