# C Macro Arguments including comma

Tags: c, macros, arguments

I would like to pass 2 arguments to a macro using another macro:

```
#define A_AND_B     5,1
#define ADD(a, b)   a + b

int add_them(void)
{
    int result = ADD(A_AND_B);
    return result ;
}
```

I would hope that expands to

```
int result = 5 + 1;
```

and I get 6. Instead I get

```
Error       'ADD' undeclared (first use in this function)   
Error       macro "ADD" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Standard alternative to GCC's ##\_\_VA\_ARGS\_\_ trick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588855/standard-alternative-to-gccs-va-args-trick)

Answer (score 3):

As is often the case, you need an extra level of (macro) indirection:

```c
#define A_AND_B     5,1
#define ADD(...)    ADD_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define ADD_(a, b)   a + b

int add_them(void)
{
    int result = ADD(A_AND_B);
    return result ;
}
```

`ADD` is defined as variadic so that it will work as either `ADD(A_AND_B)` or `ADD(A, B)`.

This works because `__VA_ARGS__` in the replacement body of `ADD` is replaced with the actual arguments before the replacement body is scanned for macros.

Comment: Variadic macros are, currently, non-standards... this is a GCC specific solution.  However, the forthcoming C2x will (hopefully) include something similar.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588855/standard-alternative-to-gccs-va-args-trick

Comment: @andrew: variadic macros have been in C since C99. The problem you reference is a that standardized variadic macros prior to C2x don't allow the variadic arguments to be omitted. That does not apply to this answer; my variadic macro is not intended to be invoked with no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Per C 2018 6.10.3.1, a compiler first identifies the arguments for a function-like macro and then performs macro replacement on the arguments, followed by macro replacement for the function-like macro. This means that, in `ADD(A_AND_B)`, the argument is identified as `A_AND_B` before it is replaced with `5,1`. As the macro invocation has only this single argument and the macro is defined to have two parameters, an error is diagnosed.

Given your definition of `ADD`, there is no way to change this behavior in a compiler that conforms to the C standard.

You can instead use another macro to expand the arguments and apply the desired macro:

```
#define Apply(Macro, Arguments) Macro(Arguments)
```

then `int result = Apply(ADD, A_AND_B);` will work. That will identify `ADD` and `A_AND_B` as arguments to `Apply`. Then it will expand those, producing an unchanged `ADD` and `5,1`. Then the macro replacement for `Apply` produces `ADD(5,1)`. Then this is again processed for macro replacement, which replaces `ADD(5,1)` in the ordinary way.

Note that good practice is usually to define `ADD` as `#define ADD(a, b)   ((a) + (b))` to avoid unexpected interactions with other operators neighboring the use of the macro.