# Variadic macros with zero arguments

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

I am working on a call macro,

```
#define CALL(f,...) FN(f)->call((ref(new LinkedList()), __VA_ARGS__))
```

which when called,

```
CALL(print,2,3,4,5);
```

adds 2 3 4 5 to the linked list (, is overloaded to do so) and calls print which expects a linked list which works as expected how ever there are some calls which do not require arguments,

```
CALL(HeapSize);
```

It still takes a linked list but an empty one, above does not work, I am trying to come up with a macro that woud work with either style?

EDIT: Digging throug gcc docs I found that adding ## before **VA_ARGS** removes the , when there are no arguments but with that I can not nest macros,

```
CALL(print,CALL(HeadSize));
```

this causes CALL not defined error how ever if I separate the the calls it works

Comment: You can have `CALL` delegate to different macros depending on the number of arguments it is passed. I demonstrated how to do this [in an answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355241/generating-function-declaration-using-a-macro-iteration/5355946#5355946).  This does not require any implementation-specific hacks.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588855/standard-alternative-to-gccs-va-args-trick

Comment: related blogpost: ["Detect empty macro arguments"](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/detect-empty-macro-arguments/).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As for the updated question, by the use of auxiliary macro `VA_ARGS` like
the following, the arguments will be expanded as expected.

```
#define VA_ARGS(...) , ##__VA_ARGS__
#define CALL(f,...) FN(f)->call((ref(new LinkedList()) VA_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__)))
```

Comment: P.S. This worked well in my case where I needed to add NULL at the end:
#define blah(x,...) actual(a,b,c,## _VA_ARGS__,NULL)

Comment: I've always been using this trick until I discovered that in pedantic mode of gcc when compiling for C99 or even C11, this yields a warning. Well, not exactly this macro definition itself, but calling a variadic macro with a zero variadic part. Why, oh why didn't they allow it in C11 standard?!

Comment: `__VA_OPT__` will be your friend @AlexanderAmelkin

Answer (score 23):

If you're using gcc/g++ there is a way:

```
#define CALL(f,...) FN(f)->call((ref(new LinkedList()), ## __VA_ARGS__))
```

From the [fine manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variadic-Macros.html):

> [...] if the variable arguments are omitted or empty, the `##' operator causes the preprocessor to remove the comma before it.

So gcc has an extension/hack specifically for the problem you are facing.

Comment: I have edited the question, I have found the same thing in the docs but with it I can not nest macros

Comment: Not only gcc/g++, works with IAR's compiler as well!

Answer (score 10):

`__VA_OPT__` (c++2a) should be more reliable, eg:
from http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0306r2.html

> The canonical use case of **VA_OPT** is for an optional separator:
>
> `#define LOG(msg, ...) printf(msg __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__)`

Answer (score 6):

If you are using GCC, it has an extension to swallow up the comma preceding the `__VA_ARGS__`. See: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html.

Comment: Only because yours is more thorough. :)

Comment: And MSVC, even though not mentioned on their MSDN page, supports the same extension, making everybody's lives a little bit easier.

Comment: @vanza: Actually, MSVC does it for you "automatically" -- if you have the sequence `, __VA_ARGS__` in a macro and `__VA_ARGS__` is empty, it will automatically swallow (delete) the `,`.  It also just ignores `##` if its between two tokens that can't be merged, so the gcc extension works by serendipity.

Answer (score 2):

Simply make `f` part of the `...`, and use a separate macro to extract the first argument where you need `f`.

Answer (score 2):

A common theme in these answers is that we need a GCC specific hack.   One way is to use the token-paste `##__VAR_ARGS__`, but pasted arguments are not macro expanded, which means that macros cannot be nested.  But if you are going to do something GCC specific anyway, then why not use the old-fashioned GCC extension:

```
 #define VARARG_FOO(ZeroOrMoreArgs...) \
     printf("VARARG_FOO: " ZeroOrMoreArgs)
```

`ZeroOrMoreArgs` is simply replaced by all the arguments (if any), commas and all.  This includes recursive macro expansion.

- then `VARARG_FOO()` expands to `printf("VARARG_FOO: ")`
- and `VARARG_FOO("I iz %d", 42)` expands to `printf("VARARGFOO: " "I iz %d", 42)`

Finally

```
 #define NEST_ME "I tawt I taw a puddy tat"
 VARARG_FOO("The evil one says %s", NEST_ME);
```

will expand to

```
 printf("VARARG_FOO: " "The evil one says %s", "I tawt I taw a puddy tat");
```

**Pros:**

- You can nest macro invocations, while having zero-or more aguments.

**Cons:**

- The `##__VA_ARGS__` hack *might* be harmless in standard C programs in the case where they always have at least one comma.  (I haven't thought about whether this is true or not).
- According to @ScootMoonen the `##__VA_ARGS__` hack is an undocumented extension to MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this cannot be done. You will need to define a separate macro to do this call.

As you end up with invalid arguments when **VA_ARGS** is substituted with nothing you end up with a floating `,`

```
#define CALL0(f) FN(f)->call((ref(new LinkedList())))
```