# Trouble with __VA_ARGS__

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

[C++ preprocessor __VA_ARGS__ number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124339/c-preprocessor-va-args-number-of-arguments)

The accepted answer there doesn't work for me.  I've tried with MSVC++ 10 and g++ 3.4.5.

I also crunched the example down into something smaller and started trying to get some information printed out to me in the error:

```
template < typename T >
struct print;

#include <boost/mpl/vector_c.hpp>

#define RSEQ_N 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0
#define ARG_N(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,N,...) N
#define ARG_N_(...) ARG_N(__VA_ARGS__)

#define XXX 5,RSEQ_N

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  print< boost::mpl::vector_c<int, ARG_N_( XXX ) > > g; // ARG_N doesn't work either.
}
```

It appears to me that the argument for ARG_N ends up being 'XXX' instead of `5,RSEQ_N` and much less `5,10,...,0`.  The error output of g++ more specifically says that only one argument is supplied.

Having trouble believing that the answer would be proposed and then accepted when it totally fails to work, so what am I doing wrong?  Why is `XXX` being interpreted as the argument and not being expanded?  In my own messing around everything works fine until I try to pass off **VA_ARGS** to a macro containing some names followed by ... like so:

```
#define WTF(X,Y,...) X , Y , __VA_ARGS__
#define WOT(...) WTF(__VA_ARGS__)

WOT(52,2,5,2,2)
```

I've tried both with and without `()` in the various macros that take no input.

Comment: After taking all the c++ stuff out I tried with gcc.  It hates it too.

Comment: Roberts: I can't help but think that there's a better way to do what you want. To what end are you trying to achieve with something like this?

Comment: @In silico - I'm trying to find the number of elements in a boost PP tuple.

Comment: [This answer in C++ preprocessor __VA_ARGS__ number of arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124339/c-preprocessor-va-args-number-of-arguments/5756072#5756072) worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__VA_ARGS__` was originally introduced in C99 and prior to C++11 was not part of the C++ standard. The compiler you’re referencing here doesn’t support C++11 (I believe), though more modern compilers should be able to handle this just fine.

Comment: Most C++ compilers support `__VA_ARGS__` as an extension. Variadic macros will be part of the C++0x standard.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with your macros.

Using both g++ 4.5.1 (in C++0x mode) and mcpp, `ARG_N_( XXX )` is correctly replaced by `1`.

This is [a reported bug in Visual C++](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/380090/variadic-macro-replacement).

Comment: The edit queues are full, so I can't edit this answer, but the link is now invalid and just redirects to a Bing search page. There's an archived version at https://web.archive.org/web/20100625002447/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/380090/variadic-macro-replacement