# Macro count params

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

In order to make compiler happy I have to count params passed to `A()`, otherwise gcc raises "`warning: ISO C99 requires rest arguments to be used`" when pedantic flag is on and only one param is passed

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Count params */
#define N_ARGS(...) N_ARGS_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,n,1,1)
#define N_ARGS_IMPL(_0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,N,...) N

#define A_fmt_void
#define A_arg_void

/* link */
#define A_fmt_link_1(fmt) " href=\""fmt"\""
#define A_fmt_link_n(fmt, ...) " href=\""fmt"\""
#define A_fmt_link_N(n, ...) A_fmt_link_##n(__VA_ARGS__)
#define A_fmt_link_X(n, ...) A_fmt_link_N(n,__VA_ARGS__)
#define A_fmt_link(...) A_fmt_link_X(N_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

#define A_arg_link_1(fmt)
#define A_arg_link_n(fmt, ...) , __VA_ARGS__
#define A_arg_link_N(n, ...) A_arg_link_##n(__VA_ARGS__)
#define A_arg_link_X(n, ...) A_arg_link_N(n,__VA_ARGS__)
#define A_arg_link(...) A_arg_link_X(N_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

/* text */
#define A_fmt_text_1(fmt) fmt
#define A_fmt_text_n(fmt, ...) fmt
#define A_fmt_text_N(n, ...) A_fmt_text_##n(__VA_ARGS__)
#define A_fmt_text_X(n, ...) A_fmt_text_N(n,__VA_ARGS__)
#define A_fmt_text(...) A_fmt_text_X(N_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

#define A_arg_text_1(fmt)
#define A_arg_text_n(fmt, ...) , __VA_ARGS__
#define A_arg_text_N(n, ...) A_arg_text_##n(__VA_ARGS__)
#define A_arg_text_X(n, ...) A_arg_text_N(n,__VA_ARGS__)
#define A_arg_text(...) A_arg_text_X(N_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)

/* macro */
#define A(link, text) \
    printf("<a"A_fmt_##link">"A_fmt_##text"</a>\n" A_arg_##link A_arg_##text)

int main(void)
{
    A(link(), void);
    A(void, text());
    A(link("http://www.google.es"), void);
    A(link("%s/%s", "http://www.google.es", "home"), text("Visit google"));
    A(void, text("%s today", "Visit google"));
    A(link("http://%s/%s", "www.google.es", "home"), text("%s today", "Visit google"));
    A(void,void);
    return 0;
}
```

With this implementation of `N_ARGS` I can use only 10 params, is there another way to check if there is more than one param without limit in macro?

I know `, ## __VA_ARGS__` gcc extension but I want to avoid warnings

Comment: It should be the compiler to make you happy, not the opposite.

Comment: This smells like an XY question, what have you done to makethe compiler issue a warning in the first place?

Comment: @StoryTeller using (fmt, ...) with only one param: warning: ISO C99 requires rest arguments to be used when pedantic flag is on using `, ## __VA_ARGS__` gcc extension

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124339/c-preprocessor-va-args-number-of-arguments/2124433#2124433

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've fixed using `__ extension__`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define A_fmt_void
#define A_arg_void
#define A_fmt_link(fmt, ...) " href=\""fmt"\""
#define A_arg_link(fmt, ...) , ## __VA_ARGS__
#define A_fmt_text(fmt, ...) fmt
#define A_arg_text(fmt, ...) , ## __VA_ARGS__
#define A(link, text) \
    __extension__ printf("<a" A_fmt_##link ">" A_fmt_##text "</a>\n" A_arg_##link A_arg_##text)

int main(void)
{
    A(
        link("%s", "http://wwww.google.com"),
        text("%s", "Visit google")
    );
    A(
        link("http://wwww.google.com"),
        void
    );
    A(
        void,
        text("Visit google")
    );
    A(
        void,
        void
    );
    return 0;
}
```

This prevents warnings when pedantic flag is on :)