# Get count of arguments passed to a variadic macro in c

Tags: c

I have a use case where i need the count of arguments passed to variadic macro in c. 
I tried using the following code:

```
#define COUNT_ARGS(...) COUNT_ARGS_(,##__VA_ARGS__,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0)
#define COUNT_ARGS_(z,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,cnt,...) cnt
```

**But this has a serious issue, if user passes say 11 arguments to this maro the count is returned as value of 11th argument.**

Is there any other way i can get the count of arguments passed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ preprocessor \_\_VA\_ARGS\_\_ number of arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124339/c-preprocessor-va-args-number-of-arguments)

Comment: As mentioned the solution proposed has an issue, what  user passes more that 63 arguments as suggested in the post, the count comes out to be value of 64 argument

Comment: Have you check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/2124433/835146 ?