# Is there a way to make a macro have different behavior if it has parenthesis?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
#define FOO printf("No paren\n");
#define FOO(x) printf(x);
```

Is there a way to do this with c++ macros?

Comment: Did you even try? What did the compiler tell you?

Comment: Yes I tried extremely hard with many hacks and could never get it to work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not advise it, but it *is* possible with some help from C++ itself,

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct CustomMessage
{
    const T& t;
    CustomMessage(const T& t) : t(t)
    {}
};

struct DefaultMessage
{
    template<typename T> CustomMessage<T> operator() (const T& t)
    {
        return {t};
    }
};
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const CustomMessage<T>& message)
{
    return os << message.t;
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const DefaultMessage& message)
{
    return os << "no paren\n";
}

using namespace std;

#define FOO std::cout << DefaultMessage{}

int main() {
    int x = 42;
    FOO;
    FOO(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Live one Ideone https://ideone.com/VboP8R

Answer (score 8):

No.  A given macro name can either be plain ("object-like") or "function-like", not both.

Comment: A "plain" macro is called "object-like" in the language of the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Not so directly: A single macro has to either be "plain" or "function like".

However, you can sorta-kinda do some things in this direction.

You can use variadic macros and change behaviour based on the [number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124339/c-preprocessor-va-args-number-of-arguments).

You can use the above to build the name of a target macro to delegate to:

```
#define NUM_ARGS_(_10, _9, _8, _7, _6, _5, _4, _3, _2, _1, N, ...) N

#define NUM_ARGS(...) NUM_ARGS_(__VA_ARGS__, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)

#define CONCAT_(a, b) a##b
#define CONCAT(a, b) CONCAT_(a, b)

#define CAKE_1(X) some-interesting-code-here
#define CAKE_2(X, Y) some-different-interesting-code-here
#define CAKE(...) CONCAT(CAKE_, NUM_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)
```

In the above, calling CAKE() with 1 argument will invoke CAKE_1, and calling it with 2 will invoke CAKE_2.

Whether or not it's a good idea to do this sort of thing, for reasons of clarity and such, is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Downvoted as this answers `CAKE(x)` vs `CAKE(x, y)` ... rather than the actual question of `CAKE` vs `CAKE(x)`

Comment: Did you try reading the first sentence, in which I explain that's impossible?

Comment: Sorry for giving OP a nearby alternative when they ask for an impossible thing, I guess?

Comment: Thanks, yea I was playing with variadic macros like you explained here (you can also do 0 argument ones) but that wasn't quite what I was looking for.

Comment: Indeed, you can't do exactly what you want using just the preprocessor, but tahsmith's answer is a quite interesting hybrid approach (One that also illustrates quite nicely why doing this is a _terrible_ idea). What do you want this for anyway?

Comment: A friend was defining custom integrators (so he didn't manually have to define thousands of them) and wanted this for some reason - I dunno, he just mentioned it to me and I thought it was a fun challenge