# Comparison of several integer values for equality

Tags: c

If I have two integer values I can test for equality simply:

```
if (a == b)
```

if I have three integer values then I could do something like:

```
if ((a == b) && (a == c) && (b == c))
```

I've got a situation where I've got 6 values to test for equality, this approach is going to get verbose

Is their a better, and more C idiomatic (c-onic?) means to achieve this?

actually, just having written this I can see that:

```
if ((a == b) && (b == c) && (c == d)... )
```

is logically ok, i.e. you don't need all the combinations as `a == b` and `b == c` implies `a == c`

But in terms of clarity of expression how close can I get to:

`if (a == b == c)` ?

Comment: Can you use an array for those 6 values? (so that you use a loop instead).

Comment: Store all of them into an array or vector and do bitwise XOR?  If final answer is `0`, then `a===b==c`, else not.

Comment: @abhishek_naik 1^2^3==0 so 1==2 and 2==3?

Comment: However, if `(a|b|c|d|e|f)==a` and `(~a|~b|~c|~d|~e|~f)==~a` then I think we have it. I'm not sure I'd call that "clarity of expression" though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not going to get very close to `a == b == c`.

To cause experienced C programmers the least surprise, I think this is best is

```
if(a == b && b == c && c == d && d == e && e == f)
```

i.e. basically like what you have already, with less parentheses. I'm not always opposed to adding parentheses that make no difference to the compiler to help humans who don't know all the precedence rules, but I think comparisons separated by `&&` (with no `||` mixed in) are a simple enough case that the parentheses are more clutter than they're worth.

If the variable names are long, putting it all on one line isn't going to be pretty, so maybe

```
if(a == b &&
   b == c &&
   c == d &&
   d == e &&
   e == f)
```

or this might be better since the duplication of the the `a` in every line will be immediately noticeable:

```
if(a == b &&
   a == c &&
   a == d &&
   a == e &&
   a == f)
```

If you really want it to be compact, the [p99 preprocessor library](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/) offers this:

```
#include "p99_for.h"

if(P99_ARE_EQ(a,b,c,d,e,f))
```

which looks like John Zwinck's answer but doesn't require a helper function.

Comment: well this is pretty much what I implemented, keeping the left hand side the same is a nice touch - p99 is new to me and looks very interesting.. cheers for the heads-up

Comment: crikey - the reference manual for p99 is over 1000 pages long! thats some header file..

Answer (score 7):

I can show you how to do it in a variadic macro, so we can write this:

```
if(EQI(a, b, c, d, e, f))
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define NUMARGS(...) (sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__}) / sizeof(int))
#define EQI(...) ( \
    alleqi(NUMARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__))

/* takes count number of int arguments */
int alleqi(size_t count, ...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, count);

    int v0 = va_arg(va, int);

    for (; count > 1; count--) {
        if (v0 != va_arg(va, int)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    va_end(va);
    return count == 1;
}
```

Please be advised the above only works for `int` arguments (and probably other types whose size is the same as `int`, though I am bracing for someone to accuse me of promoting undefined behavior if I advertise that!).

Thanks to this prior post for figuring out how to count arguments in a variadic macro: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2124433/4323

Comment: maybe INTEQ rather than EQ to adhere to principle of least surprise?

Comment: @bph: I made it `EQI` now, though I think it's OK to use it on any four-byte quantities.  We could make an `EQL` for eight-byte quantities.  You can even `assert()` the size of the first argument is correct, but beyond that is tedious.

Comment: Nice use of compound literal to determine `count`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check six values, one approach would be to store them in an array

```
int a[6];

equals = 1;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    if (a[i] != a[i+1])
    {
       equals = 0;
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: combination of this with a var arg function could be quite nice

Answer (score 2):

Approaches using arrays require you to change your data structure into an array.

Approaches using a variadic macro requires an additional function and function call (overhead).

Except for these two approaches, the only other way I see is to write them out. I feel the best way, or the more clear way, is to take the first variable and compare it to all other variables. By implication then either all variabes are equal, or at least two variables are unequal:

```
if ((a == b) && (a == c) && (a == d)
&&  (a == e) && (a == f) && (a == g) ...)
```

Comment: That is actually for 7 variables. For 6 it's hardly worth doing anything else - just 5 comparisons. If OP had realised beforehand there is no need to test `b == c` etc, he might not have asked the question.

Comment: Yes I did hesitate when posting the OP - but I have definitely learnt something so all good