# Deterministic way of saying "promote everything to floating before calculation" in C++

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, integer-promotion

Given that I'd prefer to keep numbers in my program as `int`s or whatever integral, what is the most convenient way of doing an arbitrary arithmetic with floating point equivalents of those numbers?

Say, I have

```
int a,b,c,d;
double x;
```

And I want to write

```
x=a/b/c/d+c/d+a;
```

without turning the expression into mess by putting conversions everywhere in parsed operator tree leafs like

```
x=(double)a/b/c/d+(double)c/d+a;
```

Is it doable with C-style macro (recursive or not)? Should it be done with new class and overloaded operators?

Comment: You should use `x=(double)a/b/c/d+(double)c/d+a;`, your version has 2 integer divisions (`a/b/c`).

Comment: You can reference [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) article, "Numeric promotions" part - becuase some automatical type promotion (from integral to floating point) happens, you can skip some explicit type casts.

Comment: @mch: `/` has left-to-right associativity meaning that `a/b/c/d` will be grouped as `a/(b/(c/d))`, and if I convert `a` then `b/c/d` will be integer division. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are wrong, `/` having left to right associativity means that `a/b/c/d` will be calculated as `((a/b)/c)/d`. From left to right, you explained right to left.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
x=a/b/c/d+c/d+a;
```

This is a pretty complex expression. Better give it a name:

```
double complex_expression(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
  return a/b/c/d+c/d+a;
}
```

Now when you call that with integer arguments, since the parameters are of type `double` the arguments get converted to `double` using the usual arithmetic conversions:

```
int a,b,c,d;
// Init them somehow
double x = complex_expression(a,b,c,d);
```

---

With a C++11 lambda ...

```
int a,b,c,d;
// Init them somehow
double x = [](double a, double b, double c, double d) {
  return a/b/c/d+c/d+a; }(a,b,c,d);
```

... works, but IMO somehow looks clumsy.

Slightly better?

```
double x = [a = (double)a, b = (double)b, c = (double)c, d = (double) d] {
    return a/b/c/d+c/d+a; }();
```

Oh, and if you're in for some macro fun:

```
#define SPLICE_2(l,r) l##r
#define SPLICE_1(l,r) SPLICE_2(l,r)
#define SPLICE(l,r) SPLICE_1(l,r)

#define TREAT_AS(type, name) name = static_cast<type>(name)

#define TREAT_ALL_AS_HELPER_0(type)
#define TREAT_ALL_AS_HELPER_1(type, name)  TREAT_AS(type, name)
#define TREAT_ALL_AS_HELPER_2(type, name, ...) TREAT_AS(type, name), TREAT_ALL_AS_HELPER_1(type, __VA_ARGS__)
#define TREAT_ALL_AS_HELPER_3(type, name, ...) TREAT_AS(type, name), TREAT_ALL_AS_HELPER_2(type, __VA_ARGS__)
#define TREAT_ALL_AS_HELPER_4(type, name, ...) TREAT_AS(type, name), TREAT_ALL_AS_HELPER_3(type, __VA_ARGS__)
#define TREAT_ALL_AS_HELPER_5(type, name, ...) TREAT_AS(type, name), TREAT_ALL_AS_HELPER_4(type, __VA_ARGS__)
// expand as you will

#define TREAT_ALL_AS(type, count, ...) SPLICE(TREAT_ALL_AS_HELPER_, count)(type, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Now use as

```
double x = [TREAT_ALL_AS(double, 4, a, b, c, d)] {
  return a/b/c/d+c/d+a; }();
```

You can also [automatically count the number of variadic macro arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2124339/1116364).

---

But to be honest, IMO its best to just write a named function.

Comment: @KishanKumar Then it's even better to have individual expressions *named* in order to reduce overall complexity. Functions aren't expensive, you can have lots of them (though you might want to make them static then, assuming they're only used once)

Comment: Could you add a version with C++11 anonymous functions?

Comment: IMHO your "Slightly better" version is slightly worse.

Comment: @ChrisDrew I've added a question mark ;) I think both versions are a nightmare regarding readability ...

Comment: @DanielJour Personally, I would put the lamda in a named `auto` variable. You might say it offers no advantages over a normal named function but it reduces its scope and places it close to where it is being used.

Comment: Is there any place to learn how to do advanced macro programming like that?

Comment: @kishan-kumar: I am using C++ for years and I still cannot think out a way of doing the questioned tasked effectively. The most logical answer is "do not store floating operands as integrals" or "do not use C++ for that". Really though, there should not be undocumented complex arithmetic operations, there is always a limited number of them.

Comment: Nice, nifty solutions :)

Comment: FWIW, all this to avoid having to write a `(double)` cast twice? Really?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis yeah i think its a lot of effort to just not right the float. And making a function for every expression which will be mostly used once, is also not good. As functions are made for those codes which are to be reusable.

Comment: @DanielJour if he had many calls to different function then some part of the runtime will be wasted in these function calls. better make them inline.

Comment: @0x499602d2: use IEC standard as reference. It might not be educative but it will list every possibility available.

Comment: @ChrisDrew That sounds reasonable, at least if the function's only used in a narrow part of the code.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yes, as long as it improves readability. The macro solution though is probably only relevant when there's a lot of such complex expressions...

Comment: @KishanKumar No, that's not how `inline` works, at least not since the last 10 years or so. The compiler will inline a function whenever it deems this appropriate. Marking such utility functions as `static` should be done though, otherwise the function names are exported as symbols in the resulting object file/binary.

Comment: @KishanKumar "As functions are made for those codes which are to be reusable" I'd say this is a common fallacy. Functions are an abstraction that allows us to *name* some (collection of) operations and then later refer to that using that name (possibly multiple times).

Comment: @0x499602D2 Not that I know of. Basically a combination of trial and error, looking at other peoples code and reading the standard.

Comment: @DanielJour Okay. And why do you do `#define SPLICE(l,r) SPLICE_1(l,r)` instead of `#define SPLICE(l,r) l##r`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Oops, that's actually unnecessary: You need this to "force evaluation" of constructs like `SPLICE(thing, macro(foo))` (i.e. to get the concatenation of `thing` and whatever `macro(foo)` expands into, instead of `thingmacro(foo)`). I use that `SPLICE` because I can be relatively sure that it does what I mean (splice the results after macro expansion).