# Creating and Initializing structs with variable length macro in C

Tags: c, macros

I was trying to create and initialize a struct using a variable length macro. I want to be able create/initialize the struct with '0's and then initialize some fields of the struct with values that were optionally passed in.

Is this possible to do?  I was trying the following:

```
#define INIT_ENTRY(x, ...) \
    entry_t x = {.id = 0, .age = 0} \
    x.id  = <I want to use arg1 here>
    x.age = <i want to use arg2 here if it exists>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Would something like the following use-case meet your need:  `x = INIT_ENTRY(x, 1)` would do about `(entry_t){.id = 1}` and `x = INIT_ENTRY(x, 1, 2)` would do about `(entry_t){.id = 1, .age = 2}` ?  What is the max length needed - arbitrary?  BTW: `x.id  = <I want to use arg1 here>` is not _initialization_, but assignment.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a combination of argument counting and concatenation.

1. First you need a macro that counts it's arguments, which I'll call `NARGS` This was asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2124339/1111371). Note that answers are compiler-dependent.
2. Next you need a series of macros for all specific cases:

   `#define INIT_ENTRY_0(x) entry_t x = {.id = 0, .age = 0}`
   `#define INIT_ENTRY_1(x, _id) entry_t x = {.id = _id, .age = 0}`
   `#define INIT_ENTRY_2(x, _id, _age) entry_t x = {.id = _id, .age = _age}`
3. You also need a concatenation macro:

   `#define CONCAT(a, b) a##b`
4. Last, use concatenation to choose the correct one:

   `#define INIT_ENTRY(x, ...) CONCAT(INIT_ENTRY_, NARGS(__VA_ARGS__))(x, #__VA_ARGS__)`

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the same order of initializers in your macro as in your initialization list, then given you're always initializing everything else to 0, you can simply do this:

```
#define _INIT_ENTRY_UTILITY(x, ID_, AGE_, ...) \
   entry_t x = {.id = ID_, .age = AGE_}
#define INIT_ENTRY(...) _INIT_ENTRY_UTILITY(__VA_ARGS__, 0, 0, )
```

I assume your real use case has more than 2 parameters; if you take this approach, make sure to mimic its form exactly to maintain portability.  In particular:

- Changing to `#define INIT_ENTRY(x, ...)` for "clarity" will break calls that look like `INIT_ENTRY(foo)` on *standard* C preprocessors.  What's worse is that it will actually work on some popular cpp's (such as gnu) that support such things as an extension, so the portability issue's hidden.
- Removing the final comma in the call to `_INIT_ENTRY_UTILITY` from `INIT_ENTRY`'s replacement list leads to the same portability issue