# Error: cast to incomplete array type "int []" is not allowed

Tags: c++

I want to get the length of **VA_ARGS**

I used the answer of this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/2124433/7388699 but if doesn't work!

```
#define PIN_ARRAY_LENGTH(...) ((size_t)(sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__})/sizeof(int)))

size_t c = PIN_ARRAY_LENGTH(1, 5, 7, 9);
```

I also tried

```
size_t x = sizeof((int[]){ 1, 6, 8 }) / sizeof(int);
```

It does not compile, I get the error: cast to incomplete array type "int []" is not allowed

Comment: This looks like an XY problem.  What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: This is trying to create a compound literal, but these only exist in C99 and above, not in C++.

Comment: I want to pass CREATE_PIN_ARRAY(1, 6, 8) end then let it expand to new const unsigned int[]{1, 6, 8}, 3
I have problems to pass the size of the array

Comment: `#define CREATE_PIN_ARRAY(...) const unsigned int something[] { __VA_ARGS__ }`? Not sure what you're gaining by hiding that behind a macro though. Edit: oh, there's the array size in there too. Hold on.

Comment: Because I don't wat to pass the size manually, I want it to automatically append the size

Comment: If you want just get the length of VA_ARGS use this trick https://stackoverflow.com/a/2124385/10733631

Comment: I tried it but it does not work it is just empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compound literals are out of the question, but you can create the array rvalue you need through a typedef:

```
using int_c_array = int[];

#define count_args(...) \
    (sizeof(int_c_array {__VA_ARGS__}) / sizeof(int))
```

Answer (score 1):

Variation of [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3233393/quentin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53872309/1312382):

```
#define NUM(...) (std::tuple_size<decltype(std::make_tuple(__VA_ARGS__))>::value)
```

This does not require an alias and works with arbitrary types:

```
size_t n = NUM(7, 10.12, "hello world");
```