# Macro variadic argument

Tags: c++, c++98

I have this code:

```
std::string format(const char *fmt, ...);

#define DEBUG(HANDLER, LEVEL, ...) LOG##LEVEL(HANDLER, format(__VA_ARGS__))
```

It works when I use:

```
DEBUG(handler, DEBUG, "var is %d\n", 15);
```

but it doesn't work when I use:

```
DEBUG(handler, DEBUG, "test");
```

How can I check if there's only one argument or more than one?
I need to use **C++98** solution only.

Comment: You cannot. You need to pass that information either in your format or through some additional variable.

Comment: @JoeyMallone I could modify the format function, but how?

Comment: `__VA_ARGS__` was introduced C++11, so it can't be done in C++98

Comment: @MichaelVeksler, I use `C++03` and I have `__VA_ARGS__`. `:)` I was about to test your answer with `__VA_OPTS__`, as I didn't know about that, but you deleted it.

Comment: `__VA__OPT__` is C++20, no? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher you are correct, that's why I removed my answer. However, since `__VA_ARGS__` is available for OP's C++98 compiler (despite being C++11 feature), it might also have  `__VA__OPT__` as part of the extension

Comment: @greywolf82, I didn't mean that. The information about how many parameters there are in a variadic macro can only be passed either **implicitly** in the format-string (I don't know how and I don't think you could access that information.) OR explicitly with an additional variable passed to the macro. I at least do NOT know of any other way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ preprocessor \_\_VA\_ARGS\_\_ number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124339/c-preprocessor-va-args-number-of-arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I looked at your question and I looked at your code and I realized that this is probably a case of the **infamous XY Problem**.

Although you say, you want to count the number of arguments being passed to the macro,  *what you want to do is write debug messages which do not have any other parameters except a literal string which states a debug message as you show in the example.*

> `DEBUG(handler, DEBUG, "test");`

But that is of course possible. And to test it, I wrote the following bit of code.

```
std::string format(const char* fmt, ...) {
    char buffer[256];
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, fmt);
    vsprintf(buffer, fmt, argList);
    va_end(argList);
    return std::string(buffer);
}

#define TRC(...) {\
    std::cout << "MACRO!" << std::endl; \
    std::cout << format(__VA_ARGS__);\
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    const char *t = "b";
    TRC("[%s] bla bla [%d]\n", t, 9);
    TRC("test");
    return 0;
}
```

which produces the output,

> Hello World! 
>   MACRO! 
>   format 
>   [b] bla bla [9] 
>   MACRO! 
>   format 
>   test

Like I mentioned in the comments to your question earlier, I have `C++03` compiler but this should work for C++98 also, I guess.

**Question:**

> *"How can I check if there's only one argument or more than one?"*

The variadic macro itself has no problem whether you have one argument or more.

*But if you really really still want to count the number of arguments passed in, I don't know of anyway in `C++03` or earlier to do that.*

Answer (score 1):

Since `__VA__ARGS__` is available on your otherwise C++98 compiler (despite being a [C++11 feature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace)), there is a chance it also has `__VA_OPT__` as an extension:

You should use `__VA_OPT__(something)` (which is a C++20 feature) to make the comma appear only if there is at least one argument:

```
#define DEBUG(HANDLER, LEVEL, ...) LOG##LEVEL(HANDLER __VA_OPT__( format(__VA_ARGS__)))
```

or something similar that works for your case.