# Assignment operators

Tags: c++

The following expression is valid in C++:

```
A = B = C = 10;
```

The variables A, B, and C will now contain the value 10.

I'm trying to figure out how to make it so A, B, and C can contain the value of 10 when declared, not assign them later;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int A, B, C, = 10;
   int result;
   result = A = B = C = 10;
   cout << A << B << C << 10;

   result 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In C++ every variable definition has to have its own initializer.  If you want to chain that then you need to use something like

```
int A = 10, B = A, C = B;
```

This will do what you want but it is required to  you manually specify the initializer.

Comment: I'd prefer `C = A` for some reason (*feels* better?), but this is a good answer. Surprised somewhat that I'm the only upvoter.

Comment: @Bathsheba I changed it but I've changed it back.  At first I thought having `C = A` makes the code easier to maintain because with that `B` could be removed without consequence.  After thinking about that more though I realized that if `A` is removed then you need to change `B` and `C` instead of just `B`.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do what you want directly. However, in my opinion wanting to initialize them with the same value is reason enough to define a class:

```
struct ABC {
    int A,B,C;
    ABC(int x) : A(x),B(x),C(x) {}
};
```

If there is a relation between `A`,`B` and `C`, make it explicit. Now you can use a single value to initialize them:

```
ABC abc{10};
```

Comment: An interesting point. However having the same idea in my mind I would suggest another solution: the class-wrapper of int with default constructor.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly write: `int a = 10, b = 10, c = 10;`

Comment: Yet another level of declaration :D

Comment: If you don't want to write 10 three times, you can do: `int a = 10, b = a, c = b;`. whether this is clear or silly is left as an exercise to the reader

Answer (score 3):

Declaration differs from assignment a lot. Usually assignment operator returns the reference to the object. For example the type of this operation is `int&`:

```
int a;
a = 10;
```

This allows you chaining the assignments like that: `a = b = c = 10`: at the end of the day the type of this operator is `int&` again and you still can add one more assignment to the right.

The definition of the variables is another story. Each variable has to get it's own value (or no value at all), but there is no way to "assign" (actually initialize) a single value "in one assignment".

However maybe this can solve your actual problem:

```
const int value = 10;
int a = value, b = value, c = value;
```

By the way, defining several variables in one line is a bad practice. Your example is one illustration of the problem. Other problems with that: what is the pointer, what is the reference and what is just a pure int in the next example?

```
int val;
int* a, b;
int& c = val, d = val;
```

Comment: "By the way, defining several variables in one line is a bad practice." - says who? The MISRA guys? Some author or other?

Comment: @Bathsheba One reason of why this is a bad practice is the problem in question. People forget that the initializer is applied to the last variable only. The same with pointers and references.
I don't want to argue, but in many cases this is considered to be a bad practice.

Comment: I know I’m quixotic but folk shouldn’t forget. Learn the language, pretty please with sugar on top.

Comment: I agree with putting declarations on seperate lines, but just saying "it is bad practice" without saying why is... well, bad practice. Why? Because blindly following rules is never good, only if you know why you can decide when it matters and when it doesnt

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 OK, I've updated my answer.

Comment: one more nitpick "but there is no way to assign a single value "in one assignment"." but that should be "initialize" not "assign"

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 that is why I've taken that in quotes.

Comment: the "to assign" is not in quotes, but there is no assignment, only initialization, I think it matters as you are trying to point out the difference between assignment and initialization and in `int A = 10;` there is no assignment

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Agree.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the universally understood and used: `int a = 10, b = 10, c = 10;`

That being said...

---

### C++17 !!!

We have [Structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) so Yeey!!!

<del>`auto [a, b, c] = {10, 10, 10};`</del>

Oh, you can't do that? Oh well...

---

<sub>C++17</sub>

```
auto [a, b, c] = std::tuple{10, 10, 10};
```

---

### C++20 !!!

We have [Designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) Yeey!!

<del>`auto [a, b, c] = std::tuple{[0 ... 2] = 10};`</del>

<del>`auto [a, b, c] = (int[]){[0 ... 2] = 10};`</del>

Oh, you can't do that? Oh well...

---

## At last the glorious solution

Okey... let's do it by hand. yey? :(

```
auto test()
{
    auto [a, b, c] = make_repeating_tuple<3, 10>();

    // or, alternative
    auto [a, b, c] = make_repeating_tuple<3>(10);
}
```

Implementation

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

namespace details
{
template <auto Val, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr auto make_repeating_tuple_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    // black magic
    return std::tuple{[] (auto) { return Val; }(Is)...};
}
}

template <int N, auto Val>
constexpr auto make_repeating_tuple()
{
    return details::make_repeating_tuple_impl<Val>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

Implementation (alternative)

```
namespace details
{
template <class T, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr auto make_repeating_tuple_impl(T val, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<decltype(Val)>); // because

    // black magic
    return std::tuple{[=] (auto) { return val; }(Is)...};
}
}

template <int N, class T>
constexpr auto make_repeating_tuple(T val)
{
    return details::make_repeating_tuple_impl(val, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

---

## Burn The Witch! Burn The Witch!! Burn The Witch!!!

```
auto test()
{
    DECL_CHAIN_ASSIGN(10, a, b, c);
}
```

Implementation:

```
// the darkest of magics
#define DECL_CHAIN_ASSIGN(val, ...) \
    auto [__VA_ARGS__] = make_repeating_tuple<PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__)>(val)
```

With

```
#define PP_NARG(...) \
         PP_NARG_(__VA_ARGS__,PP_RSEQ_N())
#define PP_NARG_(...) \
         PP_ARG_N(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PP_ARG_N( \
          _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9,_10, \
         _11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20, \
         _21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30, \
         _31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40, \
         _41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50, \
         _51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60, \
         _61,_62,_63,N,...) N
#define PP_RSEQ_N() \
         63,62,61,60,                   \
         59,58,57,56,55,54,53,52,51,50, \
         49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40, \
         39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30, \
         29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20, \
         19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10, \
         9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0
// taken from
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124339/c-preprocessor-va-args-number-of-arguments
```

On a more serious note: **Don't use the macro!!**

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not work that way. Although you can declare multiple variables of the same type in a single statement, you can't initialize them with a single value, they must be initialized individually, eg

```cpp
int A = 10, B = 10, C = 10;
```

So, what you are trying to do only works in assignments, not in declarations.

Answer (score 1):

If you ***really*** want to maintain your `A = B = C = 10;` syntax, then you ***can*** actually do this in a single-line declaration/initializer, provided you declare `B` and `C` before `A`. So:

```c
int C, B, A = B = C = 10;
```

This is perfectly legal, and well-defined code. But I'm not saying it's what you *should* do. (Comments welcome giving examples of where such a form may be useful!)