# Can we use recursive macro to create varadic max/min?

Tags: c, macros

Need max/min with *unknown* number of arguments, like :

```
#define MAX_N(first, second, remain...) MAX_N(((first)>(second)?(first):(second)), ##remain)
```

In my opinion, this will not keep expanding infinitely and should be accepted by compiler?

Unfortunately, I have to use pure C rather than C++.

Comment: No, this will not work. C macros are not expanded recursively.

Comment: Though if you do want this behavior, use a function that take a `va_list`.

Comment: But no termination condition is different from this situation which is limited to decrease varadic params

Comment: @AbyssCybortGin Whether or not it finds an end to the recursion has no influence on whether or not its allowed. The macro currently being expanded is simply not recognized in further expansion.

Comment: @Alexander thx, but I need to use this at compile time, like to define arrays.

Comment: @Thomas Jager Well I'm talking about the reason it's not allowed. If it can actually work, why not allowed?

Comment: @AbyssCybortGin That's just the way the language is defined. The way macros are evaluated may also not lend itself well to this. C macros aren't functions, they're just fancy text replacement.

Comment: @AbyssCybortGin Also, what you have would in fact infinetly recurse.

Answer (score 2):

C 2018 6.10.3.4 2 says, about rescanning the result of macro replacement for further macros:

> If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of the replacement list (not including the rest of the source file’s preprocessing tokens), it is not replaced. Furthermore, if any nested replacements encounter the name of the macro being replaced, it is not replaced…

Therefore, recursive macros are not possible, not even just for two levels, let alone indefinitely many.

It is possible to cause macros to be expanded multiple times by using other macros to expand them. As a simple example, after `#define X Y Y`, `X` will be replaced by two occurrences of `Y`, each of which, if it is a defined macro, will be replaced—but separately, not recursively. This can be exploited to create macros that cause sone finitely limited number of expansions, but indefinitely many expansions are not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a recursive macro? you can write a variadic min/max function like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

// credit for NUMARGS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2124433/2889478
#define NUMARGS(...)  (sizeof((int[]){__VA_ARGS__})/sizeof(int))
#define MAX(...) (max_variadic(NUMARGS(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__))

int max_variadic(int narg, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    int pos = 0, max_val = 0;

    va_start(args, narg);
    while (narg--) {
        int i = va_arg(args, int);
        max_val = !pos ? i : i > max_val ? i : max_val;
        pos++;
    }
    va_end(args);
    return max_val;
}

int main(void)
{
    int mx = MAX(4, 6, -1, 9, 2);
    printf("%d", mx);
}
```