# Get number of element in macro without allocating global variable

Tags: arrays, c, macros, preprocessor

I have the following code:

```
#define SUB_LIST 1, 2, 3

uint8_t sub_array[] = {SUB_LIST};

#define SUB_LIST_SIZE (sizeof(sub_array) / sizeof(sub_array[0]))

uint8_t array[SUB_LIST_SIZE + X] = {0};
```

Here, `sub_array[]` exists only because I need it to get the number of elements in `SUB_LIST`. It is not used anywhere else, and thus it is quite a waste of memory.

It is possible to get the number of element in `SUB_LIST` without having to permanently allocate memory for `sub_array[]`?

Comment: Is there a reasonably small maximum number of arguments? Maybe you could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2124385/5264491).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) but it gets a bit messy if you want to avoid specifying the element type (here `uint8_t`) twice:

```c
#define SUB_LIST_SIZE ( sizeof( (uint8_t[]){SUB_LIST} ) / sizeof(uint8_t) )
```

With this, a local, unnamed array will be created wherever the `SUB_LIST_SIZE` macro's code is encountered. That will be created with automatic storage duration (typically, on the stack), or *may* even optimized out by the compiler. <sup>1</sup>

A short demo:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define SUB_LIST 1, 2, 3
#define SUB_LIST_SIZE ( sizeof( (uint8_t[]){SUB_LIST} ) / sizeof(uint8_t) )

int main()
{
    #define X 42 // For example
    uint8_t array[SUB_LIST_SIZE + X] = { 0 };
    size_t arr_length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    printf("Array length = %zu\n", arr_length);
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This assumes that the macro is used at *block scope*, as it is in your declaration of `array` in `main`; if it is used at *file scope*, then a static (permanent) unnamed array will be created.

Comment: In my code, sub_array[] and array[] are global variables. If we take that into account, will the compound literal still be optimized out by the compiler ? (I am using gcc by the way)

Comment: @The_Average_Engineer That could be a language-lawyer type issue. The cppreference page I linked states that a globally-declared compound literal has static storage duration but, as it can't be used again in your use case, I can't see why a compiler can't optimize it out, if it can evaluate the expression as a compile-time constant.

Comment: Ok it is noted. Thank you for your answer. It was very helpful

Comment: @The_Average_Engineer Can't you declare your unused `sub_array[]` `static` to improve the chance of it being optimized out? Otherwise you would need link-time optimizations to stand any chance of optimizing out a variable with external linkage.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/jYKzcaG5q it will be optimized by gcc even if optimizations are disabled

Answer (score 1):

Consider a macro such as this:

```
#define GET_SIZE(...) ( sizeof (uint8_t[]){ __VA_ARGS__} )
```

Usage:

```
GET_SIZE(SUB_LIST)
```

This creates a temporary *compound literal* array and places your list of item as initializer list to that array. The compound literal will almost certainly get optimized away in any scenario - in your case it will get replaced by the number 3 in the machine code.