C array padding
I have many data array defined in my code with the length only specified in the array initializer.
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int b[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

For cache line coherence consideration, I want to padding them to cache line size (32). The following code can be used without scarifying the exact size information
struct {
   int payload[4];
} __attribute__((aligned(32))) a = {
   .payload = {1, 2, 3, 4}
};

struct {
   int payload[5];
} __attribute__((aligned(32))) b = {
   .payload = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
};

// sizeof(a.payload) == 4 * sizeof(int), sizeof(b.payload) == 5 * sizeof(int)

However, there are quite a bundle of such data, it is hard to manually rewrite them one by one. Is there a way to define a macro to handle this, like
#define ARRAY_INITIALIZER (array, initializer) ...
#define ARRAY_PAYLOAD(array) array.payload
ARRAY_INITIALIZER(a, {1, 2, 3, 4});
ARRAY_INITIALIZER(b, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});

The most difficulty thing here is how to calculate the length of initializer here, don't get any direction for it, can anyone help here?

This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124339/c-preprocessor-va-args-number-of-arguments  Yes, it is C++, but the macro definition might work for you too.

Could __attribute__((aligned(32))) be applied to the array as a single variable, but not a structure field?

Why place the arrays in a struct? Is your real question how to get the initial arrays 32-byte aligned?

@nielsen, putting it inside a struct has 2 effect 1) end data padding, not only align on start, but also align on end 2) sizeof can still get the actual size without the end padding

@StasSimonov, aligned to variable will only make it start aligned, say a array of 5 is start align on 32, the left 27 bytes are still available for other variables to allocate, we want it occupies the full 32 byte to avoid cache coherence issue

__attribute__ is a GNU-ism. Some other C implementations support it for GCC compatibility, but it is not standard C.

But GNU C allows __attribute__((aligned)) to be applied to variables as well as to types, so I'm not quite following why you are considering wrapping your arrays in structures just to get alignment.

@JohnBollinger, __attribute__((aligned)) to variable will only align its start. When apply it to struct it will align both start and end. See Link1 and Link2

That's an odd way to describe it, @EricSun, but ok.  And so what?  If there's some way you expect to benefit from padding these arrays to a multiple of the cache line size that you don't already get from aligning them to the beginning of a cache line then it's not apparent from your code or description what that is.

Here's one idea using variadic macros:
#include <stdalign.h> // for "alignas" - not needed since C23

#define VA_COUNT(...) (sizeof((int[]){0, __VA_ARGS__}) / sizeof(int) - 1)

#define ARRAY_INITIALIZER(V, ...)                       \
    struct {                                            \
        alignas(32) int payload[VA_COUNT(__VA_ARGS__)]; \
    } V = {.payload = {__VA_ARGS__}}

Note that the standard _Alignas (alignas) is used to align the array.
The payload size is calculated by using VA_COUNT.
Example use:
#include <stdio.h>

// the macro definitions from above goes here

#define SIZE(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof *(x))

int main(void) {
    ARRAY_INITIALIZER(a, 1, 2, 3, 4);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < SIZE(a.payload); ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", a.payload[i]);
    }
}

Output:
1
2
3
4


Hi Ted. In my environment I don't have alignas so I still use__attribute__((aligned(32))) after the struct. I am also changing the {0, __VA_ARGS__} to __VA_ARGS__ because I want the _VA_ARGS hold the full {...} initializer, and the result is OK. Any reason you add an extra 0 for it? I check sizeof((int[]){}) and it can compile OK

@EricSun Don't you have _Alignas either? It's in the language since C11, but perhaps you are using an older standard? I recommend that you do not remove the extra 0 and the -1 to compensate. Not that it matters much since you will not use it with empty parameter lists but there's no reason to make the macro fragile.  Demo

Understand Ted. BTW https://godbolt.org/ is new to me and seems very useful. Thank you for the help!

This initialization produces the aligned addresses either in C or C++:
#include <stdalign.h>

alignas(32) int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4} ;
alignas(32) int b[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};


sizeof(b) is 20 which is not 32 byte aligned, which leave the possibility that b and other variables are in the same cache line which may cause potential problems
