# Why is C++ numeric_limits<enum_type>::max() == 0?

Tags: c++, enums, c++11, numeric-limits, strongly-typed-enum

Here's a bit of code that might seem like it would work:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <limits>

enum test { A = 1 };

int main()
{
    int max = std::numeric_limits<test>::max();
    assert(max > 0);
}
```

But it fails under both GCC (4.6.2) and clang (2.9) on Linux: max() for enum types is in fact zero!  And this remains true even if you use the C++11 enum type specifier to explcitly say what type you want your enum to have.

Why is this?  And as for the C++11 behavior, is it something explcitly called for?  I could find no mention of it in N2347, the paper on Strongly Typed Enums.

Comment: What do you expect the value to be?

Comment: What is the result of is_specialized?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: I would assume he expects it to be the same as numeric_limits<int>::max.

Comment: @RaptorFactor:  That is not the maximum value representable by a `test` object, though.  The maximum value representable by a `test` object is `1`.

Comment: I would have been somewhat happy with either one--zero, however, surprised me.  I think what would have made more sense to me would be for it to return the same thing as the underlying type's max.  This is because the current value (0) that max() returns is no more a valid value for my enum than 65535 or anything else would be, which I think mitigates @JamesMcNellis's concern quite well.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that there is a default implementation. Why not just make unsupported types not compile? What use is something like http://ideone.com/8JSgc?

Comment: @UncleBens: that link is interesting in that it shows max() for std::string gives a runtime error rather than a compile-time one.  I am guessing the compile-time form of errors may not have been used in the standard library because such techniques came (more) into vogue well after numeric_limits was invented (again, just a guess).  Your example with std::string suggests that that compiler's default implementation of max() returns T(0)...so I wonder if it will compile at all with types that have no unary constructor.

Comment: @John: All it takes would be to leave the default case incomplete...

Comment: @UncleBens: I agree.  It now seems strange that they didn't provide a has_max flag analogous to has_infinity.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: You can check `is_specialized`. If that is not true, then all values should be considered meaningless.

Comment: Note that a value of `1` cannot be given in general in C++11 because you can forward declare your `enum`. At the point at which you use `std::numeric_limits`, the compiler may not know any of the values of the enum.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`std::numeric_limits` is specialized in the Standard Library "for each arithmetic type, both floating point and integer, including `bool`" (§18.3.2.1/2).

Your enumeration `test` is not one of these types, so the primary template is used.  Its behavior is specified by §18.3.2.3/1: "The default `numeric_limits<T>` template shall have all members, but with `0` or `false` values."

If you want to know the traits of the underlying type of `test`, you can use `underlying_type`:

```
std::numeric_limits<std::underlying_type<test>::type>::max()
```

Alternatively, you can specialize `numeric_limits` for `test` and have it return the values you want.  This is not a particularly good idea, though.

Comment: @RobKennedy:  It would be weird at best, and misleading at worst.  You can't specialize it once for all enums (because there are enums in the Standard Library), so you'd have to specialize it for each individual enum.  Then, what should the values be?  You can't really defer to `underlying_type` directly because the max value representable by the underlying type is not necessarily the max value representable by the enum (e.g., if `test` is represented by `int`, the max `int` value is perhaps `2^32-1`, but the max `test` value is `1`.

Comment: Why would anyone even want to specialize it once for all enums? Normally, one would be interested in a specialization for this particular `test` enum. There wouldn't be anything wrong with that, right?

Comment: I wouldn't expect to be able to rely on the underlying type. If that were possible, we wouldn't need to specialize in the first place. The person doing the specializing presumably knows the properties of the type and can implement the `numeric_limits` functions accordingly. If there are many enum types, this will be tedious, but I wouldn't say it's weird. Seems like a decent structure for uniformly describing the attributes of an enum. The danger is in letting the enum's definition get out of sync with the corresponding `numeric_limits` specialization.

Comment: @jrok:  Aside from it being awkward and likely misleading?  No, there's nothing _wrong_ with that.

Comment: @RobKennedy:  If you want to get traits about an enum, write an `enum_traits`, do not define the primary template, and specialize it for individual enumerations.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Assuming you're here 9 years later. There are scenarios where it's useful to treat numeric and enum types uniformly in a template.

Answer (score 3):

For non-specialized versions of the template, `max` returns `T()`. You have not written a `numeric_limits` specialization for your `test` type, so you get the default implementation.

Comment: This seems to be right. Where is this documented? Doesn't seem to be in the [`numeric_limits` docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).

Comment: Look in [the docs for `max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max), @nh2.

Answer (score 1):

The `numeric_limits<T>` is a regular class template, it is not connected to the compiler in any special way as to find out about user-defined `enum` types. If you look at the `<limits>` file, it has the default template definition that returns zeros for everything, and a whole bunch of type-specific *specifications* for the individual types, returning the right constants.

You can "plug in" your `enum` into `numeric_limits` by providing a specification of `numeric_limits<test>` by yourself. You can copy the one for `int` from the `<limits>`, and modify it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

From the C++11 draft:

In 18.3.2.1, about `numeric_limits`:

> Non-arithmetic standard types, such as complex (26.4.2), shall not have specializations.

And an enum is not an arithmetic standard type.

Then, in the non-specialized template:

```
template<class T> class numeric_limits {
    public:
    [...]
    static constexpr bool is_specialized = false;
    static constexpr T max() noexcept { return T(); }
};
```

That is, the non-specialized `max()` function returns the default initialized value for that type, that is 0.

Comment: An enum is indeed not an arithmetic standard type, but that doesn't mean it's a non-arithmetic standard type. It's not any kind of standard type at all.

Comment: @RobKennedy - Oh! You are right! That paragraph means nothing in this context. But that doesn't change the main point: that `numeric_limits` is not specialized for enum types.