# How to get enum count

Tags: c, enums

How to get enum count

I have a Enum

```
typedef enum{

DEL_TIME_VALUE    = -1,
DEL_TIMESEC_VALUE = 100,
DEL_TIMEMIN_VALUE = 200,
DEL_TIMEHOUR_VALUE = 300,
DEL_DAY_VALUE      = 1000,
DEL_COUNT_VALUE    = 1000,
....
.....
.....
DEL_END             =90002
}WORKINGTIME;
```

How do i get the enum count.

I try below for loop!

```
for(int i=DEL_TIME_VALUE; i<=DEL_END; i++) {

}
```

I guess its not good one!

can any one tell me how to get enum count! which are declared in enum.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [(How) can I count the items in an enum?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102582/how-can-i-count-the-items-in-an-enum)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can't.

There is one technique that allows you to get the enum count. It looks like

```
typedef enum {
    value_one,
    value_two,
    value_three,
    ...
    enum_count
} my_enum;
```

Now the value `enum_count` is the count of values in the enum. However, this technique only works if the enums all carry their *implicit* value, where `value_one` is `0`, `value_two` is `1`, etc. Because of this, the last value in the enum always has the value of the count of enum values. In your case, your enum constants have *explicit* values that are not monotonically incrementing. There is no way to derive a count from this type of enum. And even in the theoretical world where you could derive a count, that wouldn't help you because you could not derive the value of a given enum constant.

Comment: This is a great technique that I've used a ton before too, just thought it worth adding that I've sometimes used it to extend an enum into a second one, in a subclass for example, and still ensuring unique values like this.  typedef enumTwo{ secondTypeOfValueOne = enum_count + 1, secondTypeOfValueTwo, etc, secondTypeOfValueCount }

Comment: Brilliant solution :()

Answer (score 2):

The values of an `enum` are compile time constants, and are not available for introspection in your code.

Instead, you can look at implementing a custom `enum` class with Objective-C (something akin to the Java typesafe Enum http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html).