# Sort Array of JSON objects

Tags: swift

I need to sort an array of JSON objects.

but it is needs to be translated from a literal meaning to a numeric meaning.

for example

object["status"]

"New" = 1

"Open" = 2

"Closed" = 3

/// I need to translated in here some where

```
var sortedOrders = orders.sort { $0["status"].doubleValue < $1["status"].doubleValue  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with an enum.

```
enum Status: Int {
    case new = 1
    case open = 2
    case closed = 3
    case unknown = 99

    init(string: String) {
        switch string {
        case "new", "New": self = .new
        case "open", "Open": self = .open
        case "closed", "Closed": self = .closed
        default:
            self = .unknown
        }
    }
}
```

To use the enum, you could initialize like this:

```
var myStatus = Status(string: object["status"])
```

And use it like this:

```
print(myStatus) // prints "new"
print(myStatus.rawValue) // prints "1"
```

Edit: Since the enum has an underlying type of Int, to accomplish your sort you can compare the resulting Status directly (Thanks to this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/27871946/1718685):

```
var sortedOrders = orders.sort { Status(string: $0["status"]) < Status(string: $1["status"]) }
```

Comment: I like this implementation better than mine. I ended up creating a function to do the "translation" to a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
let statuses = [ "New", "Open", "Closed" ]
var sortedOrders = orders.sort { (statuses.index(of: $0["status"] ?? "") ?? 99) < (statuses.index(of: $1["status"] ?? "") ?? 99) }
```

This will determine the index of each status within the `statuses` array. 99 will be used for unknown or missing statuses so any unknown statuses will appear at the end of the list.