# Swift replacement for old style enums

Tags: ios, macos, swift, enums

Back in the old Objective-C days I would often use enums for things like tables with constant contents, segmented controls, etc - in situations where there was an enforced incremented list of integers starting at zero. I would also often add a ...count member at the end to give a count of the entries, useful for table section & rows. Trying to do this with swift enums is proving troublesome - lots of conversions to & from raw values and extra default clauses in switches to allow for the 'count' entry. Can anyone suggest a graceful method of dealing with these sorts of situations?

Comment: if you want to count your entries, don't add this member, try this
[How do I get the count of a Swift enum?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094878/how-do-i-get-the-count-of-a-swift-enum)

Answer (score 2):

Automatic increment is still available in Swift.

```
enum Section: Int {
   case A = 0
   case B
   case C
}

Section.C.rawValue // -> 2
```

As for `count`, you should implement it manually (as [How do I get the count of a Swift enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27094878/3804019)):

```
enum Section: Int {
   case A = 0
   case B
   case C

   static let count = C.rawValue + 1
}
```

As for "conversions to & from raw values and extra default clauses" problem, compare with `enum` instead of its `rawValue`.

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return Section.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch Section(rawValue: section)! {
    case .A: return 1
    case .B: return 2
    case .C: return 5
    }
}
```

If you want to do something like `array[Section.A]`, you can easily implement it.

```
extension Array {
    subscript(section: Section) -> T {
        return self[section.rawValue]
    }
}

extension NSIndexPath {
    convenience init(forRow row: Int, inSection section: Section) {
        self.init(forRow: row, inSection: section.rawValue)
    }
}

let array = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
array[.B] // -> "bar"


let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 20, inSection: .C)
indexPath.section // -> 2
indexPath.row // -> 20
```

And so on.. :)

Comment: Hard-coding the count - either as a literal or by referencing the (named) last element - are maintenance issues waiting to happen, the whole point of the ...count member was to automate this process. The best solution seems to be to add a 'count' computed value that iterates through integers from zero until it finds one that isn't a valid raw value. Which is clunky but usable.

Comment: You don't need to make `count` a computed value. for exmaple: `static let count: Int = { var i = 0; while Section(rawValue: i) != nil { i++ }; return i }()` works.

Answer (score 0):

Add a function "count" to each enum. For example

```
static func count() -> Int { return 3 }
```

Integer -> enum conversion is done by the init method.