# Count of enum case statements

Tags: swift, enums

I see this pattern a bit:

```
enum Stuff: Int {
        case first = 0
        case second = 1
        case third = 2
        case forth = 3

        static var count = 4
```

Later we will use this count variable, but what I really want is the number of case statements in the enum.  Is there a way to determine this in code?  (Hint, I don't want to trust the associated value)

Comment: You could make an array of all the cases and then get its `count`. Having an array of all the cases is useful in many cases actually. You'd still have to update that array every time you add / remove a case.

Comment: Easy in Swift 4.2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50177561/1187415.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you only use integers you can add this

```
enum Stuff: Int {
    case first
    case second
    case third
    case forth

    static let count: Int = {
        var max: Int = 0        
        while Stuff(rawValue: max) != .none { max += 1 }
        return max
    }()
}
```

Only problem may be that this is O(n), not O(1)

link: [How do I get the count of a Swift enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094878/how-do-i-get-the-count-of-a-swift-enum/27094913#27094913)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27094913

Comment: thanks, i got it from my own project, and I did not remember how I got this solution. Apparently from stackoverflow

Comment: This won't work of a number of enums. There are 2 assumptions that you forgot to mention: Swift enum's with `Int` raw values do not have to start from 0 (even though that's the default behaviour) and their raw values can be arbitrary, they don't have to increment by 1 (even though that's the default behaviour).