# Why the swift enum is returning wrong hashValue in swift 4.1?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift4.1

I have an enum as below

```
enum LoginItems: Int {
    case email = 0
    case password
    case login

    static let numberOfItems = LoginItems.login.hashValue + 1
}
```

Previously in xcode 9.3 we were using swift 4.0 and it used to give proper value but now it gives the value as `5364119284923175996` which is totally wrong. Can someone tell me what is wrong with swift 4.1 or am I doing something wrong in the code.

Comment: What value are you expecting?

Comment: What about using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094878/how-do-i-get-the-count-of-a-swift-enum ?

Comment: Why would you expect the `hashValue` to be consistent? Its documentation explicitly states that _"Hash values are not guaranteed to be equal across different executions of your program. Do not save hash values to use during a future execution."_. You shouldn't use that for any calculations. You should update to Swift 4.2 and use [CaseIterable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/caseiterable)'s `.allCases.count`.

Comment: Yes but before I was using hashvalue to get the count of the number of cases. We didn't have `allCases`. Can you post an answer @DávidPásztor. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have *confused* `rawValue` with `hashValue`.

```
enum LoginItems: Int {
    case email = 0
    case password
    case login

    static let numberOfItems = LoginItems.login.rawValue + 1
}
```

And your code would not have worked in *any* version of Swift. Because `rawValue` is not the same as `hashValue`. An even **better solution** has come up in **Swift 4.2** which is `CaseIterable` protocol which gives you all the cases as an array.

```
enum LoginItems: CaseIterable {
    case email
    case password
    case login
}
```

In this case you wouldn't even need a static variable.

```
print(LoginItems.allCases.count)
```

Comment: Previously using hashvalue used to give the position of the enum case and it was a perfect solution for getting the count of all the cases and it worked fine. Why did it change now @Rakesha Shastri?

Comment: @ShreeshaKedlaya I was not aware of that. My bad. This answer is what you seem to have applied. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27094973/7734643 Like the first comment says, it is an undocumented feature and to me it seems broken.

Comment: `hashValue` did indeed work in earlier versions of Swift, but it was an *invalid use* of `hashValue` and *should not* have been used.