# Enum: Count and list all cases (from outside!)

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I've got this enum (Xcode 10/Swift 5) in its own file ("MyEnum.swift"):

```
enum MyEnum: Int, CaseIterable {
    case A = 0
    case B = 1
    case C = 2
    case D = 3
    case E = 4
    //Each case needs its own number and description!

    var description: String {
        switch self {
            case .A:
                return "abc"
            case .B:
                return "bcd"
            case .C:
                return "cde"
            case .D:
                return "def"
            case .E:
                return "efg"
        }
    }
}
```

... and want to add the descriptions to a `PickerView`. I know how to set up the functions for the view but I'm now stuck on counting the enum cases and adding the descriptions.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/caseiterable) and different questions, adding `CaseIterable` is supposed to make it possible to call

```
MyEnum.allCases.count
```

... but I can only access `allCases` from within the enum file. From outside (so from my ViewController class) I can only call `MyEnum.AllCases`, which hasn't got `count` and, to be honest, I'm not even sure what `AllCases` returns exactly (it's not a normal array you can use `count` on).

Adding this code ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27094913/2016165)) to the enum file at least makes it possible to count the cases:

```
static let count: Int = {
    var max: Int = 0
    while MyEnum(rawValue: max) != .none { max += 1 }
    return max
}()
```

...but isn't there supposed to be an easier way to do this with Swift 4.2+?

How do I get a list of the case descriptions to fill my PickerView with (so "abc", "bcd",... - preferably without hardcoding it)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I tried in 1 file:

```
enum TestEnum: CaseIterable {
    case test1
    case test2
}
```

in another file of another class I wrote:

```
let count = TestEnum.allCases.count
```

And it works, but I noticed that when I was typing "allCases" wasn't shown

[image]

I manually needed to write it

Comment: I tried typing it directly but it only gave me the `Value of type 'MyEnum' has no member 'allCases'` error. After restarting Xcode `allCases` was actually in the list once, now it's back to only displaying `AllCases`...

Comment: @Neph Even though autocomplete only shows `AllCases`, continue to type `allCases` and use it normally. `MyEnum.allCases.count` will surely work from another file, it's just that it doesn't showing up while typing.

Comment: Yes, luckily it does work after restarting (Xcode might have been stuck on some error message) but it only suggests it in a specific function. In all the other ones there's only `AllCases` in the list.

Comment: I just noticed: `rawValue` isn't suggested either, even though it does exist and work.

Comment: @Neph , so I assume it's a bug of Xcode and it can be solved by just manually typing and restarting Xcode. Could you mark one of the answers as correct?

Comment: @PaulT. It's probably just coincidence that restarting made it work once. I only get the suggestion for `allCases` in a specific function. I haven't tested it with `rawValue` properly yet but there's no suggestion for it in the class I need it in.

Comment: @uchuugaka Yes, it does

Comment: Thanks for confirming :) I guess it's always the slow pace of the Swift parser keeping up with what's typed…

Answer (score 2):

`allCases` is declared `public`, so you should be able to access it from another file:

```
/// A collection of all values of this type.
public static var allCases: Self.AllCases { get }
```

like this:

```
let descriptions = MyEnum.allCases.map { $0.description }
```

Try cleaning the project and rebuild.

Also, if something is not in Xcode's autocomplete list, it doesn't mean that you can't access that thing. Xcode's complete list has a ton of bugs according to my own experience.

Comment: The issue is when you type, you don't see "allCases" option, so one needs to write it manually

Comment: Strange, that what I see https://take.ms/QWmTX , may be it's because I test from Share Extension code, I don't know

Comment: I tried typing it directly but Xcode complained that there's no "member allCases". It's weird, I restarted Xcode and the first time I then tried it, it actually suggested "allCases", now it doesn't anymore.

Comment: Try cleaning the project by Cmd+Shift+K and then rebuilding it by Cmd+B. @Neph

Comment: @Sweeper Tried that and also restarted again. The behavior is weird, in a specific function in actually suggests the lower case version, in the others it doesn't.

Comment: I just noticed: `rawValue` isn't suggested either, even though it does exist and work.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness and in case `allCases` doesn't work at all (even after a restart) add this to the enum file:

```
static let allValues = [MyEnum.A, MyEnum.B, MyEnum.C, MyEnum.D, MyEnum.E]
```

It's hardcoded but at least it gives you access to everything:

- count: `MyEnum.allValues.count`
- description (e.g. "abc"): `MyEnum.allValues[0].description`
- rawValue (e.g. 0):`MyEnum.allValues[0].rawValue`

Comment: Don't do this as it creates a dependency on the programmer to keep the cases updated. In case of `CaseIterable` it auto creates `allCases`, and right now it looks like an Xcode issue/limitation that it isn't provided in auto-complete. But rest assured, it will work because it is promised by the protocol. [Read: How CaseIterable Works Internally in Swift](https://swiftrocks.com/how-caseiterable-works-internally-in-swift.html)

Answer (score -1):

The same issue happened to me. What ended up working is restarting xcode.

Comment: Which Xcode version? Please look at the other answers, I commented on them: A restart only made it work once, afterwards the suggestion didn't pop up again.